# Transpose a page of text

Tags: code-golf, string

**EDIT** I modified the wording of the rules to make some things which were implicit more explicit. I also added some emphasis to clear up some points of apparent confusion, and explicitly defined the option of making a standalone program instead of a function.

The goal here is to make a function that takes a text file (or string) and transposes it so that lines become columns and vice versa.

**Example:**

```
I am a text.
Transpose me.
Can you do it?
```

Results in:

```
ITC
 ra
aan
mn
 sy
apo
 ou
ts
eed
x o
tm
.ei
 .t
  ?
```

**The rules:**

- You are allowed to assume that the only whitespace characters used are `" "` and `"\n"` and that there is no trailing whitespace on any line.
- You may assume that the file is ASCII. Which endline marker you want to use is up to you.(CRLF or LF). It must work correctly on the example, but it should also work on **any** input that satisfies the above assumptions.
- You might have to insert spaces (as in the example) where there were none in order to keep the columns in line.
- Your result **must not** have trailing whitespace **on any line**.
- The final newline character(for the last line) is optional.
- **It should be either a function or a complete program.** If your **function** accepts a string, then it should return the results as a string. If it accepts a filename, then you return the name of the file where you saved the result. You are additionally allowed to write a **complete program** that accepts input from STDIN and outputs the correct result to STDOUT; if you do this, you must **not** output anything to STDERR.
- Shortest procedure wins, but I will upvote any answer I like.

Based on the rules, the output on the example is either 53 or 52 bytes long (for LF newlines) depending on whether the final newline is included or not.

**Note:** It is not a specific requirement, but if your function, when run twice successively is not identical to the original(the final newline might be differ, and any empty lines at the end of the file will be deleted), then you are *probably* breaking one of the rules.

Comment: I decided to remove the prohibition on language built-ins.

Comment: I edited to clarify the trailing whitespace condition.

Comment: Are you asking for a function? Is it acceptable to accept a string from STDIN and print the correct output to STDOUT?

Comment: @Quincunx Yes, I am accepting that as a "function".I will alter the rules to be explicit on that point.

Comment: The text transpose function cannot be an involution unless you allow for trailing ws. Example: "a*c\ndef\n" ->TT-> "a*\ncd\nef\n" ~ "a\ncd\nef\n" ->TT-> "acd\nef\n", where *=ws

Comment: @EmanuelLandeholm it wasn't intended to be perfect. It was intended to be an involution up to trailing whitespace. "You might have to insert spaces (as in the example) where there were none in order to keep the columns in line." This never requires a whitespace character to be inserted at the end of a line. The correct transformation  for your example according to the rules is:  "a*c\ndef\n"->"ad\n*e\ncf\n"->"a*c\ndef\n" Note there is no trailing whitespace at any step **and** on this input it is an involution.

Comment: Later duplicate: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85255

Comment: Are blank lines allowed in the input, eg `"abc\n\ndef"` ?

Comment: @LyndonWhite I don't remember anymore what I originally intended, but reading what I wrote, I would say yes.

Comment: Are trailing new lines allowed?

Comment: @AsoneTuhid I think at this point it is best to say, that is unspecified. If you are following the "no trailing whitespace" rule I don't think it should make a difference. But if it does, then choose whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
y mx1R
```

[Try it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=eSBteDFS&input=IkkgYW0gYSB0ZXh0LgpUcmFuc3Bvc2UgbWUuCkNhbiB5b3UgZG8gaXQ/Ig==)
[Run it twice](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=eSBteDFSCnkgbXgxUg==&input=IkkgYW0gYSB0ZXh0LgpUcmFuc3Bvc2UgbWUuCkNhbiB5b3UgZG8gaXQ/Ig==) - returns original string

---

### Explanation

```
y
```

Transpose the input

```
m  R
```

Map over each line

```
x1
```

Trim right

Answer (score 4):

### J (<s>31</s> 40)

```
f=:3 :';(,&LF@dlb&.|.)&.><"1|:>LF cut y'
```

This is a function that takes a string, and returns a string (i.e. a character *vector* with linefeeds inserted in the right places, and not a matrix.)

Edit: no trailing whitespace on any line.

Test:

```
   f=:3 :';(,&LF@dlb&.|.)&.><"1|:>LF cut y'

   string=:stdin''
I am a text.
Transpose me.
Can you do it?
^D

   $string
42
   $f string
53
   f string
ITC
 ra
aan
mn
 sy
apo
 ou
ts
eed
x o
tm
.ei
 .t
  ?
```

Comment: I hope you noticed I removed the prohibition for built-ins.

Comment: @Tim: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't have posted this.

Comment: Is the trailing whitespace rule written unclearly? You seem to have more characters than I expected.

Comment: How many characters should I have? The last characters on the string are `?\n`.

Comment: 53 I think. I intended that the lines shouldn't have trailing whitespace. So apparently it is unclearly worded. Maybe also not a reasonable requirement, since there are spaces in that position in the input.

Comment: You've got trailing whitespace on the `mn`, `ts` and `tm` lines.

Comment: I changed the wording now in the question. I can't/won't penalize you if you don't fix it though.

Comment: @Tim: it's fixed now.

Comment: I'm going to hold off a couple days before marking this as accepted in case someone post something surprising. But I think you got this one. Nothing shorter in APL?

Comment: @Tim: I could only get it to 44 in APL. Main reason is that APL doesn't provide either `cut` or `dlb` by default and writing them myself takes a bunch of characters even in APL.

Answer (score 4):

**Python 2.7 (<s>97</s> <s>79</s> <s>94</s> 90)**

EDIT: Missed the function requirement;

I'm fairly sure this will be improved on since I'm sort of a beginner here, but to start with;

```
c=lambda a:'\n'.join(''.join(y or' 'for y in x).rstrip()for x in map(None,*a.split('\n')))
```

The code uses a simple `split` to split the string into a vector of rows. It then uses `map` with a function value as `None` (the unity function) and the splat operator to transpose and pad the vector (similar functionality to `zip_longest` in Python3)

The rest of the code just maps `None` to space, trims and reassembles the matrix to a single string again.

```
>>> a = 'I am a text.\nTranspose me.\nCan you do it?'
>>> c(a)                                                                            
'ITC\n ra\naan\nmn\n sy\napo\n ou\nts\need\nx o\ntm\n.ei\n .t\n  ?'
>>> len("""c=lambda a:'\n'.join(''.join(y or' 'for y in x).rstrip()for x in map(None,*a.split('\n')))""")
88
# (+2 since `\n` is considered by `len` to be a single char)
```

Comment: Not exactly compliant. It should be a function take takes a string and returns a string.

Comment: @Tim Yes, missed that. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: +1 you appear to be the shortest compliant python entry at the moment.

Comment: Nice use of `map`.  I keep looking for a place to use that... and you just beat me to it.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Ruby 111**

Golfed:

```
def f t;s=t.lines;s.map{|l|l.chomp.ljust(s.map(&:size).max).chars}.transpose.map{|l|l.join.rstrip+?\n}.join;end
```

Ungolfed:

```
def transpose_text(text)
  max_length = text.lines.map(&:size).max
  text.lines.map do |line|
    line.chomp.ljust(max_length).chars
  end.transpose.map do |chars|
    chars.join.rstrip + "\n"
  end.join
end
```

Ruby has an array transpose function, so this simply pads the lines out, turns them into an array of characters, uses Ruby's Array#transpose function, then turns the array of characters back into lines.

Golfing it was simply using single-character identifiers, removing spaces, using a temporary for text.lines, and putting the calculation for max_length inline (there are no points for efficiency).

Comment: Nice. You can strip out one more character by replacing `"\n"` with `?\n`.

Comment: Also, the `.to_a` is superfluous. You can gain another 5 characters there.

Comment: @O-I Thanks, I owe you six characters.  I dashed this off at work, which uses 1.9.3.  The to_a is required in 1.9.3, but not in 2.0.

Comment: I see. Good to know. Consider us even for showing me a few String methods in Ruby I should be using more often. Cheers!

Comment: Some of the code golf challenges have renewed my interest in learning ruby.

Answer (score 4):

### R, 171

```
function(e){p=strsplit
x=t(plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(p(p(e,"\n")[[1]],""),t)))
x[is.na(x)]=" "
cat(apply(x,1,function(y)sub(" *$","",paste(y,collapse=""))),sep="\n")}
```

Usage example:

```
text <- "I am a text.
Transpose me.
Can you do it?"


(function(e){p=strsplit
x=t(plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(p(p(e,"\n")[[1]],""),t)))
x[is.na(x)]=" "
cat(apply(x,1,function(y)sub(" *$","",paste(y,collapse=""))),sep="\n")})(text)

ITC
 ra
aan
mn
 sy
apo
 ou
ts
eed
x o
tm
.ei
 .t
  ?
```

Trailing whitespace is removed.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash+coreutils+sed, 83

```
eval paste `sed 's/.*/<(fold -w1<<<"&")/'`|expand -t2|sed 's/\(.\) /\1/g;s/ \+$//'
```

`fold` and `paste` do the important work.  The rest is just formatting.

Accepts input from stdin and outputs to stdout:

```
$ < tr.txt ./transposefile.sh
ITC
 ra
aan
mn
 sy
apo
 ou
ts
eed
x o
tm
.ei
 .t
  ?
$ < tr.txt ./transposefile.sh | ./transposefile.sh
I am a text.
Transpose me.?
Can you do it
$
```

Comment: You appear to be breaking the rule "Your result must not have trailing whitespace on any line."

Comment: @TimSeguine Oops I missed that one.  I just fixed it in the latest edit.

Comment: Great answer.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY47T8NAEIT7/RWjKOLyELcKLScoEAUVBZQussQbHMn2Wb4FDin/3ZxI0kA7j2/mTVIzTTsxhPD4/II72OgtGz1BOghMs3l6HaVPQ0yKTj09SI/v@IE64mD3VGpEo0qN67GGc8gIFwqdyK5k3C/7zNkfWvWpIf2UFoMkU2yTlnZiv@Kw2Me24L42IYTZ1WzJbnvUPEhfRLs5npPVwldLcLXh99vEqNZzZne6s2u6WGOd/y/S5Rs8/zWn6Qc "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

**C (278 bytes)**

*Edit: This actually breaks the rules, since it takes a filename in as an argument but writes to stdout. I'll edit it later to write to a file and then print the filename to stdout.*

This is my first code golf ever, so have mercy. Some plain old C. Place the input in `test.txt` and let it run!

`clang transpose.c -o transpose && ./transpose test.txt`

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

#define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char line[BUFFER_SIZE];

    FILE *f; int nLines, maxLen;

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while(!feof(f) && fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE, f)) {
        nLines++;
        maxLen = MAX(maxLen, strlen(line));
    }
    fclose(f);

    for (int charPos = 0; charPos < maxLen; charPos++) {
        f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        for (int linePos = 0; linePos < nLines; linePos++) {
            fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE, f);
            printf("%c", charPos < strlen(line) && line[charPos] != '\xA' ? line[charPos] : ' ');
        }
        printf("\n");
        fclose(f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

By using short variable names, removing gratuitous formatting, and allowing file handles to leak, and disabling all warnings this is reduced to 278 bytes. (Since this uses implicit imports, it may not link properly on all systems. Works on my machine!)

```
#import <stdio.h>
int main(int C,char**V){char L[1024];int A,B,D,I,J,*F=fopen(V[1],"r");while(!feof(F)&&fgets(L,1024,F)){A++;D=strlen(L);B=B>D?B:D;}for(I=0;I<B;I++){F=fopen(V[1],"r");for(J=0;J<A;J++)fgets(L,1024,F)&&printf("%c",I<strlen(L)&&L[I]!='\n'?L[I]:' ');printf("\n");}}
```

Comment: I think you can take advantage of implicit `int` to shorten some of your declarations, or is that illegal now?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using that in a later edit to not import stdlib.h or string.h. If I don't import stdio.h it segfaults on run.

Comment: To your edit comment on the rules: your other alternative is to accept input from stdin. I would consider that conforming as well. And also, I can't tell from a cursory glance: does it strip whitespace from the ends of lines in the transpose version?

Comment: Since I re-read the file multiple times to avoid storing in RAM, reading from stdio would probably be harder. :)

I'm not sure what whitespace should be stripped. Right now I don't think it does any stripping at all, unfortunately. I'll have to work on that too.

Comment: You can declare `A,B,D,I,J,*F` as global variables, in order to avoid `int` keyword. Similarly, you can remove `int` from `main` declaration, and `C` argument. In `C`, `int` is optional in many places.

Comment: To answer which whitespace must be stripped. After transposition there is most likely going to be trailing `" "` characters on some lines. These should be deleted.

Comment: unlucky line break. The character in the quotation marks is a space.

Answer (score 3):

### AutoHotkey 210

```
f(i){
StringSplit,o,i,`n
m:=0
loop % o0 {
a:=A_index
if (t:=Strlen(p:=o%a%))>m
m:=t
StringSplit,l%a%,o%a%
}
loop % m {
a:=A_index,n:=""
loop % o0
n.=(j:=l%A_index%%a%)=""?" ":j
s.=Rtrim(n," ") "`n"
}
return s
}
```

#### Test

```
text=
(
I am a text.
Transpose me.
Can you do it?
)
msgbox % f(text)
```

Comment: I can't test this one, but it looks compliant

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 124 bytes

```
D=`mktemp -d`;split -l1 - $D/;for F in $D/*;do grep -o . $F>$F+
done;paste $D/*+|sed -e's/\([^\t]\)\t/\1/g;s/\t/ /g;s/ *$//'
```

It reads standard input and writes standard output. Try it:

```
echo $'I am a text.\nTranspose me.\nCan you do it?' | script.sh
```

How it works:

- `split` input into single lines (files in temporary directory `$D`)
- split lines into single characters using `grep` (files *+)
- layout characters side-by-side using `paste` (TAB-separated columns)
- remove alignment TABs, replace filler TABs with BLANKs, trim using `sed`

Edit:

- -9: Removed tidy-up code `;rm -r $D` (thanks Tim)
- -2: use `+` instead of `_` as suffix and shorten `${F}_` to `$F+`
- -3: remove prefix `L` from split result files

Comment: For the purposes of code golf, you don't necessarily have to be nice and clean up after yourself. You can leave off the `rm` bit from your character count.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby: 88 characters

(Posted because it's shorter then the other Ruby solutions. Not checked whether my code introduces anything new compared to those. If you already posted a Ruby solution and you feel this is mostly a copy of yours, please comment and I will retire my answer.)

```ruby
f=->t{l=t.split$/;r=[""]*m=l.map(&:size).max;l.map{|l|m.times{|i|r[i]+=l[i]||" "}};r*$/}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> f=->t{l=t.split$/;r=[""]*m=l.map(&:size).max;l.map{|l|m.times{|i|r[i]+=l[i]||" "}};r*$/}
=> #<Proc:0x99a9e68@(irb):1 (lambda)>

irb(main):002:0> sample='I am a text.
irb(main):003:0' Transpose me.
irb(main):004:0' Can you do it?'
=> "I am a text.\nTranspose me.\nCan you do it?"

irb(main):005:0> puts f[sample]
ITC
 ra
aan
mn
 sy
apo
 ou
ts
eed
x o
tm
.ei
 .t
  ?
=> nil

irb(main):006:0> puts f[f[sample]]
I am a text.
Transpose me.
Can you do it?
=> nil
```

Comment: +1 You golfed it better in any case.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 40 bytes

```
P`.+
~L0$`.
L,$.%'vs,$.(x$%=),`.+
m` *$
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyBBT5urzsdAJUGPy0dHRU9VvawYSGlUqKjaauqAJHMTFLRUuP7/91RIzFVIVChJrSjR4wopSswrLsgvTlXITdXjck7MU6jML1VIyVfILLEHAA)

Based on [this program](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/390wgcs5gUtPm0tF25DLuSxBTw/C4VLy0VHRNikrBpJGOgl62kpxdQlcKgb//3sqJOYqJCqUpFaU6HHh5AAA) that I created to transpose any size of rectangle, which uses [Leo's suggestion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43831903#43831903) for transposing a rectangle of a known size.

Edit: Golfed more and no longer has trailing spaces on lines.

Answer (score 2):

#### Ruby — 144 characters

Here's my first attempt, golfed:

```
def f t
t.split(?\n).each{|l|l<<' 'until l.size==t.split(?\n).map(&:size).max}.map{|x|x.split('')}.transpose.map{|l|l.join.rstrip}.join(?/n)
end
```

For output, run `puts f text` where `text` is any multi-line string adhering to the rules above. The ungolfed version is below:

```
def text_transpose(text)
  lines = text.split(?\n)
  maxlen = lines.map(&:size).max
  lines.each { |line| line << ' ' until line.size == maxlen }
       .map  { |line| line.split('') }.transpose
       .map  { |char| char.join.rstrip }.join(?\n)
end
```

For a similar, but ultimately better solution in Ruby, check out Wayne Conrad's code above.

Comment: I didn't notice the `transpose` in your answer before I wrote mine.  It doesn't seem quite kosher for me to have essentially rewritten your answer, only a little better. :(

Comment: I don't mind at all. You came up with your code independently and it's not a race. I definitely learned something from your solution. Had you held back because I used `transpose`, it's possible a better Ruby solution wouldn't have surfaced. One of things I love most about programming is the willingness to collaborate and cross-pollinate ideas. Till we meet again, kind sir. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**PHP 194**

```
function x($a){$a.="\n";$s=strlen($a);$i=0;while($c<$s)if($a{$c}!="\n")$b[$i++].=$a{$c++};else{$c++;for(;$i<$s;$i++)$b[$i].=" ";$i=0;}ksort($b);return rtrim(implode("\n",array_map("trim",$b)));}
```

Non-golfed:

```
function x($a) {
    $a.="\n";
    $s=strlen($a);
    $i=0;
    while($c<$s)
        if($a{$c}!="\n")
            $b[$i++].=$a{$c++};
        else{
            $c++;
            for(;$i<$s;$i++)
                $b[$i].=" ";$i=0;
        }
    ksort($b);
    return rtrim(implode("\n",array_map("trim",$b)));
}
```

This is my first golfing attempt, so please be kind! Also, tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's shorter than my php attempt. You can save two characters by gitting rid of the `"`s around `"trim"`. php will give a warning, but it works just fine.

Comment: @TimSeguine Warnings output on screen though right? You'll have to use `@` to suppress warnings.

Comment: @eric I haven't been active in a while so the opinions might have changed, but in the past it was deemed acceptable to output irrelevant data to standard error.

Comment: It's allowed? If that is true, then I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

### MATHEMATICA 117 chars

```
t = "I am a text.\nTranspose me.\nCan you do it?";

f=(m=Length/@(f=Flatten[Characters/@StringSplit[#,"\n"],{{2},{1}}])//Max;
StringJoin@@@(PadLeft[#,m," "]&/@f)//Column)&
```

Comment: I can't test this one, so can you verify that it removes traling whitespace on the ends of lines? Also this doesn't appear(at first glance) to define a function, which the rules require.

Comment: hi @Tim, now it is a function `f`!.. tks

Answer (score 2):

## Perl (92+1)

reads stdin and writes to stdout.  adding 1 to the score for `say`

```
@L=map[grep!/\n/,split//],<>;do{$_=join'',map shift@$_||$",@L;s/ +$//;say}while grep@$_>0,@L
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>32</s> 25 bytes

CJam is newer than this challenge, so this answer is not eligible for being accepted.

Considerably shortened by user23013.

```
qN/_z,f{Se]}z{S+e`);e~N}%
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F_z%2Cf%7BSe%5D%7Dz%7BS%2Be%60)%3Be~N%7D%25&input=I%20am%20at%20ext.%0ATranspo%20se%20me.%0ACan%20you%20%20do%20it%3F)

```
qN/                       "Read input, split into lines.";
   _z,                    "Transpose, get length (find maximum line length).";
      f{Se]}              "Pad each line to that length with spaces.";
            z             "Transpose.";
             {         }% "Map this block onto each line in the result.";
              S+          "Add a space to ensure there's at least one.";
                e`        "Run-length encode.";
                  );      "Discard the trailing run of spaces.";
                    e~    "Run-length decode";
                      N   "Push a newline.";
```

Comment: Eligible or not, it is a great late answer. Seems like the hardest part for this answer was dealing with the trailing spaces.

Comment: @TimSeguine Indeed. Without a built-in trimming operator, doing this manually in CJam is surprisingly cumbersome (user23013's suggestion already improved it considerably).

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 103

```js
s=>[...s].map((_,i)=>s.split`
`.map(b=>r+=b[q=b[i]||q,i]||' ',r=q='')&&r.replace(/ *$/,q?`
`:q)).join``
```

*Less golfed*

```js
s=>[...s].map(
     // we need 'i' ranging from 0 to the length of the longest input line
     // so we scan all the input string, that is surely longer
     // but we need to check that after some point the output must be empty
     (_, i) => ( 
       r = '', // the current output row, starts empty
       q = '', // flag to check if we are beyond the longest line
       s.split('\n') // split in rows
       .map( 
         b => ( // for each input row in b
           q = b[i] || q, // if there is a char at position i in b, i goes to q
           r += b[i] || ' ' // add to output the char at position i or a fill space
         )
       ),
       q // if q is still '', we are beyond the longest input line 
       ? r.replace(/ *$/,`\n`) // trim leading space and add newline
       : '' // no output 
     )
   ).join('')
```

**Test**

```js
F=
s=>[...s].map((_,i)=>s.split`
`.map(b=>r+=b[q=b[i]||q,i]||' ',r=q='')&&r.replace(/ *$/,q?`
`:q)).join``

function go() {
  var text=I.value
  var output = F(text)
  O.textContent = output
}

go()
```

```css
#I { width:50%; height:5em }
```

```html
<textarea id=I>I am a text.
Transpose me.
Can you do it?</textarea><br>
<button onclick='go()'>Transpose</button>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 25 bytes

Note that this uses ANSI escape sequences and as such does not work on TIO, you can however [see it in action here](https://asciinema.org/a/eOM9VLfMu4qfsLECNNlSlBbQi).

```perl
$"="[1D";$_="[1;$.H@F"
```

#### Explanation

This code first changes the [list separator (`$"`)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24LIST_SEPARATOR) value to be a vertical tab, followed by the ANSI escape sequence for 'go backwards 1 column' (`\x1b[1D`), then we set the implicitly printed variable `$_` to be a string that starts with the ANSI escape sequence for 'start printing at line 1 column `$.` (where `$.` is the current line of text)' (`\x1b1;$.H`) and interpolates the list `@F` (which is a list of all the characters on that line, populated  by autosplit (`-a`) with an empty split pattern (`-F`)) which places the contents of `$"` in between each item, moving the cursor vertically down instead of continuing output after the previous character.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FyVaJWzra0EXJWiXeVgnIslbR83BwU/r/31MhMVchUaEktaJEjyukKDGvuCC/OFUhN1WPyzkxT6Eyv1QhJV8hs8T@X35BSWZ@XvF/3YLEHDcA)

Comment: Oh my god, the sheer horror! I love it!

Answer (score 1):

### C++ (243 characters)

Here's a function that takes and returns a string.

I could've shaved a couple dozen chars, but decided to keep it as not-stupid code (runs fast, reads okay). Maybe I only decided to do that because this is my first code golf... I'm not hardcore enough yet :)

```
string f(string s){stringstream ss(s);vector<string> v;for(size_t i=0;getline(ss,s);++i){if(v.size() < s.size())v.resize(s.size());for(size_t j=0;j<s.size();++j){v[j].resize(i,' ');v[j].push_back(s[j]);}}s="";for(auto& i:v)s+=i+'\n';return s;}
```

With formatting:

```
string f(string s)
{
    stringstream ss(s);
    vector<string> v;

    for(size_t i = 0; getline(ss, s); ++i)
    {
        if(v.size() < s.size())
            v.resize(s.size());

        for(size_t j = 0; j < s.size(); ++j)
        {
            v[j].resize(i, ' ');
            v[j].push_back(s[j]);
        }
    }

    s = "";
    for(auto& i : v)
        s += i + '\n';

    return s;
}
```

Comment: I assume you use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @xfix Not normally, but I did for this

Comment: If I am being picky, I would say `using namespace std;` should be added to the character count.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7 - **115 chars**:

oneliner:

```
>>> a
'I am a text.\nTranspose me.\nCan you do it?'

>>> "".join(["".join(i)+'\n' for i in zip(*[x+" "*(len(max(a.splitlines(), key=len))-len(x)) for x in a.splitlines()])])
'ITC\n ra\naan\nmn \n sy\napo\n ou\nts \need\nx o\ntm \n.ei\n .t\n  ?\n'
```

and in a cleaner printing:

```
>>> print "".join(["".join(i)+'\n' for i in zip(*[x+" "*(len(max(a.splitlines(), key=len))-len(x)) for x in a.splitlines()])])
ITC
 ra
aan
mn 
 sy
apo
 ou
ts 
eed
x o
tm 
.ei
 .t
  ?
```

**in 115 chars:**

```
>>> len(""""".join(["".join(i)+'\n' for i in zip(*[x+" "*(len(max(a.splitlines(), key=len))-len(x)) for x in a.splitlines()])])""")
115
```

Comment: You are not stripping the trailing whitespace on your lines like the rules require.

Comment: Also, it's actually 116 bytes, `\n` is considered by `len` to be a single char, but it's two :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson on unix `\n` is one. So I say one is fine.

Comment: @Tim `len("\n")` will show 1, although it's certainly 2 separate characters in the source code. Saving the source to a file will make `ls` display 116. Just saying that `len` isn't the best way to measure code size due to escape characters being processed before measuring :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson oh, sorry I misunderstood your point.

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript, 51 chars

```
n%.{,}%$-1=" "*:y;{y+y,<}%zip{n\+0{;).32=}do}%((;\+
```

This is a first attempt; I suspect it can be improved.  Most of the code is to comply with the padding and trailing space removal requirements — without them, just `n%zip n*` would suffice.

Ps. The following **46**-character version will do the job for the given sample input, but will crash if any input column consists entirely of spaces:

```
n%.{,}%$-1=" "*:y;{y+y,<}%zip{0{;).32=}do]}%n*
```

I assume that's enough to disqualify it, even if the challenge doesn't explicitly say so.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. It should work on any ASCII text under the assumptions allowed in the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Python <s>89</s> 103 chars

```
def f(a):return'\n'.join([''.join(i).rstrip()for i in zip(*[j+' '*99 for j in a.split('\n')])]).rstrip()
```

I feel dirty. <s>90</s> 104 chars for industrial strength version. :^)

Comment: not a function.

Comment: @Tim My bad, fixed. Anyway my solution is inferior to Joachim Isaksson's. I wonder if there's any short way to solve this problem with recursion.

Answer (score 1):

## Scheme/Racket 113

The text:

```
(define t (list 
    (string->list "I am a text.") 
    (string->list "Transpose me.")
    (string->list "Can you do it?")
))
```

Without new lines and extra white spaces:

```
(define s(λ(v x)(if(= x 0)'()(cons(list->string(car v))(s(cdr v)(- x 1))))))(s(apply map list t)(length(car t)))
```

The user-friendly version

```
(define text (list 
    (string->list "I am a text.") 
    (string->list "Transpose me.")
    (string->list "Can you do it?")
))

(define transpose
    (λ(text length)
        (if (= length 0)
            '()
            (cons (list->string (car text)) (transpose (cdr text) (- length 1)))
)))

(transpose (apply map list text) (length (car text)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell

```
import Data.List
main = interact (unlines . transpose . lines)
```

It was so short, I needed to add in white space...

Comment: I'm almost sure you can remove some of the whitespace here. But otherwise, great solution.

Comment: This doesn't quite work on my system. It's a bit hard to show in a comment, but if you run it twice you get `I am a text..?` `Transpose met` `Can you do i`.

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking maybe you are not padding the lines to keep the columns intact like the example does. Theorectally, the result of running the function twice should be the original string(with possibly the addition or removal of the final newline.)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 95 chars

```
f=""<>Riffle[Thread@PadRight@Characters@StringSplit[#,"\n"]//.{0->" ",{x___," "..}:>{x}},"\n"]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## K, 56

This should meet the spec now.

Accepts a string, returns a string.

```
{`/:{$[" "=*|x;|(+/&\" "=|x)_|x;x]}'x@'/:!max@#:'x:`\:x}
```

.

```
k)f:{`/:{$[" "=*|x;|(+/&\" "=|x)_|x;x]}'x@'/:!max@#:'x:`\:x}
k)f"I am a text.\nTranspose me.\nCan you do it?"
"ITC\n ra\naan\nmn\n sy\napo\n ou\nts\need\nx o\ntm\n.ei\n .t\n  ?\n"
k)f f"I am a text.\nTranspose me.\nCan you do it?"
"I am a text.\nTranspose me.\nCan you do it?\n"
```

Comment: The output appears to be an array of strings?

Comment: @Tim It is. If you want a single string then add three chars. `{\`/:x@'/:!max@#:'x:\`\:x}` for 26.

Comment: You also have a problem with trailing whitespace. And "If it accepts a filename, then you return the name of the file where you saved the result." You need to return output in the same manner you accept input.

Comment: @Tim should be fixed now. Kills my bytecount though

Comment: I suspected it might :( , but a spec is a spec.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 98 chars

```
{i->o=[].withDefault{''};i.readLines().each{it.toList().eachWithIndex{c,d->o[d]+=c}};o.join('\n')}
```

[online](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5165882108018688)

ungolfed:

```
{i->
o=[].withDefault{''};//create list with empty string as default value 
i.readLines()
.each{
    it.toList() //split every line to characters
    .eachWithIndex{ 
        c,d->o[d]+=c //append to string from list with right index
    }
};
o.join('\n')}//join list with newlines
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (MinGW), <s>272</s> <s>262</s> <s>259</s> <s>254</s> <s>234</s> <s>229</s> 228 bytes

-15 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

The TiO link requires the string.h include, but MinGW does not.

```c
n,a,i,j;*f(int*s){char*p,**L=a=n=i=0,*r;for(;p=strtok(L?0:s,"\n");j>a?a=j:0)j=strlen((L=realloc(L,++n*8))[n-1]=p);for(p=r=calloc(n+1,a+1);i<a;i++,*p++=10){for(j=0;j<n;j++)*p++=i<strlen(L[j])?L[j][i]:32;while(p[-1]==32)p--;}s=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZA/b8IwEMV3PoWVLv4XlMBS4RwZOlXK2C1ksIIDdsPFso3aCvHZU0K7nHR6791P9/r81Pfzi8V@vB5NFVOweFqf9zNKLa10ig/UYuKR3fqzDtxLzhvQgGChkDyoYQpUeXgE0/RJm7rYRZkdMGPK7XWtwe0K5hZ5NEhpA8HocZx62kghkL8y1mJeduDZ85KHAP2fAUUptSiZspVWVgjJvRBQFuy2GB0UylWonBDsKdjqn9G0rmP1Mlvb7bYb9XW2o6G@XTCw3TCf5@oeIaj7fNEWKbutltdIbDvI3om@EE2S@U7rA34EjdFP0ZCLeaxvGsnPdCXHidhUZ2rlH22lgQ40MqZW9/kX)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
# aYcw1;.tY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1khMTK53NBaryTy/39PhcRchUSFktSKEj2ukKLEvOKC/OJUhdxUPS7nxDyFyvxShZR8hcwSewA)

Takes input as a string, outputs a list of lists

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 25 bytes

```
# aYcw1=+Z1;jbcj"".n.tY)Z
```

Takes input as a string, outputs a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1khMTK53NBWO8rQOispOUtJSS9PryRSM@r/f0@FxFyFRIWS1IoSPa6QosS84oL84lSF3FQ9LufEPIXK/FKFlHyFzBJ7AA)

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>28</s> 26 Bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to frownyfrog

```
t=.,@:(,&LF"1)@|:@:>@cutLF
```

Takes a string, returns a string. I'm not sure if there's a shorter version of the 'cutopen' <s>function</s> *verb* that I could use.

There's also the shorter

```
t=.|:@:>@cutLF
```

But I'm not sure it falls within the OP's guidelines, as it returns an array of characters.

#### How it works:

```
                     cutLF   | Splits the input on new lines and boxes them
                    @        | Composes verbs (as does @:, but they're not equal)
                   >         | Unboxes this, forming an array of the lines
                 @:          |
               |:            | Transposes the array
      (      )@              |
       ,&LF                  | Appends a new line...
           "1                | To each row of the array
    @:                       |
   ,                         | Flatten the result
t=.                          | Assign this verb to t
```

The other version works the same, but doesn't convert the transposed array to a properly formatted string.

#### Examples:

```
NB. Define a multi-line string

    text =: 0 : 0
I am a text.
Transpose me.
Can you do it?
)

    t text
ITC
 ra
aan
mn    NB. There's whitespace after the 'n' here, but I assume it doesn't count as trailing since it's part of the original string
 sy
apo
 ou
ts 
eed
x o
tm 
.ei
 .t
  ?

    t t text
I am a text.     NB. Again, whitespace here, but it's part of the argument of the second 't' (added by the first 't' to keep columns straight)
Transpose me. 
Can you do it?
```

Comment: I would use `cutLF`.

Comment: Save 1 character with `0|:>@cutLF`

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <del>203</del> 189 bytes

```lua
t={{}}i=1m=0(...):gsub(".",function(c)n=#t[i]if c=="\n"then i=i+1t[i]={}else t[i][n+1]=c end m=m<=n and n+1or m end)
for x=1,m do for p=1,i do io.write(t[p][x]or" ")end _=m<=x or print()end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU89T8MwEN3zK05hcdTUIhkRJwYmdjZjIZO69ERtR44TgqL89nCuWsFyfh@n93zn0WxbwmVZV8LG4b2QUlYPn8P4IUpZ1sfRd4mCF13l8S4p0nSEDrF882U6WQ@EtGuyjstqz4OFjJXfNRo7sP4ADt0jejAMWQ0RXJar4shwxqZ2cAiQSc@EMqEgvyMlK5LqtZp1iCWUVc56z1kz5OVIPoksbvu9Ulda3N6c91XDBMQ/7A3FQaSKswu4VFHLXvvPnK4m/JVPrZS5l1Vu4XnLZqb1tr2AcWAg2TnJ4jUaP/SBz3dWFs/Gw08YL7ekp18)

I saw another Lua solution here, but I don't think there's a problem with posting 2 solutions on the same language. If there is, tell me :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with multiple answers in the same language. Even identical answers are allowed to an extent (though it's encouraged to at least check if you're posting the a similar solution)

Comment: Unfortunately *Your result must not have trailing whitespace on any line*.

Comment: But I can't see trailing whitespaces on the output of my code. There's no spaces after the line ends and no blank line at the end.

Comment: The part that seems to catch people out is *on **any** line*. e.g. [This](https://tio.run/##VU7bboMwDH3nK6zsJag0GjxO85ekUZXSsFkrAUFgSIhvp/bUatuD43Oxzslt8vuecF23jbBs8VUbY/K3j3G6aGVU0UyxTtRFXecRX5IlRw3UiOoUVfoMEQjpUIqO6xZuYwDBNh5KhzWEeIUW23eM4Bmy2g3QipxnDcMFy6KFawdCeiYkhDrzPVAKOtne2cV1gwKVS9ZZshaQ44Fi0iLux6O1D5o9t@R9FTAD8Q97T8OoU87ZGfxUUcVe9cecHyb8ls@VMdLLKrfw@8xm5ty@@0udefg3dw "Lua – Try It Online") has extra whitespace on the second line

Comment: Ohhh now I got it! Sorry. I'll try to make it work as soon as I have time.
I think the problem was that there's only 1 example test and I thought that would be the "stress" test hahah But ok, thanks for telling me :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>87</s> 101 bytes

```python
lambda s:T('\n'.join(map(T,map(''.join,zip(*[t.ljust(len(s))for t in s.split('\n')])))))
T=str.rstrip
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYwxDsIwDEX3nsJbHFRlYETqLbJRhhSIcJUmVmwGuHxIYeJL/w1vePzSR8nHFqe5pbAttwBy8mjmbNxaKOMWGP240/zM@CbGw1ldWp@imO4ZxdpYKihQBnHCifRbsBe7b/CTaHW1g7hxpawQe86E5ToE@Hu3tn0A)

Comment: Unfortunately *Your result must not have trailing whitespace on any line*. Also it seems to print a *lot* of extra newlines.

Comment: @Jo King: Thx - My new toy did not work here!

Comment: This still has trailing whitespace on some lines [for example](https://tio.run/##VYwxDgIxDAR7XuEuNkIpKJF4CUeRAyJ8yjlW7Cvg8yGIimKl0Uiz@vJnlWPP56mXtM73BHYKk4S4VBZck2L48eHNivuLx7Js5lgegkaUawMHFrBoWtjx29KViGIzbyOhro3FIY@jkObbLsHfhqX@AQ)

Comment: @Jo King: Ah yes. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB: <s>24</s> <s>42</s> 29 bytes

```
@(s)deblank(string(char(s)'))
```

**Usage**

```
s=["I am a text.";"Transpose me";"Can you do it?"];
@(s)deblank(string(char(s)'))
ans(s)
```

**Output**

```
ans =

  14×3 char array

    'ITC'
    ' ra'
    'aan'
    'mn'
    ' sy'
    'apo'
    ' ou'
    'ts'
    'eed'
    'x o'
    'tm'
    '.ei'
    '  t'
    '  ?'
```

Might be cheating here, as it's hard (as far as I can see) to get a string with newlines into MATLAB without using an array, so I went ahead and used an array for the input. Other than that, it does what it says on the tin - turns the string into a matrix of chars, transposes it and trims the whitespace.

**Edit:**
Changed (and lengthened) the program as I didn't see the requirement for whitespace to be trimmed.

**Edit:**
-13 bytes thanks to sundar.

Comment: "Your result must not have trailing whitespace on any line."

Comment: You don't need to include the `f=` in the byte count. And, you can probably shorten `transpose(char(s))` to `char(s)'` (the single quote operator acts as a transpose here).

Comment: @sundar You're right! I use the single quote operator all the time but for some reason it totally slipped my mind while golfing... how annoying.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ζεðÜ}»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3LZzWw9vODyn9tDu//@jlTwVEnMVEhVKUitK9JR0FJRCihLzigvyi1MVclPBAs6JeQqV@aUKKfkKmSX2SrEA)
[Try it when taking the output as input-list again.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3LZzWw9vODyn9tDu//@jlTxDnJV0FJQUihJBVGJiHojKBZMKxZVgsYJ8MC@/FESVFIPI1NQUEFWhAJYqyQWReqmZYHV6JWBKwV4pFgA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ζ         # Zip the input-list, swapping rows and columns
 ε  }     # For-each:
  ðÜ      #  Remove trailing spaces
     »    # Join the resulting list by new-lines (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 5 bytes

```
!Z{Zv
```

[Try it on MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%21Z%7BZv&inputs=%5B%27I+am+a+text.%27%3B+%27Transpose+me.%27%3B+%27Can+you+do+it%3F%27%5D&version=20.9.2)

Input is taken implicitly, and conveniently, the shorter lines get spaces added to them by the environment to make them all equal in length.

`!` - transpose

`Z{` - Convert to cell array (since we'll need to hold arrays of different lengths after the next step)

`Zv` - deblank i.e. remove the trailing spaces

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>35</s> 29 bytes

```matlab
@(s)strjoin(cellstr(s'),'\n')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchBCsJADAXQq/xdJiBzAREFV@7dqYvQpjDSTkqTFj39WNw9nnUhm7YBJ@Sc2yU5eyxvKzV1Oo67kxMf6FmJW198TkN60A0yQRD6iUxH0H2R6rO5YtJ/XKXiayt6Q4kzvZjbDw)

*(-1 byte thanks to Luis Mendo, -5 bytes thanks to strjoin from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29282382/8127))*

Comment: You can remove the `.`. Best practices go out of the window in code golf :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo Ha, I didn't even realize I'd added the `.`, automatic muscle memory.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <strike>102</strike> 100 bytes

```
q=>[...q].reduce((r,e,j)=>(y=w.map((e,i)=>w[i][j]||" ").join``.trimEnd())?r+y+`
`:r,"",w=q.split`
`)
```

## Run it here:

```js
f = q=>[...q].reduce((r,e,j)=>(y=w.map((e,i)=>w[i][j]||" ").join``.trimEnd())?r+y+`
`:r,"",w=q.split`
`);

console.log(f(`I am a text.
Transpose me.
Can you do it?`));
```

Comment: Seems like there is still potential to golf this; a lot of big names and movable snippets

Comment: Using the same basic idea, I was able to get 92 by replacing reduce with map then filter then join(sounds longer, but you save the ternary, an assignment and some parens)

Comment: without the string parameter golfing it looks like this: `q=>[...q].map((x,i)=>w.map(x=>x[i]||" ").join("").trimEnd(),w=q.split("\n")).filter(x=>x).join("\n")`

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that will delete empty lines

Comment: You've made me realize my solution incorrectly handles empty lines. Regardless, thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP <strike>227</strike> 217**

Here's my attempt:

```
function f($s){$p=array_map;$s=$p(str_split,explode("
",$s));foreach($s as&$l)$l=array_pad($l,max($p(count,$s)),' ');array_unshift($s,null);foreach(call_user_func_array($p,$s)as$l)$r.=rtrim(implode($l))."
";return$r;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
<?php
function f($s) {
    $s=array_map(str_split, explode("\n",$s));
    foreach($s as &$l)
        $l=array_pad($l, max(array_map(count, $s)),' ');
    array_unshift($s, null);
    foreach(call_user_func_array(array_map, $s)as$l)
        $r.=rtrim(implode($l))."\n";
    return $r;
    }
$s="I am a text.
Transpose me.
Can you do it?";
echo f($s);
echo strlen(f($s));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Haskell: 191 chars**

```
import Data.List
h [] = ' '
h (x:_) = x
t [] = []
t ([]:x) = t (" ":x)
t ((x:y):z) = takeWhile (any (/= ' ')).map (dropWhileEnd (== ' '))$(x:map h z):t (y:[s |(_:s)<-z])
m = (unlines.t.lines)
```

Comment: It's usually good to add some explanatory text. It helps those who don't know the language to decide to vote you up. :)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>177</s> 173 bytes

```
s=>{l=s.split`
`.sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length)[0];for(i=0,t=[];i<l.length;i++){t[i]=s.split`
`.map(i=>i+" ".repeat(l.length-i.length)).map(j=>j[i]).join``}return t.join`
`}
```

```
s=>{l=s.split`\n`.sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length)[0];for(i=0,t=[];i<l.length;i++){t[i]=s.split`\n`.map(i=>i+" ".repeat(l.length-i.length)).map(j=>j[i]).join``;}return t.join`\n`}
```

If you can help me shorten this up, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>95+0</s> <s>108+1</s> 110 bytes

```php
foreach($input as $s)for($y=0;~$c=$s[$y];)$r[$y++].=$c>"
"?$c:" ";echo rtrim(join("
",array_map(rtrim,$r)));
```

takes input from STDIN; breaks at the first empty line. Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ddd2e15cf2e6cdfe6ee88de76671df7990274dde).

Still trying to find something shorter than the additional rtrim to get rid of the second newline.

Comment: In general, I like this answer, but there are a number of issues; read the spec: "Your result must not have trailing whitespace on any line". Also, the rules for I/O are slightly ambiguous, but this isn't technically one of the allowed options, and this definitely isn't a complete program since you have to invoke the interpreter with non-default options.

Comment: Unless I am more rusty at PHP than I thought, the way you are calling `file(f)` will result in a warning being printed to stderr, which since you are using stdout as your output method is also not allowed. If there is a specific version of the PHP interpreter that no longer has this behviour(it used to IIRC), then please specify or correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The simplest correction to everything but the endline issue that I can think of at the moment results in 8 additional characters. The simplest solution for the endline issue I can think of adds an extra 7. That still makes it by far the shortest PHP entry.

Comment: @TimSeguine 1) `-n` (no config file) tells the compiler to run with the default options. 2) The rules are ridiculous, but I´ll look into resolving the "issues" anyway.

Comment: @TimSeguine ... and the default options include `error_reporting=E_ALL&~E_NOTICE` (`undefined constant "f", assuming string` is a notice, not a warning)

Comment: If you don't like the rules then don't post an answer, it's that simple. Being able to follow a spec exactly is an important part of being a good engineer. I have relatively little interest in this site anymore, so any time spent on arguing about the spec is time I consider wasted.

Comment: @TimSeguine Sorry. let me rephrase: not "ridiculous" but "unusual". But ok. I´d love to see your solutions to the issues.

Comment: I have a few ideas for how to shave characters, but I don't have time to try any out for now. What I see is no reason to use $argn instead of STDIN for the purpose of the challenge. And is the `$x=>` important? looks like just a waste of 4 chars to me. If you are curious, the rules were an attempt at leveling the playing field with code golfing specific languages. How successful I was in that goal is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 81 bytes

```perl
chomp(@a=<>);say((join"",map{(substr$_,0,1,"")||$"}@a)=~s/\s+$//r)while"@a"=~/\S/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcG7DoIwFADQna9oGoY2VgoDk6IkTg5OOpKYqzahhj7SW6JE5NOt53gVhjqle@@MZy002x3fIEyMPZ22lAoD/sNwvGEM@VWUohKU8nnO6bcF3iwoO1zlUgb@6vWgaAu0WWR3likdCRgCJKp3LLJLAIveoSJGFdkBLJncSB6O6Lj/OR@1s5jWp7ooq/IP)

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 205 bytes

```lua
L={}C=0 R=io.read I=R()while I~=""do L[C]=I C=C+1 I=R()end M=0 for i=0,C-1,1 do if#L[i]>M then M=#L[i]end end for i=1,M,1 do for j=0,C-1,1 do io.write(L[j]:sub(i,i)==""and" "or L[j]:sub(i,i))end print()end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4xC4MwEIX3/IojXZRa0bVwXTIJuriKQyQRT8SUGJFS2r9uo9LB493weN@DN8xyXXN8fwQmUCKZ2GqpIMMyCJeOBg3ZFzlXBvJK1JiBQHFNj1yPCgpfa40FwiQStzRKwaPUXvKK6kcBrtOjZ3a74dsfeBoVB7zZ/tQ28WLJ6SCv@vo@zU1AEYXoV8hRceCePyX7jqel0e2T1tV1NDEvyZyeHHvp/zHZMPYD)

Ungolfed

```lua
lines={}
count=0
R=io.read
input=R()

-- reads input in until an empty line is found
-- lines are added to the lines table
while input~="" do
    lines[count]=input
    count=count+1;
    input=R()
end

-- find the length of the longest string
max_len=0
for i=0,count-1,1 do
    if #lines[i]>max_len then
        max_len=#lines[i]
    end
end

-- loop through each character of each string
for i=1,max_len,1 do
    for j=0,count-1,1 do
        -- print the string's next character
        -- or a space if there is not another character
        if lines[j]:sub(i,i)=="" then--this if statement is golfed into a
            io.write(" ")            --pseudo-ternary statement in the golfed version
        else
            io.write(lines[j]:sub(i,i))
        end
    end
    print()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 2 bytes

```
.t
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.t&input=%5B%22I+am+a+text.%22%2C+%22Transpose+me.%22%2C+%22Can+you+do+it%3F%22%5D&debug=0)

Performs the built in transpose function on an input list, outputting a list of lines.

---

### Pyth, 7 bytes

```
V.t.zdN
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V.t.zdN&input=I+am+a+text.%0ATranspose+me.%0ACan+you+do+it%3F&debug=0)

The above program, modified to use the input and output format specified in the challenge.

Comment: From the spec: *"Your result **must not** have trailing whitespace **on any line.**"* - it caught me out as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 154 bytes

Takes input from `[A1]` and outputs to the console.

```vb
x=Split([A1],vbLf):u=UBound(x):For i=0To u:l=Len(x(u)):m=IIf(m>l,m,l):Next:For i=1To m:For j=0To u:s=s+Mid(x(j)&String(m,32),i,1):Next:?RTrim(s):s="":Next
```

#### Ungolfed

```vb
x=Split([A1],vbLf)              ''  Split input by lines
u=UBound(x)                     ''  Get number of lines
For i=0To u                     ''  Iterate over lines
l=Len(x(u))                     ''  Get length of line `i`
m=IIf(m>l,m,l)                  ''  Compare to max length; Store Max
Next                            ''  Loop
For i=1To m                     ''  Iterate over chars in line
For j=0To u                     ''  Iterate over lines
s=s+Mid(x(j)&String(m,32),i,1)  ''  Append `i`th char of `j`th line to `s` 
Next                            ''  Loop
?RTrim(s)                       ''  Remove right whitespace, print
s=""                            ''  Reset `s`
Next                            ''  Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 43 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{"\n"/{(-+/&\32=|x)_x}@'+(|/#:'x)$x:"\n"\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWikmT0m/WkNXW18txtjItqZCM76i1kFdW6NGX9lKvUJTpcIKpCSmotaaK8HAKk0hTclTITFXIVGhJLWiRC8mL6QoMa@4IL84VSE3Fch1TsxTqMwvVUjJV8gssVey/v8fAA)

**Explanation:**

Break on newlines, pad lines to same lengths, transpose, trim trailing whitespace and join on newlines. Feels like there has to be an easier way...

```
{"\n"/{(-+/&\32=|x)_x}@'+(|/#:'x)$x:"\n"\x} / the solution
{                                         } / lambda
                                         x  / input x
                                    "\n"\   / split (\) on "\n"
                                  x:        / save as x
                                 $          / pad right with left
                         (      )           / do this together
                            #:'x            / count (#:) each (') x
                          |/                / max
                        +                   / transpose
      {              }@'                    / apply (@) lambda to each (')
                    x                       / input x
                   _                        / drop
       (          )                         / do this together
                |x                          / reverse (|) x
             32=                            / equal to ASCII 32 aka " "
           &\                               / min
         +/                                 / sum
        -                                   / negate
 "\n"/                                      / join (/) on "\n"
```

Comment: A couple bytes can be saved by using `{(-(|^x)?0)_x}` to trim the trailing whitespace.