# Interlace strings

Tags: code-golf, string

Your challenge is to write a program or function that, when given two strings of equal length, swaps every other character and outputs/returns the resulting strings in either order.

### Examples

```
"Hello," "world!" --> "Hollo!" "werld,"
"code" "golf" --> "codf" "gole"
"happy" "angry" --> "hnpry" "aagpy"
"qwerty" "dvorak" --> "qvertk" "dworay"
"1, 2, 3" "a, b, c" --> "1, b, 3" "a, 2, c"
"3.141592653589" "2.718281828459" --> "3.111291623489" "2.748582858559"
"DJMcMayhem" "trichoplax" --> "DrMcMoylex" "tJichapham"
"Doorknob" "Downgoat" --> "Doonkoot" "Dowrgnab"
"Halloween" "Challenge" --> "Hhlloeegn" "Caallwnee"
```

### Rules

- The strings will only contain ASCII chars (32-126).
- The strings will always be the same length, and will never be empty.
- You may accept input in any suitable format: separate parameters, items in an array, separated by one or more newlines, even concatenated. The only restriction is that one string must come fully before the other (e.g. `a1\nb2\nc3` for `"abc", "123"` is invalid).
- The output may be **in either order** (i.e. you can start swapping from the first or the second char), and in any valid format mentioned above. (2-item array, separated by newline(s), concatenated, etc.)

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes for each language wins.**

Comment: +1 for `DrMcMoylex`. :D

Comment: "Dowrgnab" anagrams to "Downgrab" ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: You should point out explicitly that the "in either order" rule means swapping can begin from the first character or the second.

Comment: @DrMcMoylex Take the *code, golf* example. If we swap starting from second character, we get: c**o**d**f**, g**o**l**e**. Starting from first character: **g**o**l**e, **c**o**d**f.

Answer (score 14):

### Haskell, 37 bytes

```haskell
l=(,):flip(,):l
(unzip.).zipWith3($)l
```

Zips the two strings, alternately swapping the characters, then unzips them.

A 37-byte recursive alternative:

```haskell
(a:b)?(c:d)=a:d?b
e?_=e
a%b=(a?b,b?a)
```

Answer (score 10):

### Python, 42 bytes with [I/O golfing](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9501/20260)

```python
def f(a,b):a[1::2],b[1::2]=b[1::2],a[1::2]
```

Swaps every other character of the two lists. Takes as input two [lists of characters](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2216/20260), and outputs [by modifying them](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4942/20260).

```python
l=list('cat')
m=list('dog')    
print l,m

def f(a,b):a[1::2],b[1::2]=b[1::2],a[1::2]

f(l,m)
print l,m
```

gives

```python
['c', 'a', 't'] ['d', 'o', 'g']
['c', 'o', 't'] ['d', 'a', 'g']
```

Comment: That's clever. Do you see the input/output formats as too flexible?

Comment: @ETHproductions Not sure, it might be mostly Python-specific that lists are so much manipulable than strings.

Answer (score 8):

## Vim, <s>18</s>, 17 bytes

```
qqyljvPkvPll@qq@q
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=cXF5bGp2UGt2UGxsQHFxQHE&input=REpNY01heWhlbQp0cmljaG9wbGF4)

This uses the V interpreter because of backwards compatibility. Input comes in this format:

```
string1
string2
```

Explanation:

```
 qq                 " Start recording in register 'q'
   yl               " Yank one letter
     j              " Move down a row
      vP            " Swap the yanked letter and the letter under the cursor
        k           " Move back up a row
         vP         " Swap the yanked letter and the letter under the cursor
           ll       " Move two letters to the right. This will throw an error once we're done
             @q     " Call macro 'q' recursively
               q    " Stop recording.
                @q  " Start the recursive loop
```

Comment: Cut two letters by using `x` instead of `yl` and then jus `P` instead of second `vP`: `lqqxjvPkPll@qq@q`

Comment: @lukasz I had tried that initially, but for whatever reason, that runs it too many times and swaps the last letters when it shouldn't. I'll look into it some more though

Comment: Works for me http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=bHFxeWxqdlBrdlBsbEBxcUBx&input=REpNY01heWhlbQp0cmljaG9wbGF4

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier That link has the same code as I posted. Did you hit the `[save]` button? Either way, [it's not working for me](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=bHFxeGp2UGtQbGxAcXFAcQ&input=REpNY01heWhlbQp0cmljaG9wbGF4). The real reason why is because when you `x` the last character on the line, it moves your cursor to the left, messing up the placement of the swap.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
øvyNFÀ}})ø
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w7h2eU5Gw4B9fSnDuA&input=WyJIYWxsb3dlZW4iLCJDaGFsbGVuZ2UiXQ)

**Explanation**

input = `["code", "golf"]` used as example.

```
ø             # zip strings into list of pairs
              # STACK: ['cg', 'oo', 'dl', 'ef']
 vy           # for each pair
   NFÀ        # rotate left index times
      }}      # end-if, end-loop
              # STACK: 'cg, 'oo', 'dl', 'fe'
        )ø    # wrap in list and zip
              # OUTPUT: ['codf', 'gole']
```

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 41 bytes

```
(a:b)#(c:d)=(a,c):d#b
_#_=[]
(unzip.).(#)
```

Returns a pair with the strings. Usage example: `( (unzip.).(#) ) "Hello," "world!"`-> `("Hollo!","werld,")`.

Simple recursive approach: take the first char of each string as a pair and append a recursive call with the (rest of the) strings swapped. `unzip` makes a pair of lists out of the list of pairs.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 48 bytes

Bytecount includes 47 bytes of code and `-p` flag.

```pl
say<>=~s%.\K(.)%"s/.{$-[0]}\\K(.)/$1/;\$1"%geer
```

Run with `-p` and `-E` flag. Expect each string on a different line :

```
perl -pE 'say<>=~s%.\K(.)%"s/.{$-[0]}\\K(.)/$1/;\$1"%geer' <<< "Hello
World"
```

**Explanations** :

`-p` : capture input in `$_` and prints it at the end. (to get and print the first string)
`<>` : get a line of input. (to get the second string).
`=~` : apply a regex to `<>` : `s%%%geer`, where thanks to `r` the modified string is returned (and then printed thanks to `say`).
The regex :
`.\K(.)` finds two characters, and will replace the second one with the result of the evaluation of this code `"s/.{$-[0]}\\K(.)/$1/;\$1"` :
The first part, `s/.{$-[0]}\\K(.)/$1/` applies a regex to `$_` : `.{$-[0]}` skips the first characters to get to the same point as the outer regex (since `$-[0]` contains the index of the first capture group, so in that case the index of the characters to substitute), and then we capture a char with `(.)` and replace it with the character of the outer regex (`$1`). And then we add `$1` so the result of `"s/.{$-[0]}\\K(.)/$1/;\$1"` is the character we captured in the inner regex.
You may have noticed that `$1` refer to the character we want to replace in both strings (so two different characters), so we play with `/ee` modifier of the regex which evaluates the right side of the regex twice : the first one will substitute only the `$1` that isn't preceded by the `\`.

Answer (score 5):

### Python, 55 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[(-~len(a)/2*s)[::len(a)+1]for s in a+b,b+a]
```

Slicing!

58 bytes:

```python
def f(a,b):n=len(a);print[(s*n)[:n*n:n+1]for s in a+b,b+a]
```

---

**64 bytes:**

```python
f=lambda a,b,s='',t='':a and f(b[1:],a[1:],s+a[0],t+b[0])or[s,t]
```

Recursively accumulates the characters of the two strings into `s` and `t`, and outputs the pair of them at the end. The alternation is done by switching the input strings each recursive call. Outputting a space-separated string was the same length:

```python
lambda a,b,s='',t=' ':a and f(b[1:],a[1:],s+a[0],t+b[0])or s+t
```

This narrowly beat out a different recursive strategy of alternately taking characters from each string, with each of the two possible strings as the first one. (65 bytes)

```python
g=lambda a,b:a and a[0]+g(b[1:],a[1:])
lambda a,b:(g(a,b),g(b,a))
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
żṚż¥/
```

Input is as separate arguments, output is concatenated.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xbzhuZrFvMKlLw&input=&args=RG9vcmtub2I+RG93bmdvYXQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xbzhuZrFvMKlLwrDpzIvWQ&input=&args=IkhlbGxvLCIsICJ3b3JsZCEiLCAiY29kZSIsICJnb2xmIiwgImhhcHB5IiwgImFuZ3J5IiwgInF3ZXJ0eSIsICJkdm9yYWsiLCAiMSwgMiwgMyIsICJhLCBiLCBjIiwgIjMuMTQxNTkyNjUzNTg5IiwgIjIuNzE4MjgxODI4NDU5IiwgIkRKTWNNYXloZW0iLCAidHJpY2hvcGxheCIsICJEb29ya25vYiIsICJEb3duZ29hdCIsICJIYWxsb3dlZW4iLCAiQ2hhbGxlbmdlIg).

#### How it works

```
żṚż¥/  Main link. Left argument: s (string). Right argument: t (string)

ż      Zipwith; yield the array of pairs of corresponding characters of s and t.
   ¥   Combine the two links to the left into a dyadic chain:
 Ṛ         Reverse the chain's left argument.
  ż        Zip the result with the chain's right argument.
    /  Reduce the return value of the initial ż by the quicklink Ṛż¥.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*Thanks to ETHproductions for 1 byte off!*

```
"@X@YS&h
```

Input is a 2D array containing the two strings, such as: `['Halloween'; 'Challenge']`. The output strings are in reverse order.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkBYQFlTJmg&input=WydIYWxsb3dlZW4nOyAnQ2hhbGxlbmdlJ10)

#### Explanation

```
        % Input 2D array implicitly
"       % For each column
  @     %   Push current column
  X@    %   Push iteration index, starting at 1
  YS    %   Circularly shift the column by that amount
  &h    %   Concatenate horizontally with (concatenated) previous columns
        % End implicitly
        % Display implicitly
```

---

### Old version: 9 bytes

```
tZyP:1&YS
```

#### Explanation

```
        % Take input implicitly
t       % Duplicate 
        % STACK: ['Halloween'; 'Challenge'], ['Halloween'; 'Challenge']
Zy      % Size
        % STACK: ['Halloween'; 'Challenge'], [2 9]
P       % Flip array
        % STACK: ['Halloween'; 'Challenge'], [9 2]
:       % Range. Uses first element of the array as input
        % STACK: ['Halloween'; 'Challenge'], [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
1&YS    % Circularly shift each column by those amounts respectively
        % STACK: [Caallwnee';'Hhlloeegn']
        % Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 6 bytes

Thanks to *Dennis* for saving 2 bytes!

```
Zṙ"J$Z
```

Uses the [**Jelly** encoding](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=WuG5mSJKJFo&input=&args=IkhlbGxvIiwgIldvcmxkIg)

Comment: You can use `ṙ"J$` instead of `Ėṙ@/€`. Also, separating the string is not required, so you can drop the `Y`.

Comment: @Dennis Ahh, that's neat. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 12 bytes

```
lòyljvPkvPll
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=bMOyeWxqdlBrdlBsbA&input=REpNY01heWhlbQp0cmljaG9wbGF4)

Nothing too interesting, just a direct port of my vim answer so I can compete with (but not beat) 05AB1E.

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 9 bytes

```
,Fo2%I_(,
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%2CFo2%25I_%28%2C&input=%22code%22%2C+%22golf%22)

```
          - o = 0
,         -   transpose(input)
 F     (  -  for i in ^:
  o2%     -    (o++ %2)
     I_   -   if ^: i = reverse(i)
        , - transpose(^)
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 51 <s>54</s>

*Edit* 3 bytes saved thx @Neil

Function with array input/output

```js
p=>p.map((w,i)=>w.replace(/./g,(c,j)=>p[i+j&1][j]))
```

I like this one more, but it's 55 (2 strings in input, array in output)

```js
(a,b)=>[...a].reduce(([p,q],c,i)=>[q+c,p+b[i]],['',''])
```

**Test**

```js
f=
p=>p.map((w,i)=>w.replace(/./g,(c,j)=>p[i+j&1][j]))

function go() {
  var a=A.value, b=B.value
  if (a.length == b.length)
    O.textContent = f([a,b]).join('\n')
  else
    O.textContent = '- different length -'
    
}

go()
```

```html
<input id=A value='Hello,'><input id=B value='world!'>
<button onclick='go()'>go</button><pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: `replace` saves you 3 bytes: `p=>p.map((w,i)=>w.replace(/./g,(c,j)=>a[i+j&1][j]))`.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
C.e_FbkC
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=C.e_FbkC&input=%5B%22Hello%2C%22%2C%20%22world%21%22%5D&debug=0)

Transposes the words, reverses each pair of letters 'current index'-times, transpose again.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

```
f=([c,...s],[d,...t],o="",p="")=>c?f(t,s,o+c,p+d):[o,p]
```

I wanted to do something clever with using regexp to replace alternate characters but that ended up taking <s>67</s> 57 bytes:

```
a=>a.map((s,i)=>a[+!i].replace(/.(.?)/g,(_,c,j)=>s[j]+c))
```

Comment: Nice. I had `f=([a,...A],[b,...B])=>a?[a+f(B,A)[0],b+f(A,B)[0]]:[""]` for the same length.

Comment: I hoped to do a lot better, but no way, just 1 less. Time to post a non recursive answer

Comment: @edc65 Nice idea to use `map`, it shaved 10 bytes off my regexp answer. Still too long though.

Answer (score 2):

### Java, <strike>132</strike> <strike>103</strike> 100 bytes

*Thanks to  Kevin Cruijssen for suggesting returning the array (among other improvements) and saving 29 bytes! Also Olivier Grégoire for 3 bytes!*

```
char[]c(char[]s,int l){for(int o=l;o-->0;)if(o%2>0){char t=s[o];s[o]=s[l+o+1];s[l+o+1]=t;}return s;}
```

Called like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(c("Hello,world!".toCharArray(), 5)); // 5 is the length of each "String"
}
```

Output:

`Hollo,werld!`

Takes advantage of the fact that input can basically be formatted in any way (in this case, a single char array of Strings that are delimited by a comma), and pretty lenient output rules as well.

Comment: Hi, original input format you've got there. You can golf it some more though: `char[]c(char[]s,int l){for(int o=l,t;o-->0;)if(l%2>0){t=s[l];s[l]=s[l+o+1];s[l+o+1]=(char)t;}return s;}` (**103 bytes**) with the output being returned instead of printed directly. Example input: `System.out.println(c("Hello,world!".toCharArray(), 5));`; Example output: `Hollo,werld!`.

Comment: True enough, I hadn't considered just returning the char array for some reason. That's great!

Comment: The result should be `Hollo!werld,` and not `Hollo,werld!` (the punctuation is incorrect). I believe this can be fixed with a input value of 6 instead of 5.

Comment: Since you cast `t` to `char`, why don't you declare it in the for loop directly as a `char`? You'd spare a few bytes doing so.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't declare the char within the for-loop initializer, but you inspired me to check if declaring the char separately would be shorter than the cast and it indeed is by 1 byte.

Comment: I didn't mean in the for loop initializer, but when you first *use* `t`: `char t=s[l];`. You don't use it elsewhere. For a concrete example, look at my own answer.

Comment: Ah okay I misunderstood you. You're right, that saves 3 bytes!

Comment: Suggest `s[o]^=s[l-~o];s[o]^=s[l-~o]^=s[o];` instead of `char t=s[o];s[o]=s[l+o+1];s[l+o+1]=t;`

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 40 bytes

Includes +1 for `-n`

Give strings as lines on STDIN

```
interlace.pl
hello
world
^D
```

`interlace.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
s/./${1&$.+pos}[pos]=$&/seg}{print@0,@1
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 82 bytes

```
param($a,$b)$i=0;[char[]]$a|%{$c+=($_,$b[$i])[$i%2];$d+=($b[$i],$_)[$i++%2]};$c;$d
```

<s>Still golfing...</s> Nope. Can't seem to golf this down any without using a regex like other answers (boo on copying algorithms).

So we take `$a` and `$b` as strings, set index `$i` to `0`, cast `$a` as a `char`-array, and send it through a loop `|%{...}`. Each iteration, we're string-concatenating onto `$c` and `$d` by indexing into an array-select (i.e., so it alternates back and forth). Then, we leave `$c` and `$d` on the pipeline, and output via implicit `Write-Output` happens at program completion.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 79 Bytes

```
for(;$i<=strlen(($a=$argv)[1]);$y.=$a[2-$i%2][$i++])echo$a[1+$i%2][+$i]??" $y";
```

Previous Version PHP, 82 Bytes

```
for(;$i<strlen(($a=$argv)[1]);$y.=$a[2-$i%2][$i++])$x.=$a[1+$i%2][$i];echo"$x $y";
```

Comment: `for(...)echo$a[1+$i%2][$i];echo" $y";` (-2)

Comment: building off of Titus's comment `for(;$i<=strlen(($a=$argv)[1]);$y.=$a[2-$i%2][$i++])echo$a[1+$i%2][$i]??" $y";` is a further -2, though it requires php 7

Comment: @user59178 nice but you need 1 Byte more

Comment: do you? it works for me, you just get a `Notice: String offset cast occurred in Command line code on line 1`

Comment: @user59178 Yes to print the first letter of the first word

Comment: as I say, it works fine for me, there are just 3 notices between that first letter and the rest of the output so if you don't have error reporting turned off it's easy to miss.

Comment: @user59178 notices are still (and I guess always will be) turned off by default

Answer (score 1):

## C, 124 bytes

```
main(c,v)char**v;{char a[99],b[99];for(c=0;v[1][c]^0;++c){a[c]=v[1+c%2][c];b[c]=v[2-c%2][c];}a[c]=0;b[c]=0;puts(a);puts(b);}
```

Call with:

```
program.exe string1 string2
```

String length is limited to 98 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>64</s> 61 bytes

```
@(x)reshape(x((t=1:end)+(2*mod(t,2)-1).*(mod(t-1,4)>1)),2,[])
```

Anonymous function that inputs a 2D char array with each string in a row, and produces the output in the same format.

[Try it at Ideone](http://ideone.com/8WZ5EG).

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 208 bytes

```
(let((sl string->list)(ls list->string)(r reverse))(let p((s(sl s))(t(sl t))(u'())(v'())(g #t))(if(null? s)
(list(ls(r u))(ls(r v)))(p(cdr s)(cdr t)(cons(car(if g s t))u)(cons(car(if g t s))v)(if g #f #t)))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s t)
  (let ((sl string->list)                ; create short names of fns
        (ls list->string)
        (r reverse))
    (let loop ((s (sl s))                ; convert string to lists
               (t (sl t))
               (u '())                   ; create empty new lists
               (v '())
               (g #t))                   ; a boolean flag
      (if (null? s)                      ; if done, return new lists converted back to strings
          (list (ls (r u))
                (ls (r v)))
          (loop (rest s)
                (rest t)                 ; keep adding chars to new lists alternately
                (cons (first (if g s t)) u) 
                (cons (first (if g t s)) v)
                (if g #f #t))            ; alternate the boolean flag
          ))))
```

Testing:

```
(f "abcdef" "123456")
```

Output:

```
'("a2c4e6" "1b3d5f")
```

Above is recursive version.

Iterative version:

```
(let*((sl string->list)(ls list->string)(r reverse)(s(sl s))(t(sl t))(l'())(k'())(p(λ(a b g)(set! l(cons(if g a b)l))
(set! k(cons(if g b a)k)))))(for((i s)(j t)(n(in-naturals)))(p i j(if(= 0(modulo n 2)) #t #f)))(list(ls(r l))(ls(r k))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s t)
  (let* ((sl string->list)              ; create short form of fn names
         (ls list->string)
         (r reverse)

         (s (sl s))                     ; convert strings to lists
         (t (sl t))

         (l '())                        ; create empty lists for new sequences
         (k '())

         (p (λ(a b g)                   ; fn to add chars to one or other list
              (set! l (cons (if g a b) l))
              (set! k (cons (if g b a) k)))))

    (for ((i s)(j t)(n (in-naturals)))  ; loop with both strings
          (p i j                        ; add to new lists alternately
             (if (= 0 (modulo n 2)) #t #f)))

    (list (ls (r l))                  ; convert reversed lists to strings
          (ls (r k)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 120 characters (+3 for -v1 flag)

Line split in 2 for readability:

```
#P::((invoke P "map" (js-bridge #W,I::(replace W (regex "." "g")
     (js-bridge #C,J::(index (index P (& (+ I J) 1)) J))))))
```

Requires the `-v1` flag to `run.js` as some functions are not yet part of the standard library.

Sample usage:

```
(
    (def f #P::((invoke P "map" (js-bridge #W,I::(replace W (regex "." "g")
                (js-bridge #C,J::(index (index P (& (+ I J) 1)) J)))))))
    (print (f (list "Hello," "world!")))
)
```

This sort of highlights that I haven't spent enough time on the standard library. Having to use `js-bridge/1` twice and the long regex form, as well as invoking map using `invoke/*` all contribute to this being much longer than it needs to be.

Time to work on my standard library more I think.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```c
f(char*a,char*b,char*c){while(*c++=*a++,*c++=*b++);}
```

Assumes output `c` has already the desired length.

Usage:

```c
main(){
 char a[]="123456";
 char b[]="abcdef";
 char c[sizeof(a)+sizeof(b)-1];
 f(a,b,c);
 puts(c);
```

}

If you insist on creating the output, here is a **91 bytes** solution:

```c
char*g(char*a,char*b){char*c=malloc(2*strlen(a)),*d=c;while(*c++=*a++,*c++=*b++);return d;}
```

Usage:

```c
main(){
 char a[]="123456";
 char b[]="abcdef";
 puts(g(a,b));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>8</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
yÈéY
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ecjpWQ&input=WyJIZWxsbywiLCJ3b3JsZCEiXQotUQ)

```
yÈéY     :Implicit input of array U
y        :Transpose
 È       :Map each element at 0-based index Y then transpose back
  éY     :  Rotate right Y times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/home/), 32 bytes

```
{?[;x;y]each(not\)count[x]#10b}.
```

## k, 24 bytes

```
{?[;x;y]'(~:\)(#x)#10b}.
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 150 bytes

I used the typical omissions of header files and `main()`'s return type and return statement. It throws a warning, but compiles without issue. I also used a GCC-specific trick that allows array declarations with variable expressions.

The program expects the strings from the command line, and as such, the program should be run with `./a.out string1 string2`.

```
main(int a,char**v){int x=strlen(v[1]);char s[x],t[x],c;strcpy(s,v[1]);strcpy(t,v[2]);for(a=0;a<x;++a)if(a%2)c=s[a],s[a]=t[a],t[a]=c;puts(s),puts(t);}
```

Or more legibly,

```
main(int a,char**v){
    int x=strlen(v[1]);
    char s[x],t[x],c;
    strcpy(s,v[1]);strcpy(t,v[2]);
    for(a=0;a<x;++a)
        if(a%2)c=s[a],s[a]=t[a],t[a]=c;
    puts(s),puts(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 51 bytes

Takes input as an array of two arrays of characters, with output in the same format. The function simply constructs the new array using a (mod 2) operation.

```
Table[#[[Mod[j+i,2]+1,j]],{i,2},{j,Length@#[[1]]}]&
```

Answer (score 0):

## QBasic 4.5, 172 bytes

Ouch, this one gets painful with the ol' QBasic...

```
DEFSTR A-D:INPUT A,B
IF LEN(A)MOD 2=1 THEN A=A+" ":B=B+" "
FOR x=1 TO LEN(A) STEP 2
C=C+MID$(A,x,1)+MID$(B,x+1,1):D=D+MID$(B,x,1)+MID$(A,x+1,1):NEXT:?RTRIM$(C),RTRIM$(D)
```

Fun fact: Using `DEFSTR` saved more bytes than it cost because now I could use `A` instead of `a$`.

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ?usp=sharing), 112 bytes

QBIC can streamline a lot of the QBasic boilerplate, but the main `MID$`engine still needs to be done in QBasic because QBIC lacks a substring-function. Still, saves me 60 bytes.

```
;;_LA|~a%2=1|A=A+@ | B=B+C][1,a,2|X=X+$MID$(A$,b,1)+MID$(B$,b+1,1):Y$=Y$+MID$(B$,b,1)+MID$(A$,b+1,1)|]?_tX|,_tY|
```

Comment: `MIND$` => `MIN$` in text.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 68 bytes

```
(a,b)->{for(int i=a.length;--i>0;){char t=a[--i];a[i]=b[i];b[i]=t;}}
```

### Ungolfed and testing

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public class Main {

  static BiConsumer<char[], char[]> func = (left, right) -> {
      for (int i = left.length; --i > 0;) {
        char temp = left[--i];
        left[i] = right[i];
        right[i] = temp;
      }
    };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("Hello,","world!", "Hollo!", "werld,");
    test("code", "golf", "codf", "gole");
    test("happy", "angry", "hnpry", "aagpy");
  }

  private static void test(String left, String right, String x, String y) {
    char[] leftChars = left.toCharArray();
    char[] rightChars = right.toCharArray();
    func.accept(leftChars, rightChars);
    Collection mixed = Arrays.asList(new String(leftChars), new String(rightChars));
    if (mixed.containsAll(Arrays.asList(x, y))) {
      System.out.println("OK");
    } else {
      System.out.printf("NOK: %s, %s -> %s%n", left, right, mixed);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### APL, 12

```
{↓(⍳⍴⊃⍵)⊖↑⍵}
```

Explanation: {...} defines a function, ⍵ is the right argument.
The take (↑) creates a matrix out of the two strings, then rotates each column (⊖) n times, where n is the part in parenthesis (⍳⍴⊃⍵). That's defined as the iota of the length of the first argument. (Ex: length=5 ==> 1 2 3 4 5).
So first column is rotated once, second twice (getting back to original positions), third column three times, etc...

Try it at [tryapl.org](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2193%28%u2373%u2374%u2283%u2375%29%u2296%u2191%u2375%7D%20%27happy%27%20%27angry%27&run)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 85 bytes

```
(_:String)zip(_:String)zip(Stream from 0)map{case(t,z)=>if(z%2==0)t else t.swap}unzip
```

take an anonymous string parameter, zip it with another string parameter, zip it with an stream of natural numbers, swap every second tuple of chars and unzip to get a tuple of sequences of chars

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3, <s>129</s> 107 bytes

```
func c(n:inout[String],b:inout[String]){
for(j,c)in n.enumerated(){
if j&1<1{n[j]=b[j];b[j]=c}}
print(n,b)}
```

**Original**

The function receives two arrays of strings as parameters assuming both have same length, as follows:

```
c(n:["c", "o", "d", "e"],b:["g", "o", "l", "f"])
```

Produces following output

```
codf gole
```

**Edit 1:**

Get rid of the internal tuple and change the parameters of the function to be `inout`. Instead of string concatenation manipulate the parameters directly.

Example input:

```
var a:Array<String> = ["c", "o", "d", "e"]
var b:Array<String> = ["g", "o", "l", "f"]

c(n:&a,b:&b)
```

Ouput changed to be array of strings as in:

`["g", "o", "l", "e"] ["c", "o", "d", "f"]`

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
Tz*İ_ze
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P6RK68iG@KrU////e6Tm5OTr/A/PL8pJUQQA)

Outputs are reversed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 11 bytes

```
ir>ir[<o>o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zyC6zKNom3y4/9v//5PyUVK70/Jw0AA)

This takes the two strings on separate input lines, and outputs the interlaced strings concatenated together.  At a high level...  It reads the two strings onto separate stacks, then just loops printing the top the each stack.

```
ir          - read first string onto the stack, reverse it
  >ir       - switch to new stack, read second string and reverse it
     [    ] - loop until the stack is empty
      <o    - switch to first stack and print a char
        >o  - switch to the second stack and print a char
```