# This is my pillow

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

...will you help me immortalize it?

[image]

I've had this pillow a few years now, and apparently it's time to get rid of it. Can you please write a function or program, that I can bring with me and use to recreate this pillow whenever I want to reminisce a bit.

It must work with no input arguments.

The output should look exactly like this (trailing newlines and spaces are OK).

```
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
```

This is code golf, so the shortest code in bytes win!

---

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=98701,OVERRIDE_USER=31516;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: I'm somewhat disappointed that the pattern isn't a little more complex, to represent the different line thicknesses of the pillow.

Comment: @Sparr I tried, but I didn't manage to make it look good using only ASCII characters. Figured this was close enough :)

Comment: I'd have just added spaces

Comment: 'apparently' :P

Comment: Now you can buy a blank pillow and print the winner snippet on it.

Comment: @coredump Nah, I wouldn't  like to have an 05AB1E pillow, better do its output... except if it was 05AB1E for "Good night, good sleep."

Comment: Related: [Make me a blanket!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99023/make-me-a-blanket)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 15 bytes

Code:

```
„/\5×{4Å6×»6F=R
```

Explanation:

```
„/\               # Push the string "/\"
   5×             # Repeat 5 times: "/\/\/\/\/\"
     {            # Sort, resulting in: "/////\\\\\"
      4Å6         # Create a list of 6's with length 4: [6, 6, 6, 6]
         ×        # Vectorized string multiplication
          »       # Join by newlines
           6F     # Do the following six times..
             =    #   Print with a newline without popping
              R   #   Reverse the string
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCeL1w1w5d7NMOFNsOXwrs2Rj1S&input=)

Comment: Wow... two different takes, same byte count...

Answer (score 33):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 116 bytes

```
/a/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\///b/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\//A/aaaaa//B/bbbbb//C/ABABABABABAB
//D/BABABABABABA
/CCCCDDDDCCCCDDDDCCCCDDDD
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L2EvXFxcXFxcXFxcXFxcXFxcLy8vYi9cXFxcXFxcXFxcXFxcXFxcLy9BL2FhYWFhLy9CL2JiYmJiLy9DL0FCQUJBQkFCQUJBQgovL0QvQkFCQUJBQkFCQUJBCi9DQ0NDRERERENDQ0NEREREQ0NDQ0REREQ&input=)

**Edit**: the `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/` and `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\` are actually a *single* / and \, respectively.

**Edit**: -3 because I thought of removing `i`. I think this can't be further golfed.

Comment: Language name fits quite well

Answer (score 16):

### Python 2, 49 bytes

```python
b,a='\/';exec("print(a*5+b*5)*6;"*4+"a,b=b,a;")*6
```

Thanks to Mitch Schwartz for this clean method that saves a byte. The idea is to print four lines of `('\\'*5+'/'*5)*6`, swap the roles of slash and backslash, and then do that whole process 6 times. The two characters are stored in `a` and `b`, and swapped as `a,b=b,a`. The double-loop is double by generating the following code string, then executing it with `exec`:

```python
print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;a,b=b,a;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;a,b=b,a;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;a,b=b,a;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;a,b=b,a;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;a,b=b,a;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;print(a*5+b*5)*6;a,b=b,a;
```

---

**50 bytes:**

```python
s='/'*5+'\\'*5;exec("print s*6;"*4+"s=s[::-1];")*6
```

Makes the line string, prints it four times and then reverses it, then does that 6 times. Does so by generating the following code, then executing it:

```python
print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;s=s[::-1];print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;s=s[::-1];print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;s=s[::-1];print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;s=s[::-1];print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;s=s[::-1];print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;print s*6;s=s[::-1]
```

Here are some of the iterations of my golfing:

```python
for c in([1]*4+[-1]*4)*3:print('/'*5+'\\'*5)[::c]*6

for i in range(24):print('/\\'*5+'\/'*5)[i/4%2::2]*6

for c in range(24):print('\\'*5+'/'*5)[::(c&4)/2-1]*6

for i in range(24):print('/'*5+'\\'*5)[::1-i/4%2*2]*6

for c in([1]*4+[0]*4)*3:print('\/'*5+'/\\'*5)[c::2]*6

for c in([1]*4+[0]*4)*3:print('\/'[c]*5+'/\\'[c]*5)*6

for c in(['/\\']*4+['\/']*4)*3:print(c[0]*5+c[1]*5)*6

for c in([5]*4+[-5]*4)*3:print('/'*c+'\\'*5+'/'*-c)*6

print((('/'*5+'\\'*5)*6+'\n')*4+(('\\'*5+'/'*5)*6+'\n')*4)*3

for x in(['/'*5+'\\'*5]*4+['\\'*5+'/'*5]*4)*3:print x*6

a='/'*5;b='\\'*5
for x in([a+b]*4+[b+a]*4)*3:print x*6

s='/'*5+'\\'*5
for x in([s]*4+[s[::-1]]*4)*3:print x*6

s=('/'*5+'\\'*5)*9
exec("print s[:60];"*4+"s=s[5:];")*6

a='/'*5;b='\\'*5
for i in range(24):print[a+b,b+a][i/4%2]*6
```

Answer (score 14):

## 05AB1E, 15 bytes

```
„/\5×{R6×6FR4F=
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCeL1w1w5d7UjbDlzZGUjRGPQ&input=)

Explanation:

```
„/\             # Push "/\"
   5×           # Repeat string five times: "/\/\/\/\/\"
     {          # Sort: "/////\\\\\"
      R         # Reverse: "\\\\\/////
       6×       # Repeat string six times
         6F     # Repeat the following six times:
           R    #   Reverse
            4F  #   Repeat the following four times:
              = #     Print without popping
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding.

Answer (score 9):

## [Bubblegum](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 30 bytes

```
00000000: d307 8118 1020 9dc5 3544 3523 f8a4 b386  ..... ..5D5#....
00000010: aae6 e113 cfa3 f13c 1acf a3f1 0c00       .......<......
```

Obligatory Bubblegum answer.

Comment: Oh my goodness this language is awesome!

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>68</s> <s>60</s> 58 bytes

A recursive function. Several optimizations inspired from [chocochaos answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98720/58563).

```js
f=(n=1440)=>n--?'/\\'[n/240&1^n/5&1]+(n%60?'':`
`)+f(n):''
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n=1440)=>n--?'/\\'[n/240&1^n/5&1]+(n%60?'':`
`)+f(n):''

console.log(f());
```

Comment: I think you can leave out the first `&1` and save two bytes

Comment: @HenrikChristensen That would only work for `n < 480`. For `n >= 480`, we'd need parentheses: `(n/240^n/5)&1`.

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, <s>77</s> <s>70</s> 57 bytes

```
a%b=(<*[1..a]).([1..b]>>)
unlines$4%3$5%6<$>["/\\","\\/"]
```

Boring `concat`s and `replicate`s instead of playing with sines. Old was:

```
unlines[["\\/"!!(ceiling$sin(pi*x/5)*sin(pi*y/4))|x<-[0.5..59]]|y<-[0.5..23]]
```

Answer (score 7):

## Brainfuck, 140 bytes

```
>>>++++++++[>++++++>++++++++++++<<-]++++++++++>->----<<<<<+++[>++++[>++++++[>>.....>.....<<<-]>.<<-]++++[>++++++[>>>.....<.....<<-]>.<<-]<-]
```

:-D

Comment: Oh, look! The brainfuck solution is eight bytes shorter than the Java solution. Time for Java coders to switch to brainfuck...

Comment: Java strikes back

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>86</s> <s>80</s> <s>76</s> <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```py
for z in range(24):a=('/'*5+'\\'*5)*24;print((a+a[::-1])*3)[z*60:z*60+60]
```

Could probably golf a few more off it but it's a start.

**Edit**

Saved 6 by removing some unneeded brackets

Another 4 by using a single string and then reversing it

Thanks @Adnan. Had a late night last night and still not fully awake yet :p

-1 by moving the `*24` to the variable instead of using it twice

Comment: I believe that `*6*4` is the same as `*24`? :p

Answer (score 6):

## Brainfuck, 149 bytes

```
++++++++++>++++++[>++++++++<-]>->+++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>++>+++[<<++++[<<++++++[>.....>>.....<<<-]<.>>>-]++++[<<++++++[>>>.....<<.....<-]<.>>>-]>>-]
```

[The best interpreter EVAR!](//copy.sh/brainfuck?c=KysrKysrKysrKz4rKysrKytbPisrKysrKysrPC1dPi0-KysrKysrKysrWz4rKysrKysrKysrPC1dPisrPisrK1s8PCsrKytbPDwrKysrKytbPi4uLi4uPj4uLi4uLjw8PC1dPC4-Pj4tXSsrKytbPDwrKysrKytbPj4-Li4uLi48PC4uLi4uPC1dPC4-Pj4tXT4-LV0$)

This uses 6 cells (no wrapping, no modulo). Here they are:

```
0A 00 2F 00 5C 00
```

The `00` cells are used for the loop counters. Here, the counters are filled in with initial values:

```
0A 06 2F 04 5C 03
```

The leftmost counter is for the innermost loop (yes, I use nested loops of depth 3). Please note that the 4th cell (`04` counter) is used twice, once for `/////\\\\\...`, and once for `\\\\\/////...` every time.

`0A`, `2F` and `5C` are the characters `\n`, `/` and `\`, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

### Pyke, 16 bytes

```
"/\"6*5m*n+4*sD3
```

After update today that allowed `"` in string literals, 17 bytes

```
"/\\"6*5m*n+4*sD3
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%22%2F%5C%5C%226%2a5m%2an%2B4%2asD3)

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2.7 66 -> 56 -> 55 bytes

```
a="/"*5+"\\"*5;b=a[::-1];c=6*a+"\n";d=6*b+"\n";e=4*c+4*d;print e*3
```

new to code golfing

```
a="/"*5+"\\"*5;print(4*(6*a+"\n")+4*(6*a[::-1]+"\n"))*3
```

Thanks Stewie Griffin

Forgot a silly whitespace ;)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first answer :) Can you skip some of the intermediate variables? At least `d` and `e`, maybe more. I haven't tested this, but it should be close: `print(4*c+4*(6*b+"\n"))*3`. It's 5 bytes less.

Comment: 55 bytes: `a="/"*5+"\\"*5;print(4*(6*a+"\n")+4*(6*a[::-1]+"\n"))*3`

Answer (score 6):

## Brainfuck, 179 bytes

```
->++++++++[-<++++++>]++>+++++++++[-<++++++++++>]++++++++++>>>>+++[-<++++[-<++++++[-<+++++[-<<<.>>>]+++++[-<<.>>]>]<<.>>>]++++[-<++++++[-<+++++[-<<.>>]+++++[-<<<.>>>]>]<<.>>>]>]
```

I know this isn't the best score in the thread but I wanted to try out brainfuck and give this a try.

**Edit:**
I must've made an error while copypasting. This version should work

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Does not work for me. Browser hang up with [this interpreter](https://copy.sh/brainfuck), and personnal one show a non expected 5 line output: `/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\ ` four times, then infinite `\ `.

Comment: Yes, it works :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
/５４＊╬６×３＊
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=LyV1RkYxNSV1RkYxNCV1RkYwQSV1MjU2QyV1RkYxNiVENyV1RkYxMyV1RkYwQQ__,v=1)

Explanation:

```
/          push "/"
 54*       extend horizontally 5 times and vertically 4 times
    ╬      quad-palindromize with 0 overlap
     6×    repeat horizontally 6 times
       3*  and again vertically, 3 times
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 24 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
(60⍴5/0 4)⊖60/⍪∊3⍴⊂4/'/\'
```

Comment: `'/\'[4⌿5/2|+/¨⍳6 12]` (requires `⎕io←0`)

Comment: @ngn Why don't you just post it?

Comment: [done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98701/this-is-my-pillow/99585#99585)

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

Creates the following string (70 characters, one set more than needed) then alternates between sampling characters `0..59` and `5..64`from it.

```
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
```

**code and output**

```
24.times{|i|puts ((?/*5+?\\*5)*7)[i/4%2*5,60]}

/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
```

**interesting mistake (a 7 instead of a 5)**

```
24.times{|i|puts ((?/*5+?\\*5)*7)[i/4%2*7,60]}

/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\
```

Answer (score 5):

## C, <s>66</s> 61 bytes

5 bytes saved thanks to orlp.

Straightforward character by character printing. 61 characters per row, last is newline (ASCII 10) and the others alternate between `/`47 and `\` 92.

```
i;f(){for(i=1463;i;)putchar(i--%61?i%61/5+i/244&1?92:47:10);‌​}

//call like this
main(){f();}
```

Comment: 61 bytes: `i;f(){for(i=1463;i;)putchar(i--%61?i%61/5+i/244&1?92:47:10);}`.

Comment: @orlp thanks, I knew there had to be a better way with the `i--` but I didn´t have time to look for it.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
'\/'6:&+thK5&Y")
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J1wvJzY6Jit0aEs1JlkiKQ&input=)

#### Explanation

```
'\/'   % Push this string
6:     % Push array [1 2 3 4 5 6]
&+     % 6×6 matrix with all pair-wise additions from that array
th     % Concatenate horizontally with itself. Gives a 6×12 matrix
K      % Push 4
5      % Push 5
&Y"    % Repeat each entry of the matrix 4 times vertically and 5 times horizontally
       % This gives a 24×60 matrix
)      % Index (modularly) into the string. This produces the desired 24×60 char array
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 22 bytes

```
V6V4V12p*5?%+bN2\\\/)k
```

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V6V4V12p%2a5%3F%25%2BbN2%5C%5C%5C%2F%29k&debug=0).

Explanation:

```
V6                     Loop 6 times, with N from 0 to 5:
  V4                   Loop 4 times, with H from 0 to 3:
    V12                Loop 12 times, with b from 0 to 11:
      p                Print without newline
        *              The repetition
          5            5 times of
          ?            if
            %          the remainder
              + b N    when the sum of b and N
              2        is divided by 2
          \\           then the "\" character
          \/           else the "/" character
    )                  End
                       (implicitly print with newline)
  k                    k (empty string)
                       (implicit end)
                       (implicit end)
```

Sorry if the explanation is a little hard to understand, but it was kinda complicated.

Answer (score 5):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V),  <s>22</s>  21 bytes

**Edit** One byte won, thanks @DjMcMayhem:

```
5á\5á/05ä$4Ä5x$p4Ä3ä}
```

Changes are:

- `Y4P` -> `4Ä` Use V duplicate line instead of Vim built-in command (this will add a blank line at the end of the paragraph)
- `3äG` -> `3ä}` Duplicate the paragraph instead of the whole buffer (to avoid blank line generated by previous change)

---

**Original post**

```
5á\5á/05ä$Y4P5x$p4Ä3äG
```

[Try it online](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=NcOhXDXDoS8wNcOkJFk0UDV4JHA0w4Qzw6RH&input=)

Decomposed like this:

```
5á\                    Write 5 \
   5á/                 Write 5 / after
      0                Go to the beginning of the line
       5ä$             Copy the text to the end of the line and repeat it 5 times
          Y4P          Copy the line and create 4 new copies
             5x$p      Delete the 5 first characters and put them at the end of the line
                 4Ä    Duplicate this line
                   3äG Duplicate the whole text
```

Comment: It's cool to see someone else using V! Up until recently, it's only been me. If you ever need help with it, feel free to ping me in [the nineteenth byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)

Comment: @DrMcMoylex Yup your language seems fun to use :-) I had a problem on this one: initially I wanted to use `5á\5á/05ä$5Ä5x$p4Ä3äG` i.e. replace `Y4P` by `4Ä` but for a reason that I don't understand it copies an additional blank line... If you can enlighten me on this one it would be nice. Also if I find some free time i'd gladly contribute to the language (especially [issue #4](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/issues/4))

Comment: Ah, yes that has troubled me many times. It's a known issue. The problem is that `Ä` is a synonym for `dd`, not `Y`. This is usually not an issue, but it causes some problems if the buffer has only one line or if you're on the last line.

Comment: Actually, I just realized, that approach would still work if you replaced `3äG` with `3ä}` since it won't yank that last newline. http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=NcOhXDXDoS8wNcOkJDXDhDV4JHA0w4Qzw6R9&input=

Comment: Ok I think I get why it didn't work now. And nice way to win 1 byte, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 21 bytes

```
"/\"5*SR6*;4α@R4α+3αi
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=Ii9cIjUqU1I2Kjs0zrFAUjTOsSszzrFp&input=)

*-1 byte from Adnan*

Explanation:

```
"/\"5*SR6*;4α@R4α+3αi
"/\"5*                 "/\" repeated 5 times
      SR               sort and reverse (result: "\\\\\/////")
        6*             repeat string 6 times (forms one row)
          ;4α          copy and push a list containing 4 copies
             @R4α+     push a list containing 4 copies of the reversed string, append to previous list (now we have one row of diamonds)
                  3α   repeat pattern vertically 2 more times
                    i  flatten and implicitly print
```

Comment: Can you do something like `"/\"5*S` for creating the string of slashes?

Comment: @Adnan Great idea!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
⁾/\ẋ6Wẋ4;U$ẋ3x5Y
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oG-L1zhuos2V-G6izQ7VSThuoszeDVZ&input=)

Thanks to 6710 (miles) for -1 byte.

Comment: I think you can save a byte with `⁾/\ẋ6Wẋ4;U$ẋ3x5Y`

Comment: @miles Thanks, it seems I can't effectively use quicks yet :) And I knew I didn't need two `Y`s!

Answer (score 4):

## J, <s>31</s> <s>28</s> 19 bytes

```
4#_60]`|.\5#72$'/\'
```

### Usage

```
   4#_60]`|.\5#72$'/\'
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
```

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 30 bytes

```
A←240⍴'/////\\\\\'⋄24 60⍴A,⊖A
```

I'm quite new to APL, (I'm using APLX, but this should work across most implementations of APL), so this is a quite simplistic solution.

#### Explanation:

```
A ← 240 ⍴ '/////\\\\\' ⍝ set A to be a 240 character vector populated with '/////\\\\\'
⋄                      ⍝ statement separator
24 60 ⍴ A,⊖A           ⍝ populate a 24 by 60 character matrix with the concatenation 
                          of A and the reverse of A (⊖A)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 63 bytes

```
a='\n'.join([('/'*5+'\\'*5)*6]*4);print'\n'.join([a,a[::-1]]*3)
```

For Python 3, do this (65 bytes):

```
a='\n'.join([('/'*5+'\\'*5)*6]*4);print('\n'.join([a,a[::-1]]*3))
```

Comment: This uses the same method as [my Jelly answer](/a/98704/41024).

Comment: More efficient method than mine to start with

Comment: @ElPedro Basically, I just did some string/array manipulation. The trick is that I have prepared a bigger string: `/////\\\\\/////...` four times, separated by newlines

Answer (score 3):

### Octave, <s>50</s> 48 bytes

Anonymous function:

```
@()repmat([A=repmat(47,4,5) B=A*2-2;B A ''],3,6)
```

You can try [online here](http://octave-online.net). Simply run the above command and then run the function with `ans()`.

Essentially this creates an array of the value 47 which is 4 high and 5 wide. It then creates a second array of value 92 which is the same size.

The two arrays are concatenated into a checkerboard of `[A B;B A]`. The `''` is concatenated as well to force conversion to character strings.

Finally the whole array is replicated 3 times down and 6 times across to form the final size.

---

- Saved 2 bytes, thanks @StewieGriffin

Comment: no need for an anonymous function; save 3 bytes.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou there is, otherwise it will print `ans=` before the pillow. Having it in the function gets around this as it is expected to return the answer to a variable rather than displaying it.

Comment: That's just semantics. I mean, if you're going to be pedantic I'd worry more about the 3-line warning messages that appear instead :p  Also the usual rules state that it needs to be either an output from a direct terminal command, or a callable function handle. Meaning you should assign your anonymous function to a handle (or add another 5 bytes to account for having to pring `ans()`). Which is pointless, since `ans()` *still* prints `ans` when run!

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou `ans()` is a callable function handle, so you don't need to assign it to something with, e.g. `a=@...`, because it is implicitly assigned to `ans` as a handle. Also it doesn't print `ans=` when run unless you specifically ask it to by not doing anything with the returned value and not adding a `;`. If you did `disp(ans())` it would only print the exact output (no `ans=`). But yes, the warning is annoying, however that didn't happen previously, so it isn't language specific, but rather interpreter specific.

Comment: Ok, we'll agree to disagree. The way I see it, if you're relying on `disp(ans())` before getting your output, then you need to add 12 bytes to your answer. My own opinion is that this is just the way octave presents its result and that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](//soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf), 91 bytes

```
>>+++[<++++[<++++++[<.....<.....>>-]<<<.>>>>-]++++[<++++++[<<.....>.....>-]<<<.>>>>-]>-]
\/
```

[Try it online!](//smbf.tryitonline.net#code=Pj4rKytbPCsrKytbPCsrKysrK1s8Li4uLi48Li4uLi4-Pi1dPDw8Lj4-Pj4tXSsrKytbPCsrKysrK1s8PC4uLi4uPi4uLi4uPi1dPDw8Lj4-Pj4tXT4tXQpcLw)

Same as my [brainfuck answer](/a/98711/41024), but uses the 3 last characters of the source code instead of generating them at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, <s>73</s> 69 bytes

```php
for($s='/\\';$i<1440;$i++)echo$i%60<1?'
':'',$s[($i/5+($i/240|0))%2];
```

#### Demo

http://ideone.com/z7N1Md

Comment: 69 bytes: `for($s='/\\';$i<1440;$i++)echo$i%60<1?'\n':'',$s[($i/5+($i/240|0))%2];` (replace the `\n` with a real newline). `echo` isn't a function, so, it doesn't need parenthesys. Also, `echo` can receive multiple  values, separated by a comma. This really removes the need for those parenthesys. And then, inside your `$s[...]`, the outer-most calculation doesn't need parenthesys either, since it is contained withing `[]`. Using `$s[($i/5+($i/240|0))%2]` has the same effect and is shorter.

Comment: Thank you, updated! I didn't even know about echo accepting multiple parameters ^_^

Comment: `echo` and `print` accept multiple parameters. But `print` requires parenthesys with multiple parameters when used on a loop's increment, condition or assignment.

Comment: Can shave off that `<1`, by switching the expressions, `echo$i%60?'':'
',`, new line as expression 3 in the ternary.

Answer (score 3):

### Vim,  <s>44</s>  27 bytes

**EDIT** Lot of bytes won thanks to @DrMcMoylex:

```
5i\<esc>5a/<esc>0y$5PY4P5x$pY3PyGPP
```

---

Original answer:

I'm not sure that really fits the rules of this site but I thought that was fun to try it:

```
i\<esc>59.:s;\v(.{5})\1;\1/////;g<CR>Y4P5x$pY3PyGPP
```

Which can be decomposed like this:

```
i\<esc>                       Insert a \
59.                           Repeat 59 time the insertion
:s;\v(.{5})\1;\1/////;g<CR>   Match 5 characters followed by the same 5 characters
                              And replace them by these 5 characters followed by 5 /
Y4P                           Copy the line and repeat it 4 times
5x$p                          On the current line delete 5 characters and put them 
                              at the end of the line
Y3P                           Copy the line and repeat it 3 times
yG                            Copy all the lines
PP                            Repeat them 2 times
```

Comment: Oh hey statox, welcome to the site! This totally fits the rules. I golf mostly in vim. Just so you know, you could do `5i/<esc>5a\<esc>0y$5P` at the start to save 9 bytes.

Comment: Hey DrMcMoylex (new name? :-) ) glad to see you here and that my answer fits. Also thanks for your hint, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Haha, yeah I temporarily changed my name because of [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/98132/31716), lol. I'll change it back in 30 days

Answer (score 3):

### APL, 16

```
4⌿5/1↓⍉12 7⍴'\/'
```

Try it on [tryapl.org](http://tryapl.org/?a=4%u233F5/1%u2193%u234912%207%u2374%27%5C/%27&run)

Answer (score 3):

### Brainfuck, 168 bytes

```
++++++[>++++++++<-]>-<+++++++++[>>++++++++++<<-]>>++<<+++++[>>>++<<<-]>>>>+++[>++++[>++++++[<<<<<.....>.....>>>>-]<<<.>>-]++++[>++++++[<<<<.....<.....>>>>>-]<<<.>>-]<-]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, 120 bytes

```
String c(){String r="";for(int i=0;i<1440;r+=(i%60<1?"\n":"")+(i/60%8<4?i%10<5?"/":"\\":i%10<5?"\\":"/"),i++);return r;}
```

Pushed everything into one loop. Beats Brainfuck, mission accomplished.

See it online: https://ideone.com/pZjma3

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>142</s> 124 bytes

```
<?=str_replace(['#','-'],['/////','\\\\\\\\\\'],wordwrap(str_repeat(str_repeat("#-",24).str_repeat("-#",24), 4),12,"\n",1));
```

Previous version:

```
<?for($i=1;$i<4;$i++)echo wordwrap(str_repeat("/////\\\\\\\\\\",24),60,"\n",1)."\n".wordwrap(str_repeat("\\\\\\\\\\/////",24),60,"\n",1)."\n";
```

**Output:**

```
C:\PHP\>php this-is-my-pillow.php
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SOML](https://github.com/dzaima/SOML), 20 bytes

```
 /5* \5*+6*6{4{t}5{«
```

Explanation:

```
 /                    push "/", stack: ["/"]
  5*                  repeat it 5 times ["/////"]
     \                push "\" ["/////","\"]
      5*              repeat it 5 times ["/////","\\\\\"]
        +             add together ["/////\\\\\"]
         6*           repeat the string 6 times (it gets long here)
           6{         6 times repeat following code
             4{t}     output 4 times
                 5{«  put the 1st 5 chars at the end of the string
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
"/\\"5e*6*]4*N*_W%]3*N*
```

[ONLINE](//cjam.aditsu.net#code=%27%2F5*%27%5C5*%2B6*%5D4*N*_W%25%5D3*N*)

Thanks 8478 (Martin Ender) for -1.

Explanation:

```
"/\\"5e*6*]4*N*_W%]3*N* Code
"/\\"                   Push "/\\"
     5                  Push 5
      e*                Repeat each
        6               Push 6
         *              Repeat
          ]             Wrap stack from [ to ToS in array
           4            Push 4
            *           Repeat
             N          Push N = "\n"
              *         Join
               _        Duplicate
                W       Push W = -1
                 %      Take every nth item
                  ]     Wrap stack from [ to ToS in array
                   3    Push 3
                    *   Repeat
                     N  Push N = "\n"
                      * Join
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vitsy, <s>28</s> 26 bytes

This can be golfed a bit.

```
'\/'6\[4\[c\[4\[DO]r]aO]r]
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=J1wvJzZcWzRcW2NcWzRcW0RPXXJdYU9dcl0&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>51</s> 50 bytes

Perl 5.10.0+:

```
perl -E 'say+((@_=("/"x5,"\\"x5)x6,$/)x4,(pop@_,@_,$/)x4)x3'
```

Perl before 5.10.0 (52 bytes):

```
perl -e 'print+((@_=("/"x5,"\\"x5)x6,$/)x4,(pop@_,@_,$/)x4)x3'
```

Ungolfed:

```perl
say(
    (
        (
            @_ = ('/' x 5, '\\' x 5) x 6,
            $/,  # new line symbol
        ) x 4,
        (
            pop(@_),
            @_,
            $/,
        ) x 4,
    ) x 3
);
```

Thanx to @DomHastings for 1 byte.

Comment: Didn't think to use an array to store the slashes, nice! You can save 1 byte dropping the outermost `()` and prepend `+`: `perl -E 'say+((@_=('/'x5,'\\'x5)x6,$/)x4,(pop@_,@_,$/)x4)x3'`

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 24 bytes

```
Jj*4[*6+*5\/*5\\;j*3[J_J
```

[Try it!](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=Jj%2a4%5B%2a6%2B%2a5%5C%2F%2a5%5C%5C%3Bj%2a3%5BJ_J)

Explanation:

```
Jj*4[*6+*5\/*5\\;j*3[J_J
   4                     4
      6                  6
         5               5
          \/             "/"
        *                Repeat
             5           5
              \\         "\\"
            *            Repeat
       +                 Concatenate
     *                   Repeat
    [                    List
  *                      Repeat
 j                       Join
J                        Assign copy to J
                ;        Close argument list
                   3     3
                     J   J
                       J J
                      _  Reverse
                    [    List
                  *      Repeat
                 j       Join
```

Comment: That explanation was painful to write... wish there was some way to use `<something>5"/\\"` instead of ``+*5\/*5\\``.

Comment: `sC*5]"/\\"` There is, but it's a byte longer.

Comment: I see I still have a fair bit to learn. I've only posted 2 Pyth answers but I hope I'm getting there. Any suggestions/comments as to how I could improve how I did it? Gratefully received if so :)

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB, <s>58</s> 44 bytes

Thanks to @Stewie Griffin for saving a bunch of bytes ;)

```
[repmat(kron(['/\';'\/'],ones(4,5)),3,6),'']
```

Old version:

```
p=@()char(47+45*kron(ones(3,6),kron([0 1;1 0],ones(4,5))))
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 44 bytes

```
,(,('/////\\\\\'*6)*4+,('\\\\\/////'*6)*4)*3
```

Abuses the crap outta the default `Write-Output` behavior to put a newline between elements.

#### Explanation

I'm also trying out a new explanation format, rather than the long prose I traditionally write.

```
,(,('/////\\\\\'*6)*4+,('\\\\\/////'*6)*4)*3
    '/////\\\\\'*6                            # Repeat this string 6 times
  ,(              )*4                         # Repeat it into an array of four elements
                     +                        # Array concatenate with
                      ,('\\\\\/////'*6)*4)    # The same with the slashes the other way
,(                                       )*3  # Repeat it into an array of three elements
                                              # (i.e., 24 total strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>49</s> <s>48</s> <s>40</s> <s>37</s> 34 bytes

```
J60K*24+*5\/*5\\V24:*3+K_K*JN+J*JN
```

OK, I'm just learning Pyth so this is a direct port of my Python answer. Still a lot of golfing to do but it works so I am posting it anyway. Any hints gratefully received :)

1 byte saved with thanks to @Flp.Tkc

-8 by working out how to do it with a variable

-3 by moving the `*24` to the assignment of `K`

-3 by getting rid of the quotes

Comment: I've never tried pyth apart from looking at the docs once or twice, but I think you can replace `FN24` with `V24`

Comment: Nice. Just tested and it works. Will check the docs on that.

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 126 Bytes

```
var s="";var c="/";for(int a=0;a<24;){for(int b=0;b<60;)s+=b++%5>0?c:c=="/"?c=@"\":c="/";s+="\n";c=a++%3>1?c=="/"?@"\":"/":c;}
```

`string s` is output.
It could be 3 byte less, when it is infinite.

### Ungolfed

```
        var s = "";
        var c = "/";
        for (int a = 0; a < 24;)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < 60;)//write line
            {
                s += b++ % 5 > 0 ? c : c == "/" ? c = @"\" : c = "/";//Change  /to \ and vice versa after five times
            }
            s += "\n";


            c = a++ % 3 > 1 ? c == "/"? c = @"\" : c = "/" :c; //Change  /to \ and vice versa after three lines
        }
```

Comment: Can save at least two bytes with `b%5>0` and `c=a%3>1...` I'm not sure because I'm on my phone but you may be able to store c as a char instead of a string and save a few bytes using implicit int to char conversions. Also do you really need all the `c=` in the last line ? I think it can be `c=a%3>1?c=="/"?"\\":"/“:c;` I see why you do it in the inner loop due to assigning to c and appending to s at the same time but you can probably refactor that a bit for byte savings as well

Comment: Maybe also take the post increments out of the loop and add them into into the assignments... Ie `s+=b++%5...` and `c=a++%3...` save another two bytes

Comment: Thank you, I complete forgot these `c=` in last line. Implicit int to char conversions does not work, because char is 16bit and written number is 32bit int, so there is only cast avaiable.

Answer (score 1):

## GameMaker Language, 104 bytes

You should make sure that uninitialized variables don't throw an error. This setting is in the main page of Preferences. Otherwise, add `e=''` to the beginning of the program.

```
a="/////"b="\\\\\"d=b+a+b+a+b+a+b c=a+d d+=a for(i=0;i<24;i++)if i mod 8>3e+=d else e+=c e+="#" return e
```

P.S. Yes, each part of the for loop needs an expression. So I can't `for(i=0;i<24;)` and have i++ later.

**Output**

```
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
```

Comment: Are there missing newlines?

Answer (score 1):

## C++ 138

```c++
void P(){int i,j,k,l;for(i=0;i<3;i++)for(j=0;j<8;j++)for(k=0;k<12;k++)for(l=0;l<5;l++)cout<<((j/4)?(k%2)?'/':'\\':(k%2)?'\\':'/')<<'\n';}
```

**Ungolfed**

```c++
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void P()
{
    int i,j,k,l;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
            for(k=0;k<12;k++)
                for(l=0;l<5;l++)
                    cout<<((j/4)?(k%2)?'/':'\\':(k%2)?'\\':'/')<<'\n';
}

int main()
{
    P();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why braces on the second for loop?

Comment: edited @pinkfloydx33

Answer (score 1):

## [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 166 characters

Line split for readability.

```
#::((def x #S,N::(invoke S repeat N))(var A (x "/" 5))(var B (x "\\" 5))
(var C (+ (x (+ A B) 6) (nl)))(var D (+ (x (+ B A) 6) (nl)))
(print (x (+ (x C 4) (x D 4)) 5)))
```

Sample usage:

```
% pillow.lithp
(
    (def f #::((def x #S,N::(invoke S repeat N))(var A (x "/" 5))(var B (x "\\" 5))(var C (+ (x (+ A B) 6) (nl)))(var D (+ (x (+ B A) 6) (nl)))(print (x (+ (x C 4) (x D 4)) 5))))
    (f)
)
```

Run with:

```
./run.js pillow.lithp
```

This is a fairly simple solution that repeats characters. There is no standalone `repeat` function yet, so `invoke` is used to call `"string".repeat(N)` and adds a bit to the count.

Answer (score 1):

### GolfSharp, 59 bytes

```
r(0,1440).s(n=>n%10<5^n%480<240?"\\":"/").j().S(60).j("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 76 bytes

```
'/\::2%0`!\4c*/2%0`!-> #0 #\ #\' $ #\_\3k:4k,1+:c%0`!> #0 #, #a_:cad+*\`!#@_
```

[TryItOnline!](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=Jy9cOjoyJTBgIVw0YyovMiUwYCEtPiAjMCAjXCAjXCcgJCAjXF9cM2s6NGssMSs6YyUwYCE-ICMwICMsICNhXzpjYWQrKlxgISNAXw&input=)

String processing/generation can be difficult with only a stack available...

A couple bytes may be able to be shaved off here or there, but I beat brainfuck, so I'm happy.

### Explanation

```
Push '/' on the stack
Swap top two (at the beginning, zero will now be on top). Call top = iterator = n
Calculate (n % 2 == 0) != ((n / 48) % 2 == 0)
If true, swap top two, replace '/' with '\', swap again
Swap top two (so that we now have the character to print on top, followed by n)
Duplicate the char 4 times, and print 5 times
Increment n
If n % 12 == 0, print a newline character
If !(288 > n), end, else repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 83 + 14 = 97 bytes

```
puts Zlib.inflate Base64.decode64"eNrTB4EYECCdxTVENSP4pLOGqubhE8+j8Twaz6PxDAA3Pofw"
```

Add 14 bytes for `-rzlib` and `-rbase64` flags.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 56 bytes

```
a="////\\\\\\\\"^6*"\n";print((a^4*a[[48:-1:1,49]]^4)^3)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 72 bytes

```r
write(matrix(c(x<-rep(rep(c('/','\\'),e=5),24),rev(x)),24,60),'',60,,'')
```

builds a matrix of appropriate characters and writes it to stdout.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYxCoAwDEbh4ySBX5SiTnqTLlIydBAkFM3tYzs8vmcRn9WmfF/NqnNhPybTh0eFaSZQziTQcxOkVWD6sst47IuAqIOORPw)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 113 bytes

```
DECLARE @ INT=0L:IF @%8<4PRINT REPLICATE('/////\\\\\',6)ELSE PRINT REPLICATE('\\\\\/////',6)SET @+=1IF @<24GOTO L
```

Formatted:

```
DECLARE @ INT=0
L:
   IF @%8<4 PRINT REPLICATE('/////\\\\\',6)
   ELSE PRINT REPLICATE('\\\\\/////',6)
   SET @+=1
IF @<24 GOTO L
```

Using both string literals seems to be the shortest option, trying to `REPLICATE(REPLICATE('/',5)+REPLICATE('\',5)` is way longer, as is using additional variables.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
└5*5∙╬¡6*3∙
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyNTE0NSo1JXUyMjE5JXUyNTZDJUExNiozJXUyMjE5,inputs=JXUyNTE0NSoldTI1NkMlQjM2KjQldTIyMTkldTI1NkMldTIyMTEzJXUyMjE5)

Explanation:

```
└            push "/"
 5*          repeat 5 times
   5∙        repeat vertically 5 times
     ╬¡      quad-palindromize with 0 overlap and mirroring characters
       6*    multiply 6 times horizontally
         3∙  multiply 3 times vertically
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jstx](https://github.com/Quantum64/Jstx), 21 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/codepage)

```
♣/►\:►/;1BO♠/♦/!41o16
```

Not the shortest solution but I wanted to try this interesting challenge.

Explanation

```
♣  # Push literal 5
/  # Enter an iteration block over the first stack value.
►\ # Push literal \
:  # Push the sum of the second and first stack values.
►/ # Push literal /
;  # Push the difference of the second and first stack values.
1  # End an iteration block.
B  # Push five copies of the first stack value.
O  # Collapse all stack values into a string, then Push that string.
♠  # Push literal 6
/  # Enter an iteration block over the first stack value.
♦  # Push literal 4
/  # Enter an iteration block over the first stack value.
!  # Push a copy of the first stack value.
4  # Print the first stack value, then a newline.
1  # End an iteration block.
o  # Push the first stack value with characters in reverse order.
1  # End an iteration block.
6  # Ends program execution.
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.2/JstxGWT.html?code=4pmjL%24KWulw64pa6LzsxQk_imaAv4pmmLyE0MW8xNg%3D%3D)

Answer (score 1):

### [Pip `-n`](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 24 bytes

```
(RF('/X6.'\X6)X24)X3<>72
```

Quad reflect is a bit weird in pip, so this answer uses normal reflect.

The -n flag joins lists with newlines.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fI8hNQ10/wkxPPSbCTDPCyEQzwtjGztzo////unkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 88 bytes

```
3[4[6[5[68W1A;1A]%4[68W2A2W;1A]%1A]%52W;1A]4[6[5[68W2A2W;1A]%4[68W1A;1A]%1A]%52W;1A]%1A]
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=3%5B4%5B6%5B5%5B68W1A%3B1A%5D%254%5B68W2A2W%3B1A%5D%251A%5D%2552W%3B1A%5D4%5B6%5B5%5B68W2A2W%3B1A%5D%254%5B68W1A%3B1A%5D%251A%5D%2552W%3B1A%5D%251A%5D&input=)

Raise the max executions to at least 15000 to test it :D Oh, and be ready to wait for quite some time for it to finish.

## [MAWP 2.0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 61 bytes

```
3[4[6["/////\\\\\":1-]`10;1-]`4[6["\\\\\/////":1-]`10;1-]`1-]
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v2.0?code=3%5B4%5B6%5B%22%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%22%3A1-%5D%6010%3B1-%5D%604%5B6%5B%22%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%22%3A1-%5D%6010%3B1-%5D%601-%5D&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 40 bytes

Binary:

```
00000000: b85c 2fb1 18b3 0cf6 c103 7502 86e0 ba05  .\/.......u.....
00000010: 00cd 294a 75fb 86e0 4b75 f350 b00d cd29  ..)Ju...Ku.P...)
00000020: b00a cd29 58e2 dec3                      ...)X...
```

Listing:

```
B8 2F5C         MOV  AX, '/\'       ; the two chars              
B1 18           MOV  CL, 24         ; CX = row counter 
            ROW: 
B3 0C           MOV  BL, 12         ; BX = pattern counter 
F6 C1 03        TEST CL, 3          ; have displayed 4 lines of same direction? 
75 02           JNZ  DIR            ; if not, continue with same 
86 E0           XCHG AH, AL         ; otherwise, swap the chars 
            DIR: 
BA 0005         MOV  DX, 5          ; DX = char counter 
            PATT: 
CD 29           INT  29H            ; write char to console 
4A              DEC  DX             ; have displayed 5 of the same? 
75 FB           JNZ  PATT           ; if not, keep writing  
86 E0           XCHG AH, AL         ; otherwise, swap the chars 
4B              DEC  BX             ; have displayed 12 patterns on a line? 
75 F3           JNZ  DIR            ; if not, keep writing patterns 
50              PUSH AX             ; otherwise, save the chars and write a newline 
B0 0D           MOV  AL, 0DH        ; CR char 
CD 29           INT  29H            ; write to console 
B0 0A           MOV  AL, 0AH        ; LF char 
CD 29           INT  29H            ; write to console 
58              POP  AX             ; restore original chars 
E2 DE           LOOP ROW            ; loop until written 24 lines written 
C3              RET                 ; return to DOS
```

A standalone PC DOS executable COM program.  Output to console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles), 13 bytes

```
^3`<^4`:;^6`<^5"/\\"\$
```

explanation

```
^3                     # replicate 3 times
  `<                   # sort
    ^4                 # replicate 4 times
      `:               # list of two lists (for getting newlines)
        ;              # let (save value to $)
         ^6            # replicate 6 times
           `<          # sort
             ^5        # replicate 5 times
               "/\\"   # the string /\
                    \$ # reverse the saved value
```

Note that that last $ can't be omitted because in the binary form the sort needs to place more data after its arg

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
ＵＯ⁵¦⁴/‖Ｍ↓→‖Ｍ↓→‖Ｍ‖ＢＯ²⁰‖ＢＯ↓⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98/KSc/L13DVEfBREdBSV9J05orKDUtJzW5xDezqCi/SMPKJb88T0fBKigzPaOERFmEgFNpSUlqUVpOpX9ZalFOYoGGkQEeSaipFkAl/wE) Link is to verbose version of code.

Explanation:

```
ＵＯ⁵¦⁴/  - drawing a 5 by 4 rectangle filled with /
‖Ｍ↓→            - reflect and mirror the canvas to the down and right direction (note that for this pattern order doesn't matter)
‖Ｍ             - reflect mirror without a argument (default is to the right, n times)
‖ＢＯ²⁰         - reflect butterfly overlap which would reflect the same thing n times to the left by default
‖ＢＯ↓⁸        - 8 characters but this time with a given direction which is down
```

Optimizing: -9, Thanks to @Neil for the help on reflects.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 132 bytes

```
@set s=/////\\\\\
@set s=%s%%s%%s%%s%%s%%s%
@set s=%s% %s:~5%/////
@for %%s in (%s% %s% %s%)do @for /l %%i in (1,1,4)do @echo %%s
```

Works by building up the two types of row, then looping through six rows four times per row.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3, <s>100 99</s> 97 bytes

```
var a="/////",b="\\\\\\\\\\",c=""
(1...144).map{c+=a+b+($0%6<1 ?"\n":"")
$0%24<1 ?swap(&a,&b):()}
```

Could save 1 byte if `Swift` `print` function did not add a newline by default.

**Edit 1:**

Saved 1 byte by changing the if to ternary

`if(i%24<1){swap(&a,&b)}` -> `i%24<1 ?swap(&a,&b):()`

**Edit 2:**

Changed from `for` to `map` over the `CountableClosedRange`

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 156 bytes

```
(define g #t)(for((k 24))(for((i 12))(for((j 5))(display(if g "/""\\")))(set! g(if g #f #t)))
(when(= 0(modulo(add1 k)4))(set! g(if g #f #t)))(displayln""))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define(f)
  (define g #t)
  (for ((k 24))
    (for ((i 12))
      (for ((j 5))
        (display (if g "/" "\\")))
      (set! g (if g #f #t)))
    (when (= 0 (modulo (add1 k) 4))
      (set! g (if g #f #t)))
    (displayln "")))
```

Testing:

```
(f)
```

Output:

```
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 148 bytes

```
String c(){String r,z,y=z=r="",p="/////\\\\\\\\\\",q="\\\\\\\\\\/////";int i=0;for(;i++<6;y+=p,z+=q);for(i=0;i<24;r+=(i++%8<4?y:z)+"\n");}return r;}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/FHyRP5)

```
class M{
  static String c() {
    String r, z, y = z = r = "",
           p = "/////\\\\\\\\\\",
           q = "\\\\\\\\\\/////";
    int i = 0;
    for(; i++ < 6; y += p, z += q);
    for(i = 0; i < 24; r += (i++%8 < 4 ? y : z)+"\n");
    return r;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c());
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 55 bytes

```
for(;$i<1440;)echo"/\\"[($i/5^$i/240)&1],"\n"[++$i%60];
```

toggles between forward and backward slash every 5 characters, inverted every 240 characters;
not counting newlines; newlines inserted every 60 characters.

has one trailing newline. Run with `-r`.

---

**recursive program** for 66 bytes:

```
<?="/\\"[($i/5^$i/240)&1]."\n"[++$i%60];if($i<1440)include"p.php";
```

save to file `p.php`; call from CLI (or insert `($i?"":"<pre>").` after `<?=`)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>83</s> 55 bytes

```python
x=('/'*5+'\\'*5)*6;print((x+'\n')*4+(x[::-1]+'\n')*4)*3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8JWQ11fXctUWz0mBkhpaplZFxRl5pVoaFQAhfLUNbVMtDUqoq2sdA1jYQKaWsb//wMA)

-28 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun

Comment: 55 bytes: [`x=('/'*5+'\\'*5)*6;print((x+'\n')*4+(x[::-1]+'\n')*4)*3`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8JWQ11fXctUWz0mBkhpaplZFxRl5pVoaFQAhfLUNbVMtDUqoq2sdA1jYQKaWsb//wMA)

Comment: TIO link please.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Done

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 60 bytes

Lots of multiplying strings!

```
print((((('/'*5+'\\'*5)*6+'\n')*4)+(('\\'*5+'/'*5)*6+'\n')*4)*3)
```

**Output**

```
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////\\\\\/////
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 77 bytes

I must say I thought this would be easier with PowerShell, but it's quite hard to create something more condense than this.

`$a=@("/","\");"$(1..6|%{1..3|%{1..6|%{$a[$b]*5;$a[!$b]*5};"`r`n"}; $b=!$b})"`

More readable:

```
$a=@("/","\")
"$(1..6|%{
    1..3|%{ 
     1..6|%{
     $a[$b]*5
     $a[!$b]*5
        }
     "`r`n"}
    $b=!$b})"
```

I'm using the index numbers of the array in order to decide whether I should put `\` or `/` and between every loop I simply toggle the variable.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I get your logic, but it doesn't seem to work quite right. With the code as-is, you're going to get a bunch of `Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.` errors since `$b` is uninitialized on the first inner loop of `1..6`. Additionally, this will join the strings you're creating with spaces, since that's the default `$OutputFieldSeparator` when stringifying an array (what you're doing here).

Comment: Additionally, you don't need both `r` and `n` -- just `n` will work for newlines. You've also got an extra space between `;` and `$b=`.

Comment: Must be ISE messing with me again. The host retains variables between each run, that's what got me here. Dammit.

Comment: You can fix the array index by putting a `+` in front -- like `$a[+$b]` -- to force a cast to int. However, that doesn't eliminate the spaces between elements. :-/

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 97

```
proc r s\ n {string repe $s $n}
puts [r [r [r /////[r \\ 5] 6]\n 4][r [r [r \\ 5]///// 6]\n 4] 3]
```

---

My try to outgolf myself didn't go well :( :

## tcl, 102

```
proc r s\ n {string repe $s $n}
proc R s\ t {r [r [r $s 5][r $t 5] 6]\n 4}
puts [r [R / \\][R \\ /] 3]
```

runnable on: http://rextester.com/live/HURDH99224

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
J*6S*5"/\\"V6V4J)=_J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30vLLFjLVEk/JkYpzCzMxEvTNt7r/38A)

Python 3 translation:

```
J=6*sorted(5*"/\\")
for N in range(6):
    for N in range(4):
        print(J)
    J=J[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel (loaded with VBA), <strike>70</strike> 62 bytes

Formula for each cell (A4 through BH27):

```
=IF(SIN(COLUMN()*0.62)*SIN(ROW()*0.8)>0,"\","/")
```

I'm not sure how to score this and I couldn't find a consensus. It's a 48 byte pure Excel formula, the same in every cell (but of course the fact that it should be in a particular range is also information). It takes 62 bytes to load it by executing this in the VBA Immediate window.

```
[A4:BH27]="=IF(SIN(COLUMN()*.62)*SIN(ROW()*.8)>0,""\"",""/"")"
```

## Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Saved 8 bytes by realizing I don't need `.Formula` in the VBA

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus) `-i`, 27 bytes

```
L,"/\"5€*6*b]4*d€bR+3*bUBJn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HR0k/Rsn0UdMaLTOtpFgTrRQgMylI21grKdTJK@///3/5BSWZ@XnF/3UzAQ)

The `-i` flag simply invokes the function with a clean stack and then outputs its return value.

### How it works

```
L,		; Anonymous function
	"/\"	; Push this string			STACK = ["/\"]
	5€*	; Repeat each character 5 times		STACK = [["/////" "\\\\\"]]
	6*	; Repeat the array 6 times		STACK = [["/////" "\\\\\" "/////" "\\\\\" "/////" "\\\\\" "/////" "\\\\\" "/////" "\\\\\" "/////" "\\\\\"]]
	b]4*	; Repeat the whole thing 4 times	STACK = [[["/////" "\\\\\" ... "/////" "\\\\\"]]]
	d	; Duplicate				STACK = [[["/////" "\\\\\" ... "/////" "\\\\\"]] [["/////" "\\\\\" ... "/////" "\\\\\"]]]
	€bR	; Reverse the second copy		STACK = [[["/////" "\\\\\" ... "/////" "\\\\\"]] [["\\\\\" "/////" ... "\\\\\" "/////"]]]
	+	; Concatenate				STACK = [[["/////" "\\\\\" ...] ... [... "\\\\\" "/////"]]]
	3*	; Repeat 3 times			STACK = [[["/////" "\\\\\" ...] ... [... "\\\\\" "/////"]]]
	bUBJn	; Concatenate and grid			STACK = ["/////\\\\\...\\\\\/////"]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
‛/\5*s6(4(:6*,)Ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%80%9B%2F%5C5*s6%284%28%3A6*%2C%29%E1%B9%98&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Do not worry, your pillow will be remembered.

```
‛/\              # String `/\`
   5*            # times 5
     s           # Sort
      6(         # Six times
        4(    )  # Four times
          :      # Duplicate
           6*    # 6 lots
             ,   # Output
               Ṙ # Reverse
```