# Make me a blanket!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

I want a blanket that looks like this. Each strip goes over, under, over, under. Can you print it?

```
\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////
 \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\//// 
  ////    ////    ////    ////    ////    ////  
 ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\ 
////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\
\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\
\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\
\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\
\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////
 \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\//// 
  ////    ////    ////    ////    ////    ////  
 ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\ 
////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\
\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\
\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\
\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\
\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////
 \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\//// 
  ////    ////    ////    ////    ////    ////  
 ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\ 
////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\
\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\
\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\
\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\
```

Trailing spaces at the end of each line and trailing newlines are acceptable.

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=99023,OVERRIDE_USER=12537;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: The right edge seems misaligned.

Comment: Is the left edge not overlapping intended?

Comment: @xnor Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @carusocomputing Fixed.

Comment: There's still some weirdness -- the left edge messes up the alternation of overs and unders.

Comment: @xnor No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Oliver You sure? Look at the ``\\\\`` strand from the top left corner. It goes over, over, under, over, under, over.

Comment: @xnor Oh, okay... let me fix that.

Comment: @xnor Fixed....

Comment: Had you used the Sandbox, those issues could have been avoided before this went up on main.

Comment: Related: [This is my pillow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98701/this-is-my-pillow)

Answer (score 11):

### Python 2, 84 bytes

```python
R=range(24)
for i in R:print''.join(" \// \/\\"[i+~j>>2&1^i+j>>1&2^i&4]for j in R*2)
```

Thanks to Sp3000 for 6 bytes from turning the arithmetic operations into bitwise ones.

Comment: Whoa... how????

Comment: `i+~j>>2&1^i+j>>1&2^i&4`, perhaps?

Comment: @Sp3000 That's some nice bitwise precedence. I'll have to remember that when combining arithmetically-derived booleans into an index.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 36 bytes

```
V24sm@" \// \/\\"im<3%k8++BNdt-NdT48
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V24sm%40%22+%5C%2F%2F+%5C%2F%5C%5C%22im%3C3%25k8%2B%2BBNdt-NdT48&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

We can determine the symbol by checking 3 conditions:

```
A := row % 8 > 3
B := (row + column) % 8 > 3
C := (row - column - 1) % 8 > 3
```

If we interpret `[A,B,C]` as a binary number, we get the following mapping:

```
01234567
 \// \/\
```

We can also interpret `[A,B,C]` as decimal number and perform a modular indexed lookup in the string. This doesn't make a difference because `10 mod 8 = 2`.

Now to the code:

`V24` iterates `N` (row-idx) over `[0, 1, ..., 23]`.

`sm...48` maps the numbers `d` (column-idx) in `[0, 1, ..., 47]` to chars and print the combined string.

`++BNd` generates the list `[N, N+d]`, `+...t-Nd` appends `N-d-1`. So we have get the list `[N, N+d, N-d-1]`. `m<3%k8` checks for each computed number `k`, if `3 < k % 8`, so this gives the list with the conditions `[A, B, C]`.

`i...T` convents this to a decimal number and then `@" \// \/\\"` does the lookup in the string.

More or less the same code in Python2: **98 bytes**:

```
R=range(8)
for r in R*3:print''.join(" \// \/\\"[4*(r>3)+2*((r+c)%8>3)+((r-c-1)%8>3)]for c in R*6)
```

Comment: Just trying to get to grips with Pyth so any decent answer with a good explanation gets an upvote from me. was going to try Pyth after my base 3 experiment :)

Comment: You should post the Python2 answer as well...

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>174</s> <s>172</s> 138 bytes

```
print("\n".join(o*6for o in("bbbb////"," bb//// ","  ////  "," ////bb ","////bbbb","b//  bbb","bb    bb","bbb  //b")*3).replace("b","\\"))
```

Found the smallest pattern I could find in the blanket (the "under" and "over" pattern), stuck it in a list and added some list comprehension and string manipulation to unpack it all. Substituted all escaped backslashes by "b" and replaced them back later to save a few bytes.

Thanks to Oliver for golfing off 2 bytes!

Took 34 bytes off by changing the pattern - the whole pattern for the blanket is now in a single list, so only one for loop is needed to unwrap the pattern.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! nice first post! You can shave a byte in python 2 I think, you don't need the parends for print.

Comment: Thank you Easterly Irk, I've been lurking around in code golf for too long now, so I decided to participate. :)

Comment: You can save two byte by removing the space after `0*6` and `u*6`

Comment: You could save 4 bytes by using the "b" for double backslashes and anywhere you need a single backslash just use escaping:`print((("\n".join(o*6 for o in("bb////"," b//// ","  ////  "," ////b ",""))+"\n".join(u*6 for u in("////bb","\\//  b\\","b    b","b\\  //\\","")))*3).replace("b","\\\\"))`

Comment: dzaima: your code doesn't seem to generate a valid blanket.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>171</s> <s>170</s> 168 bytes

```py
a,b,c=r"\\","/"*4," "
f,g=c*2,c+a+b+c
d=(a*2+b)*6,g*6,(f+b+f)*6,g[::-1]*6,(b+a*2)*6,('\\//'+f+a+"\\")*6,(a+f*2+a)*6,(a+"\\"+f+'//\\')*6
for e in 0,1,2:print'\n'.join(d)
```

Not pretty and not clever. Just sets variables for the most often used groups of strings then combines them and prints the result 3 times. May try and golf it more later if I don't find a better approach.

1 byte saved by using raw input on the a assignment. Thanks @nedla2004

-2 by assigning a couple of variables but still not a serious competitor

Comment: You could define a as r"\\"

Comment: Thanks @nedla2004 Good point. Threw this together pretty quickly and was going to look at it later. That's a good start :)

Comment: Most interested in finding a way round the `*6` on each tuple element though. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how you could do that, but the last line can be `exec r"print'\n'.join(d);"*3`.

Comment: I just posted an alternative just out of interest. Would value your comments on that also.

Answer (score 4):

## Brainfuck, 301 bytes

```
-[>+<-----]-[>>+<<---]>---->+++++++>>++++[<++++++++>-]>+++>++++++++++<[-<++++++[-<<....<....>>>]>>.<<++++++[-<.<..<....>>.>]>>.<<++++++[-<..<<....>>..>]>>.<<++++++[-<.<<....>..>.>]>>.<<++++++[-<<<....>....>>]>>.<<++++++[-<<.<..>>..<...>>]>>.<<++++++[-<<..>....<..>>]>>.<<++++++[-<<...>..<<..>.>>]>>.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1RCoAgDAbgAw09wfgvIj5UEETQQ9D5bb@agTpEt31O13s5rv3ZzpRcgKhjREstZxHBBqQEchJUvtqch7TQ4Kpaot4ibwAi4PU39iv5wbx@NFolrt4acbQ3/sYHda5lTOdGLHeqxpRe)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 209 + 17 = 226 bytes

Run with `-mList::Util=max -M5.010` (the second flag is free).  It's not winning any byte count competitions, but here's my solution.

```
for(0..7){@b=(1)x8;@b[$_+3..$_+7]=(3)x4;@b[7-$_..10-$_]=(2)x4;for$c(0..2){$b[$c+8]=max$b[$c+8],$b[$c];$b[5-$c]=max$b[5-$c],$b[13-$c];}push@a,sprintf("%-8s",join("",@b[3..10])=~tr[123][ /\\]r)x6;}say for@a,@a,@a
```

Readable:

```
for(0..7){
    @b=(1)x8;
    @b[$_+3..$_+7]=(3)x4;
    @b[7-$_..10-$_]=(2)x4;
    for$c(0..2){
        $b[$c+8]=max$b[$c+8],$b[$c];
        $b[5-$c]=max$b[5-$c],$b[13-$c];
    }
    push@a,sprintf("%-8s",join("",@b[3..10])=~tr[123][ /\\]r)x6
}
say for@a,@a,@a
```

Procedurally generates each segment, then repeats the pattern 6 times, then outputs the total result 3 times.

Comment: Woah,I'm not the longest answe any more :) +1 for doing it in Perl anyway.

Comment: I could have done it the same way as everyone else (just printing a bunch of lines), but I decided to do things algorithmically instead of explicitly because I felt it was cooler.

Comment: Cool by my standards. I've taken an approach that I have never tried before cos it was an interesting challenge. As I said, +1. No insult intended by my comment. That's why I upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 37 bytes

Uses [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.

```
24FNU48FXXN+XN-<)8%3›J" \// \/\"è?}¶?
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MjRGTlU0OEZYWE4rWE4tPCk4JTPigLpKIiBcLy8gXC9cIsOoP33Ctj8&input=)

**Explanation**

Uses the mod-8 trick expertly explained in [Jakube's pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99209/47066).

```
24F                                    # for N in [0 ... 23] do:
   NU                                  # save N in X
     48F                               # for N in [0 ... 48] do:
        XXN+XN-<)                      # push [X,X+N,X-N-1]
                 8%                    # mod each by 8
                   3›                  # compare with 3
                     J                 # join
                      " \// \/\"è?     # index into string and print
                                  }    # end inner loop
                                   ¶?  # print newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP <strike>157</strike> 126 bytes

Taking the changes @Titus lists in the comments...
I'm annoyed I missed point 1 which I should have caught, but I didn't know strtr() existed which is where most of the savings come - nice work Titus!

NEW:

```
while($i<32)echo$b=strtr([3322,' 322 ','0220',' 223 ',2233,12013,3003,13021][$i++%8],['  ','\\','//','\\\\']),"$b$b$b$b$b\n";
```

OLD:

```
<?$a=[zzyy,' zyy ',syys,' yyz ',yyzz,xysxz,zssz,xzsyx];while($i<32){$b=$a[$i++%8];$b=str_replace([z,x,y,s],['\\\\','\\','//','  '],$b);echo"$b$b$b$b$b$b
";}
```

Because all the backslashes need escaping it saves quite a bit of space to pack them up as different character and replace them for output, and then once I'm calling str_replace() it makes sense to use it as often as possible.

Comment: You can remove the open tag if you use `-r`. Use these five steps to save another 30 bytes: http://ideone.com/wt4HGB 1) use `$a[...]` directly as `str_replace` parameter instead of assigning it. 2) `strtr` instead of `str_replace`. 3) Use digits instead of letters. 4) Include the assignment in the echo. 5) Don´t assign `$a`, just use it.

Answer (score 2):

## [SOML](https://github.com/dzaima/SOML), 106 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOML/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
3{"\\\\////”6*p" \\//// ”6*p"  ////  ”6*p" ////\\ ”6*p"////\\\\”6*p"\//  \\\”6*p"\\    \\”6*p"\\\  //\”6*p
```

a non-competing version using a function that I've only recently added: (<s>83</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes)

explanation:

```
  →$\\→#////→@”6*p"→~3{"##@~ #@ ~$@$~ @# ~@##~\//$#\~#$$#~#\$//\~”
  →$                                                                in the further code replace "$" with "  "
    \\→#                                                            replace "#" with "\\"
        ////→@                                                      replace "@" with "////"
              ”6*p"→~3{"##@~ #@ ~$@$~ @# ~@##~\//$#\~#$$#~#\$//\~” the code to exchange stuff in

so that results in:
”6*p"→~3{"\\\\////~ \\//// ~  ////  ~ ////\\ ~////\\\\~\//  \\\~\\    \\~\\\  //\~”
”6*p"→~3{"A~B~C~D~E~F~G~H~”  modified version of the program (removing "/","\" and " " and replaced with A,B,C,ect.)
”6*p"→~                      replace in the further program "~" with ”6*p" which is:
”                            end string
 6*                          repeat the last thing in stack 6 times
   p                         output the result
    "                        start a string
resulting program: 
3{"A”6*p"B”6*p"C”6*p"D”6*p"E”6*p"F”6*p"G”6*p"H”6*p"”
shortened example:
3{"A”6*p"B”6*p"H”6*p"”
3{                      repeat 3 times
  "A”                   push "A" (original: "\\\\////")
     6*p                output it multiplied by 6
        "B”             push "B" (original: " \\//// ")
           6*p          output it multiplied by 6
              "H”       push "H" (original: "\\\  //\")
                 6*p    output it multiplied by 6
                    "”  push an empty string (shorter to do ~” than ”6*p)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>132</s> <s>131</s> 113 bytes

```
@a=((0)x4,1..4);map{say+(map$a[7-$_]?$a[$_]*$r?'/':'\\':$a[$_]?'/':$",0..7)x6;push@a,shift@a;$_%4||($r=!$r)}0..23
```

Ungolfed:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @a = ((1) x 4, (0) x 4);  # print '\' if true
my @b = ((0) x 4, (1) x 4);  # print '/' if true
my $r = 0;                   # print '\' over '/' if true

for (0 .. 23) {
    say((map { $a[$_] ? ($b[$_] * $r ? '/' : '\\') : ($b[$_] ? '/' : ' ') } 0 .. 7) x 6);
    unshift(@a, pop(@a));    # circular shift to left
    push(@b, shift(@b));     # circular shift to right
    $r = !$r if !($_ % 4);   # change print priority
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>245</s> <s>236</s> <s>234</s> <s>233</s> <s>230</s> <s>216</s> <s>212</s> <s>198</s> 195 bytes

OK, longer than my last (and any other) answer but would be interested in feedback on the approach.

```py
for a in(40,4496,6200,5456,3240,1188,720,228)*3:print((`a%6561/2178`+`a%2178/729`+`a%729/243`+`a%243/81`+`a%81/27`+`a%27/9`+`a%9/3`+`a%3/1`)*6).replace('0','\\').replace('1','/').replace('2',' ')
```

**Edit**

-9 due to @nedla2004 being more on the ball than me

-2 by taking the lambda outside of the loop and so losing 2 indent spaces

-1 by using `in' '*3` instead of `in 0,1,2` since I don't use `h` anyway. it's just a counter.

-3 Why, why, why did I leave a newline and 2 indents between the second for and the print??? It's late. Will revisit tomorrow.

-14 Can actually lose the lambda completely and just include the base 3 decoder directly after the print statement. Looks messy but after all, this is code golf :)

-4 No point setting a variable for the integer list. Just use it directly in the second for loop.

-14 and no point using the outer loop. Just multiply the integer tuple by 3 (shamelessly stolen from @nedla2004 to get under 200 :))

-3 Saved 3 by making \=0, /=1 and space=2. This makes the integer list shorter as three of the base 3 numbers now have leading 0's

**How it works (and it does)**

Since only 3 characters are used:

1. l is a list of the 8 repeating patterns as integer equivalents of their base 3 representation assuming that " "=0, "\"=1 and "/"=2
2. <s>The lambda</s> The first code after the print statement is a lightweight converter from integer to a base 3 string
3. The first loop loops 3 times and the second prints each line with the base 3 characters multiplied by 6 and replaced with /,\ or space.

I'm sure I could use a regex instead of the nested replace() but I'm too tired to try right now. This was just an experiment and longer than my previous Python effort but have posted just for any comments on the approach (and also because I have never worked in base 3 before and I quite enjoyed working out the converter).

Comment: You could just remove the first division in the base 3 conversion.

Comment: For some reason that was causing me problems earlier but just tried and it works now. many thanks for being more awake than me. I'll re-edit my answer (and you have just saved me 9 bytes :))

Comment: I rewrote the base 3 conversion, it is no longer a lambda, I had to make it a function, but it might be able to be converted back to a lambda. You can find the function [here](https://repl.it/ETcp/0).

Comment: Thanks. I think a combination of the two may work but that's probably a job for tomorrow evening :) Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: The function replaces the lambda, and that is all the complete code is [here](https://repl.it/ETeL/0).

Comment: Just lost both the function and the lambda but will be looking at your code tomorrow. Thanks again. If I can get this under 200 I'll be happy with it.

Comment: I got it down to 169, [here](https://repl.it/ETeL/1).

Comment: @nedla2004 I think that is different enough from mine that you should post it as your own solution. I have no problem with that. Nice work :) As I said, mine was just an idea that I threw out to the community. Nice effort for improving on it.

Comment: I think you mixed up the explanation, but the code is correct.

Comment: Fixed. Got \ and / wrong way round

Comment: and apologies for stealing your `*3`. Just wanted to get below 200 :)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 75 bytes

```
1152.times{|i|$><<"\\/ /\\\\ /"[(i+j=i/48)/4&1|(i-j)/2&2|j&4]+$/*(i%48/47)}
```

Better golfed, using a single 8-byte string lookup indexed by j&4 in addition to the other parameters, rather than a modifiable 4-byte string.

## Ruby, 81 bytes

```
1152.times{|i|j=i/48%8;$><<"\\#{'/\\'[j/4]} /"[(i+j)/4&1|(i-j)/2&2]+$/*(i%48/47)}
```

Prints the diagonal stripes character by character. The correct character is selected from a string of 4 characters depending on the presence / absence of each strand. The overlap character is varied depending on which strand is on top.

**Commented**

```
1152.times{|i|j=i/48%8;        #Iterate through all printable chars. j is line number.
  $><<"\\#{'/\\'[j/4]} /"[     #Print a char from "\/ /" if j/4 even or "\\ /" if odd. character changes depending which strand on top.
   (i+j)/4&1|(i-j)/2&2]+       #Print \ if (i+j)/4==0, / if (i-j)/2&2 >0, space if both false. As above if both true. 
   $/*(i%48/47)                #If on column 47, print a newline.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 96 bytes

```
f n=n`mod`8`div`4
putStr$unlines[["\\ //\\ \\/"!!(f(x-y)+2*f(x+y)+4*f y)|x<-[0..47]]|y<-[0..23]]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 135 bytes

`puts [3320,1212,720,2172,6520,4144,2920,3184].map{|e|(e.to_s(3).rjust(8,"0").gsub("0"," ").gsub("1","\\").gsub("2","/"))*6+"\n"}.join*3`

The number array corresponds to each component of each line, translated to base 3:  = 0, `\` = 1, `/`= 2, then converted to decimal. The gsub() calls are too big, though.

And, just now, I saw @ElPedro's answer. :-( Just coincidence.

Comment: `e.to_s(3).rjust(8,"0")` → `("%8s"%e.to_s(3))`; `gsub("0"," ").gsub("1","\\")..gsub("2","/")` → `tr("013"," \\/")`; `"\n"` → `$/`; `.join` → `*""`. You can also save a byte by dividing all of the numbers in the array by 4 and replacing `e` with `(e*4)`.

Comment: Oops, I guess that ought to be `tr("021"," /\\")`.

Comment: 90 bytes: https://tio.run/##DcjNDkUwEEDhV5FJJG0zl6mhauG@CHJDws5PlMUNnr26Ol/Ofg5/Py21/3yvxjIhE6O2hEUeasLQxAbLgLIyXTL323WPt4DYOojFqHKZHOvPCZYBuwDKNCBEaduCVOZR/PjtPFw0LU3nXw

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>36</s></sup> 34 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
'\/ /\\ /'[(2⊥3<8|⊣,-⍨,+)/¨⍳24 48]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@q8foK@jHxCjoq0drGD3qWmpsY1HzqGuxju6j3hU62pr6h1Y86t1sZKJgYhH7H6jhfxoA)

Because I can't tolerate an APL answer doing so badly.

This is almost a port of [Angs' Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99356/78410). Uses `⎕IO←0`.

#### How it works

```apl
'\/ /\\ /'[(2⊥0⌷2 4⊤⊣,-⍨,+)/¨⍳24 48]
⍳24 48   ⍝ Construct a matrix containing pairs of (0..23),(0..47)
(...)/¨  ⍝ Map over each pair...
⊣,-⍨,+   ⍝   Given two numbers x and y, construct [x,y-x,x+y]
2 4⊤     ⍝   Convert the three numbers to mixed base;
         ⍝   equivalent to n → [n%8/4,n%4] in Python 2
0⌷       ⍝   Extract first row (n%8/4)
2⊥       ⍝   Convert base 2 to integer
'\/ /\\ /'[...]  ⍝ Convert each number in the entire matrix with
                 ⍝ the character at that index
```

Comment: `0⌷2 4⊤` -> `3<8|`

Comment: @ngn Thanks, updated. (Idk why I insisted `⊤` there)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>169</s> <s>161</s> <s>165</s> <s>160</s> <s>155</s> <s>154</s> 152

Based on @ElPedro's answer, with small improvements. To see the explanation, see [their answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99211/59363). This is Python 2, even though there seems to be parenthesis near the `print`.

<s>Saved 8 bytes by using a variable for `replace`.</s> That works only for strings, and using a function for it would be longer.

Saved 4 bytes by seeing that @ElPedro realized that they did not need l, and I did not either.

Saved 5 bytes by not flipping the `range(8)`, and instead of using `+=` to append to r, adding r to the end of the new digit.
Try it using [repl.it](https://repl.it/ETeL/6)

Saved 5 bytes by stealing @ElPedro's new list of values.

Saved 1 byte by removing the space between the `in` and `(`.

Saved 2 bytes by removing the variable a.

```python
for x in(40,4496,6200,5456,3240,1188,720,228)*3:
 r=''
 for i in range(8):r=`x/3**i%3`+r
 print(r*6).replace('0','\\').replace('1','/').replace('2',' ')
```

Comment: You can save 1 by removing the space between `in` and the `(` in the first for

Comment: Also I have lost three bytes by reordering the sequence of which numbers represent each character in the base 3 list. See my answer for explanation. feel free to copy. As far as I am concerned this one is a joint effort and I'm happy to see that my original idea had at least some potential :)

Comment: You don't need `a=3**i`. Just use `for i in range(8):r=`x/3**i%3`+r` to save a couple. operator precedence takes care of the rest :)

Comment: Not sure how to delimit the string conversion characters. The parser removed them in my last comment so don't just copy and paste from my suggestion or it will break :)

Comment: Good point, I understood.

Comment: Here is a sneaky one to save 1 more - `print r.replace('0','\\').replace('1','/').replace('2',' ')*6` (loses one bracket)

Comment: I think that's about as golfed as it gets. Enjoyed working with you on this one. Now it even looks like Python 2 :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 184 bytes

```
<?$p=['1111////',' 11//// ','  ////  ',' ////11 ','////1111','1//  111','11    11','111  //1'];for($j=0;$j<3;$j++)for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)echo str_replace(1,'\\',str_repeat($p[$i],6))."\n";
```

**Output:**

```
C:\PHP>php make-me-a-blanket.php
\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////
 \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\//// 
  ////    ////    ////    ////    ////    ////  
 ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\ 
////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\
\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\
\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\
\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\
\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////
 \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\//// 
  ////    ////    ////    ////    ////    ////  
 ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\ 
////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\
\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\
\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\
\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\
\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////
 \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\////  \\//// 
  ////    ////    ////    ////    ////    ////  
 ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\  ////\\ 
////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\
\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\\//  \\\
\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\\\    \\
\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\\\\  //\
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 89 bytes

```powershell
0..23|%{$y=$_
-join(48..94|%{('\/'[$y%8-lt4]+'\/ ')[(($_+$y)%8-lt4)+2*(($_-$y)%8-ge4)]})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPz8i4RrVapdJWJZ5LNys/M0/DxEJPz9IEKKihHqOvHq1SqWqhm1NiEqsN5Cqoa0ZraKjEa6tUakKENbWNtEAiuhCR9FQTzdhazdr//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 29 bytes

```
•M;(Ð§0—øθε;û…•…/\ Åв8ôJ6×3и»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMiX2uNwxMOLTd41DDl8I5zO85ttT68@1HDMqAMkNSPUTjcemGTxeEtXmaHpxtf2HFo9///AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 130 bytes

```
((\\\\////)( \\//// )(  ////  )( ////\\ )(////\\\\)(\//  \\\)(\\    \\)(\\\  //\)()(::**:*S(
)S)(:(~*a(a)~*^*)~a*^):*:*:*^!^)::**^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcsxDoBACATA3ldgBzT2fONaQnKJdkYTE9v7Oi7e0swGeK/9eM6775nMjmyIME0QRD9KBXdowl3YazXlRMWS1xMkbKZq2niRhsJDO3cZGiqja4hpTawQDiPzAw)

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 152 bytes

```
@call:l
@call:l
:l
@for %%s in (\\\\//// " \\//// " "  ////  " " ////\\ " ////\\\\ "\//  \\\" "\\    \\" "\\\  //\")do @echo %%~s%%~s%%~s%%~s%%~s%%~s
```

String processing in Batch sucks, so this is probably the best approach. The call-and-fall-through is very slightly shorter than a nested `for` loop. At least I don't have to quote my backslashes!

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 110 bytes

I'm new to APL, so this is a simplistic solution.

```
A←48⍴'\\\\////'⋄B←48⍴' \\//// '⋄C←48⍴'  ////  '⋄F←48⍴'\//  \\\'⋄G←48⍴'\\    \\'⋄24 48⍴A,B,C,(⊖B),(⊖A),F,G,⊖F
```

Here's my approach: note that after the first 8 lines of the blanket, the pattern repeats itself. Therefore I only need to define the first 8 lines, and then I can repeat them 3 times. Also note that each line repeats itself after the first 8 characters. Therefore to define a single line I only need to define the first 8 characters and then repeat them 8 times.

Here's an ungolfed solution:

```
A←48⍴'\\\\////'⋄ ⍝ set A to a 48 element vector (48⍴) of repeated '\\\\////'s
B←48⍴' \\//// '⋄ ⍝ set B to a 48 element vector (48⍴) of repeated ' \\//// 's
C←48⍴'  ////  '⋄ ⍝ ...
D←48⍴' ////\\ '⋄ ⍝ Note that this is actually the reverse of vector B
E←48⍴'////\\\\'⋄ ⍝ Note that this is actually the reverse of vector A
F←48⍴'\//  \\\'⋄
G←48⍴'\\    \\'⋄
H←48⍴'\\\  //\'⋄ ⍝ Note that this is actually the reverse of vector F

24 48 ⍴ A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H ⍝ Make a 24 by 48 character matrix (24 48⍴) by concatenating A,B...H
                        ⍝ and repeating the string until the matrix is full
```

I noted above that D is the reverse of B, E is the revers of A, and H is the reverse of F. In my actual code, I take advantage of this by not defining D,F, or H and using the reverse function `⊖`:

`24 48⍴A,B,C,(⊖B),(⊖A),F,G,⊖F`

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 132 bytes

```
puts Zlib.inflate Base64.decode64 "eJzt0bENADAMAsGeKdggC/3+cyQRC+A2ipuT3RgJgHWGUjm6VXb2Vjn/3KpJ/qtIPlp1v+XSKZKPVk3y/x5+D6/3sAEUXQ+Q"
```

very simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 97 bytes

```perl
say s/\d(.)/$1x$&/ger x6for('4\4/| 2\4/ |  4/  | 4/2\ |4/4\|\//  3\|2\4 2\|3\  //\\'=~/[^|]+/g)x3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYpBCsIwEEWvMotiW8T8tkndeYSewFEQrEUQUxIXKQwe3XE278HjrXN6jar5tlEG3xvXoupLtcMyJyrHR0xNHThAaDCSEBlNAQOTBAQWhhXPYoNN4pkIYK5PX5yvctljaYtX/cX184zvrIdpdH3nuj8)