# ASCII rhombic grid

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, grid

Write the shortest code measured by byte count to generate an ASCII grid composed of rhombi, given the following parameters:

- m - number of complete rhombi in one row
- n -  number of rows
- s - side of the smallest rhombus
- r - level of nesting - how many rhombi are there inside the "base ones" (which are fonud between the intersections of the grid)

### Examples

```
1. Input: 5 3 1 0
Output:

/\/\/\/\/\
\/\/\/\/\/
/\/\/\/\/\
\/\/\/\/\/
/\/\/\/\/\
\/\/\/\/\/

A 5x3 grid of rhombi with side 1, no nesting

2. Input: 3 2 2 0
Output:

 /\  /\  /\
/  \/  \/  \
\  /\  /\  /
 \/  \/  \/ 
 /\  /\  /\
/  \/  \/  \
\  /\  /\  /
 \/  \/  \/ 
 
A 3x2 grid of rhombi with side 2, no nesting

3. Input: 5 2 1 2
Output:

///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\
///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\
///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\
\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///
\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///
\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///
///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\
///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\
///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\
\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///
\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///
\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///

A 5x2 grid of rhombi with side 1 (the smallest rhombus), level of nesting is 2

4. Input: 4 2 2 1
Output:

 //\\  //\\  //\\  //\\ 
///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\
//  \\//  \\//  \\//  \\
\\  //\\  //\\  //\\  //
\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///
 \\//  \\//  \\//  \\//   
 //\\  //\\  //\\  //\\ 
///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\
//  \\//  \\//  \\//  \\
\\  //\\  //\\  //\\  //
\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///
 \\//  \\//  \\//  \\//   
 
A 4x2 grid of rhombi with side 2 with level of nesting 1 
 
5. Input: 4 2 3 3
Output:
 
  ////\\\\    ////\\\\    ////\\\\    ////\\\\
 /////\\\\\  /////\\\\\  /////\\\\\  /////\\\\\
//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\
//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\
/////  \\\\\/////  \\\\\/////  \\\\\/////  \\\\\
////    \\\\////    \\\\////    \\\\////    \\\\
\\\\    ////\\\\    ////\\\\    ////\\\\    ////
\\\\\  /////\\\\\  /////\\\\\  /////\\\\\  /////
\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////
\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////
 \\\\\/////  \\\\\/////  \\\\\/////  \\\\\/////  
  \\\\////    \\\\////    \\\\////    \\\\////  
  ////\\\\    ////\\\\    ////\\\\    ////\\\\
 /////\\\\\  /////\\\\\  /////\\\\\  /////\\\\\
//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\
//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\
/////  \\\\\/////  \\\\\/////  \\\\\/////  \\\\\
////    \\\\////    \\\\////    \\\\////    \\\\
\\\\    ////\\\\    ////\\\\    ////\\\\    ////
\\\\\  /////\\\\\  /////\\\\\  /////\\\\\  /////
\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////
\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////\\\\\\//////
 \\\\\/////  \\\\\/////  \\\\\/////  \\\\\/////  
  \\\\////    \\\\////    \\\\////    \\\\////  

A 4x2 grid of rhombi with side 3, level of nesting 3
```

Be sure to display the partially visible rhombi at the edges and corners where necessary.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork By "nesting" I mean the number of rhombi inscribed in the base ones, found between the intersections of the grid.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/98701/36398)

Comment: @Luis Mendo - yes, it's clearly related to my task.

Comment: @Stewie Griffin: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146747/ascii-rhombic-grid#comment359169_146747 — 3rd test case

Comment: Oh, how I miss my pillow!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
ā.I∫e+H╚╬8}:±№╬8╬¡∙*
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwMTAxLkkldTIyMkJlK0gldTI1NUEldTI1NkM4JTdEJTNBJUIxJXUyMTE2JXUyNTZDOCV1MjU2QyVBMSV1MjIxOSo_,inputs=MyUwQTMlMEEyJTBBNA__)
Takes the input in the reversed order of what they are in the examples - r, s, n, m.

Explanation:

```
ā                     push an empty array - canvas
 .I∫      }           for each in range(input) (1-indexed)
    e+                  add the second input
      H                 decrement
       ╚                create a diagonal of that size
        ╬8              insert into the canvas
           :          create a duplicate of the canvas
            ±№        reverse it vertically and horizotally
              ╬8      insert that into the canvas
                ╬¡    quad-palindromize
                  ∙   multiply vertically by the next input
                   *  multiply horizontally by the next input
```

Comment: This is just amazing, how do you even compress such a program in 20 bytes.

Comment: This is just brilliant... +1 from me for beating Charcoal by a staggering 28 bytes :O

Comment: That''s really impressive!

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder 19 bytes now. But then I'm up against builtins like `∙*`...

Comment: @Neil `*` is basically vercorized repetition, and `∙` - non-vectorized repetition. Those two built-ins together should be <=4 bytes in many golfing languages

Comment: Vectorised string repeating is reasonably short in Charcoal; if I could build up a string representation of the diamond it would only cost me 6 bytes to repeat it. Unfortunately it takes me 50 bytes to do that. On the other hand, drawing the diamond only takes me 17 bytes, just 1 more than SOGL... but it then takes 20 bytes to multiply the canvas.

Comment: @neil I had a feeling it was like that. I'm guessing that Charcoal can't get the canvas as a single string?

Answer (score 9):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>48</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
ＵＯ⊕Ｉε\Ｆ⊖ＩζＣ¹¦¹‖ＭL≔⊗⁺ＩζＩεδＦ⊖ＮＣδ⁰Ｆ⊖ＮＣ⁰δ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY07C8IwFIV3f0XodAMRWnHSSdql4AvnLm16@4A0KTeJoH8@BqEO4iB3OVy@cz451CRNrUK4NMroHkotCSfUDlvIa@sAORcsqaqE71edIQYFfhFPzjnLzfyATLAsYjfsFEp3GokMwe4YXwdrx15DYXyjYu@qvF3Kgi2eGNtfllLP3p391CDBx9UKlv4Np@/lELZsEy8L67t6AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＵＯ⊕Ｉε\
```

Draw a square of size `r + 1`. This is a quarter of a nested diamond of size 1.

```
Ｆ⊖ＩζＣ¹¦¹
```

Copy the square 1 square right and down `s - 1` times to get it to the right size.

```
‖ＭL
```

Reflect it to become a full nested diamond.

```
≔⊗⁺ＩζＩεδ
```

Compute the size of this nested diamond.

```
Ｆ⊖ＮＣδ⁰
```

Copy the diamond to the right `m - 1` times.

```
Ｆ⊖ＮＣ⁰δ
```

Copy the diamond downwards `n - 1` times.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>160</s> <s>159</s> 158 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Frech</sup>

```python
m,n,s,r=input()
l=~-s*' '+'/'*(r-~r)+~-s*' '
for x in range(n*2):print'\n'.join(m*(l[i:i+s+r]+l.replace(*'/\\')[i:i+s+r][::-1])for i in range(r+s))[::1-x%2*2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxNCoMwEEDhvafIpkx@FaOrgCdRF1JsmxLHMLFgN149baG02/fBi8/ttqLNedGok6bOY3xsXBShO0ySwEBBBZKTOUiobyouK7GdeWQ04XXmKK1wkTxuMCCU99UjXyQPvXdeJUWjCiXNMUznmUuohgHEj3rnTD2Kz9H/j6SSEG@qzX6y0o45t9rqRjcv)

This uses the fact that the bottom of the rhombus is the top inverted (`[::-1]`), iterating over `range(n*2)` and using `~x%2*2-1` to control if it is the top or the bottom.
For the top (and the bottom) the right side is just the left side inverted and replacing `/` with `\` -> `l.replace(*'/\\')..[::-1]`
To generate the pattern / nesting `~-s*' '+'/'*(1+r*2)+~-s*' '` is used to make a string like   `///`   that will be iterated and chopped :

```python
   '|  //|/  '  
  ' | ///|  '  
 '  |/// | '  
'  /|//  |'
```

Comment: I think `(1+r*2)` can be `(r-~r)`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 190 bytes

```julia
g(n,m,s,r)=(s+=r+1;f(i,j,u=mod(i-j+r,2s),v=mod(j+i+r,2s))=(" \\/")[abs(u-r)<abs(v-r)?1+(u<=2r):1+2(v<=2r)];
for i=1:2(s-1)m println((f(i+(i-1)÷(s-1),s+j+(j-1)÷(s-1))for j=1:2(s-1)n)...)end)
```

This is a functional solution which computes for every index pair `i,j` what the symbol should be displayed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5RDoIwEESvQvjazS6YbaIfSONBxA8MYtpAMa3lah7Ag2HBRP/ezO5kxsbBtIdluYPjkQN71BBIe5JjD4YtRz1OHZjCkmcVkOdNWzJfnd7zrGl2OZ7ba4BYeKxXmBOchCDWWnmshBTMG16O/eQzo6VSEArBMXt4456DA0iFlJoE36/txIEsgf0buEbtL@qwLEu8uQ7T/D0rFla4fAA)

#### Illustration

Start with a grid

```julia
f(i,j,u=mod(i,2s),v=mod(j,2s))=(" -|*")[1+(u==0)+2(v==0)]
for i=1:2(s-1)m println((f(i-1,j)for j=1:2(s-1)n)...)end

---------*---------*----
         |         |    
         |         |    
         |         |    
         |         |    
         |         |    
         |         |    
         |         |    
         |         |    
         |         |    
---------*---------*----
         |         |    
         |         |    
         |         |    
         |         |    
         |         |
```

`r > 0` means thicker lines

```julia
f(i,j,u=mod(i+r,2s),v=mod(j+r,2s))=(" -|*")[1+(u<=2r)+2(v<=2r)]
for i=1:2(s-1)m println((f(i,j)for j=1:2(s-1)n)...)end

**-----*****-----*****--
**-----*****-----*****--
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
**-----*****-----*****--
**-----*****-----*****--
**-----*****-----*****--
**-----*****-----*****--
**-----*****-----*****--
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||
```

Handle the corners by checking which line on the original grid is closest

```julia
f(i,j,u=mod(i+r,2s),v=mod(j+r,2s))=(" -|")[abs(u-r)<abs(v-r)?1+(u<=2r):1+2(v<=2r)]
for i=1:2(s-1)m println((f(i,j)for j=1:2(s-1)n)...)end

|-------|||-------|||---
||-----|||||-----|||||--
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||-----|||||-----|||||--
|-------|||-------|||---
---------|---------|----
|-------|||-------|||---
||-----|||||-----|||||--
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||  
||     |||||     |||||
```

A fairy tells us to remove every `s-1` line

```julia
f(i,j,u=mod(i+r,2s),v=mod(j+r,2s))=(" -|")[abs(u-r)<abs(v-r)?1+(u<=2r):1+2(v<=2r)]
for i=1:2(s-1)m println((f(i+(i-1)÷(s-1),s+j+(j-1)÷(s-1))for j=1:2(s-1)n)...)end

---||------||------||---
--||||----||||----||||--
  ||||    ||||    ||||  
  ||||    ||||    ||||  
  ||||    ||||    ||||  
  ||||    ||||    ||||  
--||||----||||----||||--
---||------||------||---
---||------||------||---
--||||----||||----||||--
  ||||    ||||    ||||  
  ||||    ||||    ||||  
  ||||    ||||    ||||  
  ||||    ||||    ||||  
--||||----||||----||||--
---||------||------||---
```

Traverse diagonally and done

```julia
f(i,j,u=mod(i-j+r,2s),v=mod(j+i+r,2s))=(" \\/")[abs(u-r)<abs(v-r)?1+(u<=2r):1+2(v<=2r)]
for i=1:2(s-1)m println((f(i+(i-1)÷(s-1),s+j+(j-1)÷(s-1))for j=1:2(s-1)n)...)end

 ///\\\  ///\\\  ///\\\ 
////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\
////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\
///  \\\///  \\\///  \\\
\\\  ///\\\  ///\\\  ///
\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////
\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////
 \\\///  \\\///  \\\/// 
 ///\\\  ///\\\  ///\\\ 
////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\
////\\\\////\\\\////\\\\
///  \\\///  \\\///  \\\
\\\  ///\\\  ///\\\  ///
\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////
\\\\////\\\\////\\\\////
 \\\///  \\\///  \\\///
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 154 bytes

```js
f=
(m,n,s,r)=>[...Array((s+=r)*n*2)].map((_,i)=>[...Array(s*m*2)].map((_,j)=>i/s&1^j/s&1?`\\ `[g(j%s)]:`/ `[g(s-1-j%s)],g=j=>i%s-j>r|j-i%s>r).join``).join`
`
```

```html
<div oninput=o.textContent=f(+m.value,+n.value,+s.value,+r.value)>
m: <input type=number min=0 id=m><br>
n: <input type=number min=0 id=n><br>
s: <input type=number min=0 id=s><br>
r: <input type=number min=0 id=r></div>
<pre id=o>
```

Directly calculates the character at each cell of the output.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 44

```
q~:R+,_ff{-zR>}{_W%:~\+"\ /"f=}%_W%Wf%+*f*N*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7E%3AR%2B%2C_ff%7B-zR%3E%7D%7B_W%25%3A%7E%5C%2B%22%5C%20%2F%22f%3D%7D%25_W%25Wf%25%2B*f*N*&input=4%202%203%203)

**Explanation:**

```
q~           read and evaluate the input
:R+          save the last number in variable R, then add the last 2 numbers (s+r)
,_           make an array [0 1 … s+r-1] and duplicate it
ff{…}        make a matrix, calculating for each (x,y) pair from the 2 arrays:
  -z         abs(x-y)
  R>         compared with R (1 if greater, 0 if not)
{…}%         transform each row of the matrix:
  _W%        duplicate and reverse it
  :~         bitwise-NOT each element (0 → -1, 1 → -2)
  \+         prepend to the original row
  "\ /"f=    replace numbers with characters from this string (by index):
              0 → '\'; 1, -2 → ' '; -1 → '/'
              this generates the "/\" part
_W%          duplicate the matrix and reverse the rows
Wf%+         reverse each row, then append (by rows) to the original matrix
              this adds the "\/" part
*            repeat the matrix (by rows) n times
f*           repeat each row m times
N*           join the rows with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 167 bytes

```cs
(c,r,s,n)=>{int w=s+n,i=0,j;var g="";for(;i<r*2*w;i++,g+="\n")for(j=0;j<c*2*w;){int y=i%w,q=(j/w+i/w+1)%2,p=~-w*q+j++%w*(1-2*q);g+=p>y+n|p<y-n?' ':"\\/"[q];}return g;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY8xT8MwEIVn8iusSFHt@EKbhC44DgMSLCBVMDBQhmBCcNQ6je02ikr468GthIRYqE53y/vu6T1hItHoctwaqSr02BtbrpknVoUxaLH3jC2sFOhmq0QmlQX05xir3V@OHj6a9asUt1q@IY5GLECDAUV4vncc6rihCiSfQc12hUYV93323mjMZKbDJOyYpBQqyv2l8slBqPmM1Zk4auTo0XMZdNByXE87Kt3GJEhgw7@iLmxpTWnQhTiOkrAlzDlt8p6qz03WR@pqgiaX/nI59Z/bFzbo0m61QhUbRub9NNw1Lvl9IRUm3t47u26UaVbl@ZOWtryTqsS/GuI5pBDDjBD2H5lC4uYUcu64GJITyIujZ3wimUJ6IAdvGL8B)

I'm surprised by the size I managed; I was initially expecting a longer solution. In saying this, I'm sure there are other tricks I've missed.

#### DeGolfed

```cs
(c,r,s,n)=>{
    int w=s+n, // rhombus quadrant width, and height
        i=0, // string row
        j; // string column

    var g="";

    // go through every character row and column
    for(; i < r*2*w; i++, g += "\n")
        for(j = 0; j < c*2*w;)
        {
            int y = i % w, // vertical position in the quadrant
                q = ( j / w + i / w + 1) % 2, // Get the rhombus quadrant as a 0 or 1
                p = ~-w * q + j++ % w * (1-2*q); // horizontal position in quadrant. the value is either ascending or descending depending on the quadrant

            // select which character to use at this [i,j] position
            g += p > y + n | p < y - n ? ' ' : "\\/"[q];
        }

    return g;
}
```

Comment: [163 bytes](https://tio.run/##jY/BToNAEIbP8hQbklqWHWwBe3FZPJjoRROjBw/WA66IQ9oFdrclpNZXR2hiYrzYTGYu832T@aUJZKXzfmNQFeSxMzZfc0euMmPI/c4xNrMoyfVGyQSVBfJnGKsHLyUPH9X6FeWNxjciSO9J0GBAUZHutpkmhXBd/l5pb5BIKwxTgGIOJXTQQM0x0X7ktxwZg4IJd6lcOtKlmPMykYddI8pZy3Do8DSEWnwFrd@wkrFJ63thEPkNHd067Zj6rJMuUJdTMr1wl8uZ@9y80E7gpOU6txutSMH3PXd@0m2r4eu7DJVHnZ1zclUpU63ysyeNNr9FlXu/0nkLiCGEOaX8PzKGaKhjyMXAhRAdQZ4fboZHkjHEI7l39v03 "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>201</s> 189 bytes

```python
def f(m,n,s,r):Z=range(s+r);R=[r-~min(i,s+~i+r,min(s-1,r))for i in Z];L=[m*(' '*(s+~i)+'/'*R[i]+'  '*(i-r)+'\\'*R[i]+' '*(s+~i))for i in Z];print'\n'.join((L+[l[s+r:]+l[:s+r]for l in L])*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY67DoMgFED3fgUbr2tbtS4a/8DJUWRoUmlpFA24dPHXKZjYpGE5nJzce5fP@ppN5v1jUEiRCQw4sLTsans3z4E4bmnV1sIm26QN0eD4prmF@HFJGlKqZos00gZ1smpqMTGCEWYkhpTjC2at0JJjFKVObHB9/5NH@DdlsdqsuDf4/J7DHtJwMYpwSSn5KMoAMtZjrBtJmaFekQJySOFKT4rkkIW3YxEghSzibbfpgTnk1H8B)

Uses the fact that the bottom is the same as the top, but shifted:

```python
Top:       /\/\/\
Bottom:     /\/\/\
```

Saved 22 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech

Comment: `s-i-1` can be `s+~i`, saving two bytes. `r+1+min(...` can be `r-~min(...`, saving another one. `L=[(...)*m for` can be `L=[m*(...)for`, saving one more byte.

Comment: `L+=[...];print'\n'.join(L*n)` can be `print'\n'.join((L+[...])*n)` to save another byte, resulting in [196 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY07EoMwDER7TuHOPzmZQCpmuAEVrXGRIh9lQGYEKdJwdccukiqVVk@7q@W9PSLVKc1AsAJ3SMtrU7oaOs9un5EUwmrZoTtB2dY8WetbZIECSfCF7leVHTpUfedno6SQJoMdtZVHaQaPwUpRIDrObBx/8Gv8X7cw0iZHkodnzJ9Vb/3k86kNdvJtFqHEphLrgzakUzpDDQ00Hw).

Comment: [195 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY05EoMwDEV7TuHOm0gmkIoZbkBFa1ykyKIMyIxMijRc3bGLpEqn/6T3tb63R6AmpQUIInCPtL42pauxd1zvC5JCiHZHy1BCrE/AWt8CCxRIgi90v6poWftq6N1ilBTSqGJoK4/SjA69laJArDmzafrB7@H/upWRNjmRPDxD/qwG62aXV523s@vy4Is2F23w2pBO6QwNtNB@AA), if one also replaces `s+r-i-1` with `s+~i+r`.

Comment: [190 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY67DoJAEEV7vmK7fQ0a0QrDH1BRsmxh4WMMDGQWCxt@fd0tNLGbe3Jy7yzv9TFTFeMEBAG4QVpeq9LnvuEL3a8qWNZF1zgutwlJIQS7oWXIIZQHYK1vMwsUSKL3Rdu4ySgppFFZ1FbupekceitFhlhyYsPwg1/xr2VhpFUOJHfPOe2o1rrRpU9qb0dXp8Nne8x267UhHeMJKjjC8QM).

Comment: Alternative [192 bytes version](https://tio.run/##PY1BCsIwEEWvEgolmWSqWF219AZduY1ZiFQdaadlUkE3Xr2mCA58@Dz@Y6b3fB@5XJYBGSNKQzw9ZwN19@ou2bHxUnwGYrMmFjsUQEJxeazbxg/WaKWtie5D4PRW26On4LRaIRWS2CndH2ubxyw3JvsZcB1FkSJWcuZbl6BAyBBsCfUkxLM@sd48xvTatM73Pg2q4HpfpRJWuV/lNoBlWJYDlrjH/Rc) or [191 bytes version](https://tio.run/##PY3BCoJAFEV/ZRBk5s08i7SV4R@4ajvOIsLqhT7ljUFt/HVTghYXLufAveNnegycL0uPjBGlIh5fk4FT@26vSpJz5SWbe2KzJWYHFEBCcWmsK99bo5W2JrqZwOm9tmdPwWm1QcpkZU3zh9qmcRTiSTesd89hHTS1852PTsrgOl@uJdwGUZ0iVnUAy5CkxiS/A9gUbUoufG9XKBBOCYLNYVmOmGOBxRc) using `exec` and string formatting.

Comment: [189 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY47DoMwEESv4s6/JVEgFYgbUFFiXEQKThzBgtY0abi6YxeJlG7n6Wlmt/f@XLGM8T455sQCCAFI1kNLN3xMImiSTd8aKo7Fo/AQ9OE1QQ6huCRVupWYZx7ZYJuuNYsSnHElsig1P3PVG281Zxn6ghIbxx/8in8tG3nc@Yj89FrTjui0mU36pLZ6NnU6bLbnbHdWKpTRiSuUUEEl4wc) by using an imperative function.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 159 + 3 (-anl) bytes

```
($m,$n,$s,$r)=@F;$s=$"x($s+$r-1);$_="$s/\\$s"x$m;$n*=2;{$t=$_;map$t=~s, ?(\S) ?,$1x$&=~y///c,ge,1..$r;print$t;redo if s, /,/ ,g&&s,\\ , \\,g||y,/\\,\\/,&&--$n}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##DY3RCoIwGEZf5Uc@htZvS6urMeqqF@h2IFImgs6xeWFUPnrLu8OBw3GN708xphgYlhEYPtOXq0LQSOYUYQufF5lCpRMEaQxCMmNQsBtdqjcmjUoNtVthCUzn1NwyOjOKGUIvLynlnduGi90OXjnf2QmT8s1jpO5JayBZErdCBDaGmIzh9vN58TpahWQh8hz2G@ORSjrQ/je6qRttiHlt@z8)