# Draw this diamond pattern

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

The below pattern will form the basis of this challenge.

```
     /\
     \/
     /\
    /  \
   /    \
/\/      \/\
\/\      /\/
   \    /
    \  /
     \/
     /\
     \/
```

Given an input width and height, each `>=1`, output the above ASCII art pattern repeated that many times, joining (and overlapping) at the small diamonds.

For example, here is an input with `width = 2` and `height = 1`:

```
     /\        /\
     \/        \/
     /\        /\
    /  \      /  \
   /    \    /    \
/\/      \/\/      \/\
\/\      /\/\      /\/
   \    /    \    /
    \  /      \  /
     \/        \/
     /\        /\
     \/        \/
```

Here is an input `width = 3` and `height = 2`:

```
     /\        /\        /\
     \/        \/        \/
     /\        /\        /\
    /  \      /  \      /  \
   /    \    /    \    /    \
/\/      \/\/      \/\/      \/\
\/\      /\/\      /\/\      /\/
   \    /    \    /    \    /
    \  /      \  /      \  /
     \/        \/        \/
     /\        /\        /\
     \/        \/        \/
     /\        /\        /\
    /  \      /  \      /  \
   /    \    /    \    /    \
/\/      \/\/      \/\/      \/\
\/\      /\/\      /\/\      /\/
   \    /    \    /    \    /
    \  /      \  /      \  /
     \/        \/        \/
     /\        /\        /\
     \/        \/        \/
```

#### Rules and I/O

- Input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print it to STDOUT or return it as a function result.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- Any amount of extraneous whitespace is acceptable, so long as the characters line up appropriately.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: [Loosely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/98701/36398)

Answer (score 10):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>26</s> <s>25</s> <s>24</s> <s>21</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
４／╬/╬⁰ｒ：⤢ｎ↷⁸｛Ａ×├ｍ↷
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjE0JXVGRjBGJXUyNTZDLyV1MjU2QyV1MjA3MCV1RkY1MiV1RkYxQSV1MjkyMiV1RkY0RSV1MjFCNyV1MjA3OCV1RkY1QiV1RkYyMSVENyV1MjUxQyV1RkY0RCV1MjFCNw__,i=JTVCMyUyQzIlNUQ_,v=8)

-3 bytes by fixing `ｍ` not repeating canvas

Explanation:

```
4/╬                 quad-palindromize a 4-long diagonal - big inner diamond
   /╬               quad-palindromize "/" - small diamond
     ⁰r             join the two vertically, centered
       :⤢n          overlap with transpose
           ↷        and rotate the thing clockwise
            ⁸{      for each input
              A×      times 10
                ├     plus 2
                 m    mold the canvas to that width
                  ↷   and rotate clockwise, setting up for the next iteration
```

Comment: wow O_o canvas is too short

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>167</s> <s>161</s> 159 bytes

<sup>*NB: This is encoding the pattern. See [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175685/58563) for a shorter mathematical approach.*</sup>

Takes input as `(width)(height)`.

```javascript
w=>h=>(g=h=>h?g(--h)+`
`+([4106,4016,31305,21504,17010]['0102344320'[h%=10]]+'').replace(/./g,c=>'\\/'[c^h>5]||''.padEnd(c-1)).repeat(w+1).slice(8):'')(h*10+2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBboMwEEX3vUflmdgYj23SKpLpqqcgVLGMgxMhQAGFTe5OrWze4uv9d/dPv4THbV6LcerifnX75urkauhdZvrpoSgS8svHhUNjSR2FVXQUhoyqhKZKWUFfilTbsExtrDVasSZ9ury1nDGUjzgPPkQoZdmL4Gp2PpesCX@prtrXizE5@@537CAUhG87@hU2TiiX4ZZ/33jKGUgHUlzjHqZxmYYoh6mHKxgEjbj/Aw)

#### How?

We encode the upper half of the pattern with digits:

- \$0\$ means `\`
- \$1\$ means `/`
- \$n=2\$ to \$7\$ means \$n-1\$ spaces

This gives:

```
0  ···/\·····  -->  [3 spaces] [/] [\] [5 spaces]             -->  4106
1  ···\/·····  -->  [3 spaces] [\] [/] [5 spaces]             -->  4016
0  ···/\·····  -->  [3 spaces] [/] [\] [5 spaces]             -->  4106
2  ··/··\····  -->  [2 spaces] [/] [2 spaces] [\] [4 spaces]  -->  31305
3  ·/····\···  -->  [1 space] [/] [4 spaces] [\] [3 spaces]   -->  21504
4  /······\/\  -->  [/] [6 spaces] [\] [/] [\]                -->  17010
```

For the lower half, we use the rows \$4,3,2,0\$ with `/` and `\` inverted.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 139 bytes

This is using quite a different approach from my initial answer, so I'm posting this separately.

Takes input as `(width)(height)`.

```javascript
w=>h=>(g=x=>y>8?` /\\
`[a=(x+y*9)%10,d=(x+y)%10,x?(y%10>3&&2*(a==8)|d==5)|(y%10<6&&2*(a==6)|d==7):3]+g(x--?x:--y&&w):'')(w=w*10+2,y=-~h*10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcjbCoJAFIXh@56im3RvdcoDmUl7fJAMHDwW4kRGzoD06pMIXa1/fQ/xEWP5uj/fbJBVbRoyE/GOOLSkiGueZMX2kOeb4ioIlKudM@4C36vWs6bKQC/LI8sKHRBECc4V0RHn1S/x3@PVT5hGN7cFxVimUsa0ZU2Y2jbCRJMT@G7oaWLfbkk0pRxG2df7XrbQQIQQIpof)

#### How?

Given the width \$w\$ and the height \$h\$, we draw the output character by character over a grid which is:

- \$10w+3\$ characters wide
- \$10h+2\$ characters high

with \$x\$ going from \$10w+2\$ to \$0\$ (left to right) and \$y\$ going from \$10h+10\$ to \$9\$ (top to bottom).

Example for \$w=3\$ and \$h=2\$:

$$\begin{matrix}(32,30)&(31,30)&\dots&(0,30)\\
(32,29)&(31,29)&&(0,29)\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
(32,9)&(31,9)&\dots&(0,9)\end{matrix}$$

The rightmost cells (at \$x=0\$) are simply filled with linefeeds.

For all other cells, we compute:

- \$a=(x-y)\bmod 10\$ (constant over anti-diagonals)
- \$d=(x+y)\bmod 10\$ (constant over diagonals)

We draw a `"/"` if:

$$((y\bmod 10)>3\text{ and }d=5)\text{ or }((y\bmod 10)<6\text{ and }d=7)$$

```
 y  | y % 10 | output (w = 3, h = 1)
----+--------+----------------------------------
 20 |    0   | ...../........./........./......
 19 |    9   | ....../........./........./.....
 18 |    8   | ...../........./........./......
 17 |    7   | ..../........./........./.......
 16 |    6   | .../........./........./........
 15 |    5   | /./......././......././......./.
 14 |    4   | ./......././......././......././
 13 |    3   | ......../........./........./...
 12 |    2   | ......./........./........./....
 11 |    1   | ....../........./........./.....
 10 |    0   | ...../........./........./......
  9 |    9   | ....../........./........./.....
```

We draw a `"\"` if:

$$((y\bmod 10)>3\text{ and }a=8)\text{ or }((y\bmod 10)<6\text{ and }a=6)$$

```
 y  | y % 10 | output (w = 3, h = 1)
----+--------+----------------------------------
 20 |    0   | ......\.........\.........\.....
 19 |    9   | .....\.........\.........\......
 18 |    8   | ......\.........\.........\.....
 17 |    7   | .......\.........\.........\....
 16 |    6   | ........\.........\.........\...
 15 |    5   | .\.......\.\.......\.\.......\.\
 14 |    4   | \.\.......\.\.......\.\.......\.
 13 |    3   | ...\.........\.........\........
 12 |    2   | ....\.........\.........\.......
 11 |    1   | .....\.........\.........\......
 10 |    0   | ......\.........\.........\.....
  9 |    9   | .....\.........\.........\......
```

Or we draw a space if none of these conditions is fulfilled.

Comment: This is really cool.

Comment: [111 using the C++ answer?](https://tio.run/##JYvLDoIwEEX3foUbYMY6WkAT0qTlQ8QEgjw0hBoxtt3467XEzc05J7mP5tMs7ev@fNOsb53vpTdSjVLBIK1Ujoqy3lbVcVNfbGBwUcqZDYNRQee/0@qsWMup5CIVmcivbABLFC5WOKI4NiiSBMFI@ppdyvcuwBgAfavnRU/dYdID9JAjZIj@Bw)

Comment: @Arnauld I knew this was your answer by just looking at the code :D

Answer (score 6):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 137 bytes

```cpp
#include<cstdio>
auto p(int x,int y){int n=10,t=x=++x*n;for(++y*=n;y>8;)t>7?putchar(t<9?y--,n:t%n-y%n+4&7?t%n+y%n-5&7?32:47:92),t--:t=x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/BboMwDIbP4ymiTh1Jk0xdYWJNAkh7jl5QYG3U1kHUkUBVn52FHSbtsov/T7b1/7bte3m0dn52YC@h7Yhx/oZD11yr356xN2ydr5ImoCc9dYBkFEud2H0RKN@2Asux5HzcgP7yA@V82pSgp@pDM6yKug9oT81A0ezrSUoBCtcgpzXw/KWoI/PI8j1ytlN5ofY7JlBKFV31Y15Cro0Dysg9IfEapawPaMzq0wdoiT119vx6gJUxP8P4gYMjzbYilSkzJj1AqpOnnmYiZ/qPwz/7j/kb)

*Explanation*

```cpp
_______________________________
   098765432109876.... 
   9    \/    .     factor =y%10 - x10
   8    /\    .     if factor = -4 || 4. Print --> '\'  47
   7   /  \   . 
   6  /    \  .     factor =x%10+y%10;  
   5\/      \/*-.   if factor = 5 || 13 --> /  92
   4/\      /\   `.
   3  \    /       `->  * is 9,5 => \
   2   \  /      
   1    \/   
   0    /\       
   9
```

Comment: Invalid, not a full program nor a function

Comment: But, 10/10 a very nice method

Comment: Sorry I was confused because some of the other answer are not full program too. I repair it!

Comment: Which answers exactly aren't full programs or functions? (just asking, may have missed it) Note that some languages (e.g. scripting languages) don't need boilerplate for full programs

Comment: [I think you need to include the `#include`](https://tio.run/##PY1BDoIwEEXXcopuSFrbJgoYkaFyFjJGZcHQkNHQEM5e6cbNz8t7i4/e2xdijN9peAgvB2KxmLRBrfjuZ4GG3PkESTFoHY6O4DnNUuslYbjXEKw1OH24bUmlxG6BumXgv0eFToacLOekK5XXnUy0m53tpSuLpro2twK2mI7GfiCpxJodvCxNpSDb4g8)

Comment: [159](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoMwFETX9SsCRchtEmjVUmuMfotc@wi0MdhYDOK3p2bXzXCYMzBorXgghrDXBl9Tf6vx43o9NMl30D2xVBtHZh7Tw4LPbiTIjTodZaycZMwflJH3YaSMzRF9U0ovBLeTi3NqAKJ1apZl7aT7UwiAivrUCJcaVkBatjTS1mwszm2eVcWlumZyDfHu3WlDgSzJztKcFyCTNfwA), but not sure if outputting from a function is valid (it probably is)

Comment: [181, program](https://tio.run/##PcnRCoIwFIDhe59iEII2B6VG5tH5LONoNsij6BEc0bMvvenu4/9xmlSP6P3JEr7XtqvsuPDcmUEH62KpF2SGbpkMdmLhFgJLLAZjKYo/B7fEJQz4MrPAhOrrBdCS1pvWDqR055rgOc6RlNtBpwtwSiU4rlxVFB@L6w2KioH/HWOsIxeS4pBkHodFEx3ay251a7K0zO/lI4Wv95nIfg)

Comment: Since I see snippets on header and footer sections in most codes I thought I could put #include <iostream> using namespace std ; in header and the main function with a call to my function in the footer. Every c++ program has this surrounding structure. The function takes 2 arguments and do the job. I don't see any reason to penalize c++

Comment: @AZTECCO First of all, welcome to PPCG. You may be interested in [our current consensus regarding valid submissions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet); instead of writing a full program you are allowed to only write a function, however not a snippet (being a very untethered piece of code). Furthermore, I would also be interested in seeing non-complying answers, as ASCII-only stated above.

Comment: @Jonathan Frech I'm confused, why my function is considered a snippet? Do I have to declare it as std::string funcName(int x... instead of a closure? Do I have to include iostream? My function takes the two arguments and return the solution, i checked the I/O rules and it seems it's fine to do so..

Comment: Edited using Tio, I hope it's alright now. A special thanks to downvoters, very helpful for newcomers.. Good job! And true thanks for who helped

Comment: @AZTECCO Sorry for any confusion. The way it is right now is perfectly fine, an anonymous lambda function would -- I think -- also be valid.

Comment: As a bit-fiddling golfing trick: `(y%n-t%n+4)%8` can most likely be `y%n-t%n+4&7`.

Comment: Thaks for your help @Jonathan Frech! I think there's no big difference in bytes between lambda and normal function. And thanks for the trick!

Comment: [173](https://tio.run/##TY7NDoIwEITP8hQkBtNamviDAWnBZyEVtYlsSVkSGuKzY6sHvWxmv8nOrOp7fldqWWtQz/HaSm0GtG3T1T/kgYZ7HQ14LcvvEvdEA8ZTGqaj879lhHo0NoZqvxOMuW0F4mYsYWwK0tWFcJynhlVAAw8JWE2ikCiQc@qNcE9cAhwTYNkmv5AgPKBJwU@X46HM8vJ8oMK2OFrwja8lxHSNBkLjOVp9/lFmRCl7ckwzKqLX8gY) - you don't use `cout` in your function so you only really need `<string>` for `std::string`

Comment: [155](https://tio.run/##RY5NCoMwEIXX9RRCaTFNAloFW6P2LBKtBGoS4ggJ4tltYhfdzPC99@aHa01HzvezkPyz9EMt1Axm6Kb2L3lByLGNugVUrBMhIQYSqkPrDH1V/QKxYm9lEozh1mQpwdiFzlz7YI5SorAnFBJh1DbArHcspcg77pKl1PqCi2v5CoQPyj3l96ooq@edmQEWI/2ZbQ8rpk7IBMVrdDqe4GqButZJTgrEom3/Ag)

Comment: Edited thanks to @ASCII-only and Jonathan Frech help.

Comment: @AZTECCO wait, if you use `cout` in your functionm, you need to include the `#include` in the bytecount

Comment: Saved some bytes thanks to @ceilingcat good tip use c style, plus with one more ternary I left one loop.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 179 bytes

```hs
k '\\'='/'
k '/'='\\'
k x=x
f x=take(10*x+2)
w#h=map(f w.cycle).f h.drop 9.cycle$(++).reverse=<<map(map k)$["\\/\\      /","   \\    / ","    \\  /  ","     \\/   ","     /\\   "]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxRD4IgEAfwdz/FDd2QbFCulzb5BvXUY7TGDGdDzaGlfXq6ZMV28P/d7qj1YE3TeG@BKkUlFTTCKDAhMc5yjiq8R21Nut2s5ixn0RTXstV9WsHEy3fZGMYrqPnNPXrYh06SZhnjzryMG4wsiu84FliWnIlSQilYjiBrgk@ggKCFAn5CIv4Ku@TiW33vQAJ@e7xC/xxPozt0kMAuzv0H)

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 181 bytes

```hs
k '\\'='/'
k '/'='\\'
k x=x
f x=take(10*x+2)
w#h=map(f w.cycle).f h.drop 9.cycle$(++).reverse=<<map(map k)$map t[49200,36058,31630,30010,29038]
t 0=""
t n="\\ /"!!mod n 3:t(div n 3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxLDoJADAbgPaeoQAIjBAqjRAxzA125FGMIDMHwkMAIeHoscdH@X5umVTbWsmnWtQYrTS1h@ZZG9Ek0EhexaCV1ldXSDnC/OCHTZqMSbdbbJcxe/s0bybwSKq8Y3j3E/41pOw7zBjnJYZQiSbZzKqiZuYW6H@IQ0eURHk8uDyJORgzQDWPkp4emAIWuU3RCT1Pw9d2ufRfQAT8ru3hNm9jaZq8OBNDH6xP6j7qp4dKBCQcjXH8)

Comment: Using `reverse.map(map k)<>id` over `(++).reverse=<<map(map k)` saves you 3 bytes in both solutions.

Comment: Ah, and in the 2nd one `map t` can become `t<$>` and `take$10*x+2` saves another byte too and finally you can use `cycle"\\ /"!!n` over `"\\ /"!!mod n 3` - now the second one is shorter :)  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBboMwEETvfMWGWAK3yBicRiHCnHJsTj2WqrKCERZgkOMk5Ovptj3MzJvVajp17fUwrGacJ@fhpLxi58lOpoE4LitK1x6iuo5klEYBYoqEFXGRS9Cie9VrkvGX5TUPHttOjmqOW3iwy/MyaMpa6FjjphmK/wtx@q7dVbPfPxT0tKxMQ3xJqs9dkXOeiD1/OyQi2wtkzjOe5AUXh6/AA5dhiGHl31ZY15CGm409@rgxd7Ag6DoqY0ECTp@/Yb75D@/eLRDYbfP1Bw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
\/↘²‖Ｍ↘LＦ⊖ＮＣχ⁰Ｆ⊖ＮＣ⁰χ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREMpJkZfSdOaC8KzcskvzwvKTM8o0VEwAooGpablpCaX@GYWFeUXocha@QCl0/KLFDRcUpOLUnNT80pSUzQ88wpKS/xKc5NSizQ0NTUVnPMLKjUMDXQUDIhWDVRsCFT9/78xl9F/3bIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
´\/↘²
```

Draw one eighth of the original pattern.

```
‖Ｍ↘L
```

Duplicate it three times to complete the original pattern.

```
Ｆ⊖ＮＣχ⁰
```

Copy the required number of times horizontally.

```
Ｆ⊖ＮＣ⁰χ
```

Copy the required number of times vertically.

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 146 bytes

```powershell
param($w,$h)0..9*$h+0,1|%{$y=$_
-join(0..9*$w+0,1|%{('3  /\33  \/33  /\33 /  \3  /3 \ /\/33\\/\33/3\3 /3  \  /33 \/3'-replace3,'   ')[$y*10+$_]})}
```

### Explanation

The pattern is 10x10 chars array:

```powershell
     /\   
     \/   
     /\   
    /  \  
   /    \ 
/\/      \
\/\      /
   \    / 
    \  /  
     \/
```

The script:

- repeats the pattern;
- appends columns [0,1] to the end of each line;
- appends lines [0,1] to the end of the output.

Two things for golf:

1. The pattern array mapped to string with length 100 bytes;
2. The string reduced by simple `replace`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 148 bytes

```perl
$_='3A3'x$_.$/.'3B3
3A3
2/2\\2
1/4\\1
A6A
B6B
1\\4/1
2\\2/2
3B3
3A3
'=~s/^.*$/$&x$_/mger x<>.'3B3'x$_;s|A+|/\\|g;s|B+|\\/|g;s/\d/$"x$&/ge;s|^ |  |gm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCoMwFET3/xShBAMV802ibloLyb43@OimEgq1inbhIvToTWOhuxne8GYelkcdI@9bYawRG@8lRymMM5A6aNREGhRWRApsY8E1DhRRhQp2hBr@W9G@V@zkkSPPkgdHPyxsO19@tt18WoPNAxIFn6LLAxHuEemG/LDxDP2QQMcCY8GPMab/zzS/7tNzjcUci2stS1V@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 159 bytes

pattern taken from mazzy; translated to 1-2-3, converted to base26 -> decoded by the program

```php
while($y<$argv[2]*10+2)echo str_pad("",$argv[1]*10+2,strtr(base_convert([jng1,jnnb,jng1,jofn,k333,"1h4p5",23814,k94d,k02h,jnnb][$y++%10],26,4),312,"\ /")),"
";
```

requires PHP 5.5 or later. Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc42dffa84c94143ef2018a1a4d1a1aeea5d92e0).

calculating may be shorter (as it was for Arnauld). I may look into that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>196</s> 135 bytes

Saved 61 bytes thanks to ASCII-only's suggestion to use AZTECCO's C++ algorithm.

```
{h,w->var r=""
for(l in 9..h*10+10){for(c in 9..w*10+10){r+=when{(l%10+c%10)%8==5->'/'
(l%10-c%10+8)%8==4->'\\'
else->' '}}
r+='\n'}
r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VhLc9s2EL7rVyCeSSzVEmX5kdiayjPOo61n2qYTu9Np6x4gEhLRgAQDUpZdy789/XZBkFJi1@mht/IgE4vdxWIf3y793lZG5x@HQ/HKKVmpRMysE1WqSxHbRIm5NTMRp9IYlc/VuAPGtKqKcjwc0j5tR2Ul4/fqGlxgiWKbDT8sVFlpm5fD0YvD56NjEnvt5NIrTrTMbJ6IQlaVcjltXqRKTJWxy0AUS20M2ZJBBnuyhKCdsQISaEyKOrTkZ3jZvF4O76HiN7zzDy@Gl40Ir/EnyAUdTGgUXq69338OUen9W32lciFzofNiUeFGSZVimYhU6Xla9YWScSpOJqO@sIsKLCREt5VTe6XE6fmrszMhXdX4xKnCx6hKZSUymd@whM5U2Rd/Wp3rfC66dALknZFFAUJPgJe0lhlcRgK1/0vvum8Qb3Uts8KoPixzSsDTa0bDZm/5ROyR9ZwCfAFQRuN19wtxjysCccNVn3MOaz/fE6aHA/Zw6B4I4v3hFPcF9gvt3uQk6nef@9C7b38t@OTNB3z3yBmP2PWYZx/18Zd4@0v8/mgEHovFI1H5137434v/pRdp/93CqJKT/Gz4tk7ugTjjImBUYpQTMSpjitbC8Di9ETWO0RPbHEStcsCbqlKbREHLr3bBgoXT2NSANCvOL16//flCAMCcqhYASJAlDAjaZos8pjaE7XJhqkbXG4CackKCAU2mcHbuZEZqZCsinQpqZByropJToxoNpznMzuwCpqApqevKyVzZRSmWqa5UWciYIOBzBX1RWmEsYBp2EiijjzkZA91LgT6sxKJohAoYhtsC8M1Nc/B5BUdKl0CJLVLL/gbcoFFOdZKovGG8oE5bd/EBd3GcjAYgFuVCGu7r1C0chWztSHPT51Bxw0itw2UqPwl0NQUL6x4ALa@bx@RfPyT15rrAGehj6FIlOZsbuxJGZtNE@p6DMSJDGpR8oZeyBDdFxcytw3ZGeXP628WbV6/eRutDyXK5jEpr4Bjpcp5FfnJ2po0a7h/vHx/v7n06wXzCHV/F3x79cv7j8bn9EAaT0H7hzUwmFCMyWIrR7vVot9mlnkwS4Gr6tEd@btBkPfd7DjNf2PMH@bXe4OXreceWimXKCJVEAlMLnYl2ihPVp9FMO4pTSCbKZT7H52CuFHkbFYOY6zKlOrGzWZ@y1ZDbIQuzGzaSwVDnqpqRPbzaHe3tHxw@f3F0vMJ6sDNonh2sd1ctJND@aNUiCK33Vi100np/1YIXrQ9WLR7S@nDVYh@tn69axKP1i1ULcLQ@@uT840/O37S3mTkxV8brAUYOFJaTDb5fWpqV5jaXPDdxFLjeKY7sduuWVIwUuymGYF6U8Gfqi4pm6edrNR7xoRyZZzjKLDIAmvWjckCcach1OsApI3k31UVTJevi7Qzn7WktGAck@MEmSNUN6cIAqrINulcXkACeUB4kDymXRvuEHiRwVPNn4kYrk5TicNOCTS/8kw2Zzh8xgq08WrPlgG3Z@8yWIFCbdBB1AOOE67Eqyy4X4RjFU/XrAuNFbwwwdYSBt50OMmUIoq60NPovVfuemgbHluLYFq/m2HgZz0Ra6iTqh3PZsghcV9IFXROxtQUKqesGVcdR5K36arS7M9rteXNY@Tfh2DpVdL5m2MaZMkmCEHHUldziAbpNYuMFISro/H0RsQCb0qqHMeyu1hZfg7X9OxNABpp2bWJr5lrIkTEerhoWvupTaPTn4K339AitA5yDE7E93N7Q9nIzgxD0B9QNGnU7R7XCA1Z4ebmp8Zza8VgodJsbYTmTjI25rlqtygBnSVps17Q7kqXrdpoVvNUE5zRJal8vfVoAXgk9jKqU/84lqj@gdd/2ZU76G20ijC6epcMbdQZxYf0gdd6MKO23efv5S6megakr3bwci1Pn5M3XPrNPek1uf@9bK2ycq1w5WfkcrxPIpylGobHocp1QfZA36gqZeCWj/UM/AkQfb9P@cnDCqT1BTsOwrgnZXCfPLRHjkFWB6HYm5NPbruGM8MkwmRwOTigRmDqIQ0wnkwPQKZ4UHryK7bu7DlSQG/Fy95HtukBccTOnpA9JgoablwyqsxqXwkXFOzB1mkKhEGEmK4zmXofR0oqldUnpp6BMFr4Dewne8Uz4UXNG9DPGIMxgNIdRywCgA0euapnAuI4Lklo8/49EJev930s0Ey7GZer5PLX5tI3RG6Aplgskq8w9v7qm6bJO5gqu8EVL8eTvzxKwQ675Hnft9p48ifi63S2x1YvogrdNDegqqixC3@2JOybqGY19pCMqCRYn9D@AZ89qvb/v/iFOJmIESqvC74z8Tq@m85VM3i26jWS/Ze15NgpxzV@lzi7FGVJ8Ls2pmzNwvQn37G69RKC9@JOtXp3hb/PWE31fiaiKDTgWiZpJVFnfS1CEg7MjLkqAAtC2q5yzboxeDStoag84GK6xdn4f8zRVSK2Z7dm88V5f7PENubQRH1/jVLIf/wY)

Comment: [136](https://tio.run/##TZHfT8IwEMff91ccS2Ct@yEQTRDtEkx8IPFN38SHOgprLLel60Ak@9uxZUO4pMnlc/f99q79LoySeFzVCBsukXC9rqYw05rvn96MlrhOKRw82HIN5ZTM0UT20Dhti@x4yKNdnLqyZr7/6BJko6G3KjRRIBEekiS/wRDpwaGsQ7sW6ZDtcoEHovoYZn2k/Qlj93Ea3AaeY7Fl4eRE7yxdLAJPqErYFIKm8aw8WGBgk@YIYPTejWpjy93VZW0qYKAFX75KFIT2eklVKmmIDz5NNrzs2l1Ik5jCrkYoNCcoV0Baj6SSvwIYgzEMBp3vx/ATUgYjSy4WbWXUVmjHS/tORiEpyb8yurTSts0t1fWbXBc7mCsl1lzN9LreCDQvP5kojSyQ@M982cl7vhM3kHGT5UCE1oWewrvT8y8laLfdeYArZQR1ZX8PlmLFa3V2up51HMH4NFvjNcc/), stealing from the new C++ answer

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>194</s> <s>192</s> <s>187</s> 127 bytes

@ASCII-only's solution:

```python
lambda w,h,n=10:"\n".join("".join([" /","\\"][(j%n-i%n)%8==4][(j%n+i%n)%8==5]for i in range(-1,w*n+1))for j in range(-1,h*n+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcnRCsIgFIDhVzkcELS5ylYQgU8yd2GUeaSOQwajp7diddHVz8c/PqeYuavBunr3j/PFw6yjZmu2J3SM65SJJX7bI2xQo3M49DIJbkmwEkdr94ubnw9DyAUIiKF4vl1la/S84sYo9Rnpb8Rl1LEQTzLITu/eegE)

---

Original Solution

```python
n="\n"
def f(w,h):a=[r"     /\   "*w,r"     \/   "*w,r"    \  /  "*w,r"   \    / "*w,r"\/\      /"*w+r"\/"];return a[0]+n+n.join(([i.translate({47:92,92:47})for i in a]+a[::-1])*h)+n+a[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctLCsMgEIDhfU8hrjTapHlAiCUnURdCI7GESbCWUErPbk3Iop3FwDfDv7zCOEMdI/RYAT7dBossWflIhemlx2ibQqWFs5UfVsWf07f4sdqTw2pvt0My24z11Q/h6QEZedEMGOT32QEh0uXBG3hMJgzk3bSiq3hXiab9UDt75JBLiWZGCnEuNc1GmmIjSx0X7yAQS2peURq/)

-2 bytes thanks to @Black Owl Kai showing that the tops and bottoms can be accessed from the generated array instead of in separate variables.

-5 more bytes thanks to @Black Owl Kai using a more creative way to store the diamonds

Generates this portion of each diamond:

```python
     /\
     \/
    \  /
   \    /
\/\      /\/
```

A `/\` added at the end of each row to complete it. Then, the `/`s and `\`s are swapped to form the top of each diamond, and the order of the lines is reversed to form the bottom half. Finally, it adds in the very top row of `/\`s and the very bottom row of `\/`s to complete the image.

Comment: [192 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYtBCsMgEEX3PYW40miTJg2EGDxJdCE0EkuZBGsJpfTsVkMX7Sw@897MX59hXuAcI0isAB8uk0WWbHymwsjRY5RHVSlwsfEvV@qP01X9cLVXdsaV2rtZqCRYFlgPhsnRlcEbuN9MmMir7UTf8L4RbfemdvHIIQfIjEIca53@CzkPfgoPn2WtGTAor4sDYmjazXjScfUOArHkzBtK4wc) by not using the variables b and c

Comment: [187 bytes](https://tio.run/##VctLCsMgEIDhfU8hrjTapHlAiCUnURdCI7GESbCWUErPbk3Iop3FwDfDv7zCOEMdI/RYAT7dBossWflIhemlx2ibQqWFs5UfVsWf07f4sdqTw2pvt0My24z11Q/h6QEZedEMGOT32QEh0uXBG3hMJgzk3bSiq3hXiab9UDt75JBLiWZGCnEuNc1GmmIjSx0X7yAQS2peURq/) by removing two `+=`/`*=` assignments and flipping the whole diamond upside-down, making the last string easier to store

Comment: [181](https://tio.run/##VctNCoMwEAXgq4SsEo1af0BM6UmSLAZqMKVMJE2RUnr2VMVF@xYPvhne/IqTxzal62iJZYuYuISLCpRsqfRaNFvEYV39ef1WP9b75LDet9thdb6ZmnMY4zMg1UjLm3fIFKiTERlTrowB8HGHOLJ318uhEUMju/7DrQ/EEYcETA5KyqI2PJsEqNoYnubgMDLLWtFwnr4)

Comment: [147](https://tio.run/##VY1NCsIwEEb3OcUwEEiaFE2rIEJOYl0IJiZdTMsQKZ4@1oKC2/e@n/lV0kR9rfcQIarFJn0WwJY8onV7AXFiGCET8I0eQbXOpoaM@6Q2l//c8nPAxjPCsMOLUqOkNkvS8uT9QZuu2ZD5oqO@iq2AA@H6HsqT19E6c6aiouptp3V9Aw), uses c++ solution

Comment: [127](https://tio.run/##VcnRCsIgFIDhVzkcELS5ylYQgU8yd2GUeaSOQwajp7diddHVz8c/PqeYuavBunr3j/PFw6yjZmu2J3SM65SJJX7bI2xQo3M49DIJbkmwEkdr94ubnw9DyAUIiKF4vl1la/S84sYo9Rnpb8Rl1LEQTzLITu/eegE)