# Interleave strings

Tags: code-golf, string, sorting

[Inspiration.](https://twitter.com/dyalogapl/status/806443935811993600)* I cannot believe we have not had this challenge before:

**Task**

Given one or more printable ASCII strings, interleave them by taking one character from each string, cyclically until out of characters. If a string runs out of characters before the others, just skip that one from then on.

**Examples**

`SIMPLE` gives `SIMPLE`

`POLLS` and `EPEES` gives `PEOPLELESS`

`LYES` and `APRONS` gives `LAYPERSONS`

`ABCDE` and `a c` and `123 567` gives `Aa1B 2Cc3D E567`

`"\n$?*` and `​` (empty string) and `,(.)"`  (trailing space) gives `",\(n.$)?"*`  (trailing space)

---

<sup>* There are shorter APL solutions.</sup>

Comment: Since this is basically just a transpose operation, we've had a few challenges that are very similar, but possibly none that are exactly the same.

Comment: I had this question on my CS HW, does that mean I can close this as a homework question? ;P

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Cool! I learned something today.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
Z
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Wg&input=&args=WydBQkNERScsJ2EgYycsJzEyMyA1NjcnXQ)

The “transpose” built-in will do exactly this to a list of strings.

Comment: I'm curious, what would the code have looked like if you had to pad short strings with spaces?

Comment: That would be [`z⁶`](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=euKBtg&input=&args=WydBQkNERScsJ2EgYycsJzEyMyA1NjcnXQ). `z` is “transpose left, padding with right”; `⁶` is a space.

Comment: And what if built-ins doing the exact job were not allowed?

Comment: @Adám Jelly works very well on lists; where do built-ins end and language constructs / design begin?

Comment: @Lynn In Jelly? Anything on the Atoms and Quicks lists are buildt-ins.

Comment: @Adám `;"` (element-wise concatenation) would solve the task without a built-in.

Comment: @Dennis `;"/` tbf

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, <s>101</s> <s>89</s> <s>86</s> 69 bytes

<s>I'm hoping I can get this into a lambda somehow, shortening it down by making it recursive.</s> It isn't ideal because you would hope transposing is shorter, unfortunately it isn't (from what I have managed to come up with so far).

```python
f=lambda s:' '*any(s)and''.join(x[:1]for x in s)+f([x[1:]for x in s])
```

Old solutions:

```python
w=input();o=''
while any(w):
 for i in range(len(w)):o+=w[i][:1];w[i]=w[i][1:]
print o
```

`lambda s:''.join(''.join([c,''][c<' ']for c in x)for x in map(None,*[list(y)for y in s]))`

```python
w=input();o=''
while any(x>=' 'for x in w):
 for i in range(len(w)):o+=w[i][:1];w[i]=w[i][1:]
print o
```

<sup>*thanks to mathmandan for making me feel dumb ;) saved me a bunch of bytes! (on an old solution)*</sup>

Comment: Couldn't you just do `while any(w):`?  Empty strings are falsey in Python.

Comment: @mathmandan You're absolutely right, don't know what I was thinking..

Comment: No problem :)  Your new solution looks great, except I think you need to prepend `f=`.

Comment: You can take the `[]` off of the recursive call, leaving `f(x[1:] for x in s)`, that makes it a generator comprehension, which acts the same as a list in this context.

Answer (score 8):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <strike>34</strike> 32 bytes

```
{[~] flat roundrobin |$_».comb}
```

```
{roundrobin(|$_».comb).flat.join}
```

A lambda that takes an array of strings as argument, and returns a string.

([Try it online](https://ideone.com/3yFIAL))

Comment: I  would have used `@_` instead of `$_`

Answer (score 7):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 4 bytes

```
qN/z
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4veg&input=QUJDREUKYSBjCjEyMyA1Njc)

We can also write an unnamed function for 4 bytes, which expects a list of strings on top of the stack:

```
{zs}
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=WyJBQkNERSIgImEgYyIgIjEyMyA1NjciXQoKe3pzfQoKfg&input=)

Comment: That's one byte a minute!

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth - 3 bytes

Very simple, will add expansion later, on mobile.

```
s.T
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.T&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22SIMPLE%22%0A%22LYES%22%2C%20%22APRON%22%0A%22ABCDE%22%2C%20%22a%20c%22%2C%20%22123%20567%22&debug=0)

```
s                         Join all the strings together
 .T                       Transpose, without chopping off overhang
  (Q implicit)
```

Comment: @Daniel I'm in school too :P

Comment: Any plans on adding the explanation?

Comment: @JanDvorak sure doing it now.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>52</s> 46 bytes

```
f=([[c,...s],...a])=>s+a?c+f(s+s?[...a,s]:a):c
```

Takes input as an array of strings and outputs as a single string.

#### Test snippet

```js
f=([[c,...s],...a])=>s+a?c+f(s+s?[...a,s]:a):c

g=a=>console.log("Input:",JSON.stringify(a),"Output:",JSON.stringify(f(a)))

g(["SIMPLE"])
g(["POLLS","EPEES"])
g(["LYES","APRONS"])
g(["ABCDE","a c","123 567"])
g(["\"\\n$?*",",(.)\" "]) // Backslash and quote are escaped, but in/output are correct
```

Comment: `f=([[c,...s],...a])=>c?c+f([...a,s]):a+a&&f(a)`

Comment: @Neil That's a great approach. I managed to golf 6 bytes off my own :-)

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 33 bytes

```haskell
import Data.List
concat.transpose
```

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/fU5986) Usage:

```haskell
Prelude Data.List> concat.transpose$["ABCDE","a c","123 567"]
"Aa1B 2Cc3D E567"
```

---

#### Without using a build-in: (<s>38</s> 34 bytes)

```haskell
f[]=[]
f x=[h|h:_<-x]++f[t|_:t<-x]
```

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/d8vZGp) 4 bytes off thanks to Zgarb! Usage:

```haskell
Prelude> f["ABCDE","a c","123 567"]
"Aa1B 2Cc3D E567"
```

Comment: You can remove all parens in the alternative version. Still won't beat the import though.

Comment: Do you actually need the base case?

Comment: Never mind, of course the base case is needed.

Comment: @xnor You also can't move the base case to the end and replace it with `f a=a` to save a byte because both `[]` have a different type ... so close.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```
for(;$f=!$k=$f;$i++)for(;y|$v=$argv[++$k];$f&=""==$c)echo$c=$v[$i];
```

Loops over command line arguments. Run with `-r`.

After the inner loop, `$f` is `1` when all strings are finished, `0` else (bitwise `&` casts `""==$c` to int).
Next iteration of the outer loop: copy `$f` to `$k` (saves one byte from `$k=0`) and toggle `$f`:
When all strings are done, `$f` is now `false` and the loop gets broken.

Comment: Doesn't work with empty input strings. Take a look at the last testcase

Comment: @aross: fixed. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## C, <s>114</s> 84 bytes

-20 bytes for not calculating the length.

```c++
i,b;f(char**s){b=1;while(b){i=-1;b=0;while(s[++i]>0)if(*s[i])putchar(*s[i]++),++b;}}
```

Accepts array of char pointers and requires last item to be a null-pointer (see usage).

Ungolfed and usage:

```c++
i,b;f(char**s){
 b=1;
 while(b){
  i=-1;
  b=0;
  while(s[++i]>0)
   if(*s[i])
    putchar(*s[i]++),++b;
 }
}


int main(){
 char*a[]={ 
//  "POLLS","EPEES"
//  "LYES","APRONS"
 "ABCDE","a c","123 567"
 ,0};
 f(a);
 puts("");
}
```

Comment: Does the usage of printf/sprintf not allowed ? :D you would win quite some bytes.

Comment: @Walfrat Without printing directly I'd need to allocate a string, so how could this save anything.

Comment: it was before your edit where you added the ++b and remove length compute, so yes can't work anymore.

Comment: @Walfrat Yes, but i had a `malloc` and `return` before and this was longer than just printing

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com), 13 bytes

```
({~/:)&;#\&.>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGuloFFdp2@lqWatHKOmZ8eVmpyRr5CmYKMe7Okb4OOqDhNQD/D38QlWt1Z3DXB1DUYI@0S6gkQdA4L8/ZCEHZ2cXVyB4okKyUDS0MhYwdTMHCGtFJOnYq8FlAEiHQ09TSUF9f//AQ)

Based on the [inspiration](https://twitter.com/dyalogapl/status/806443935811993600) for this question.

Another way to do it takes 27 bytes but operates using transpose. Most of the bytes are to handle the automatically added zeroes from padding.

```
[:u:0<:@-.~[:,@|:(1+3&u:)&>
```

### Explanation

```
({~/:)&;#\&.>  Input: list of boxed strings S
          &.>  For each boxed string x in S
        #\       Get the length of each prefix from shortest to longest
                 This forms the range [1, 2, ..., len(x)]
                 Rebox it
(    )         Operate on S and the prefix lengths
      &;         Raze both
   /:            Grade up the raze of the prefix lengths
 {~              Index into the raze of S using the grades
               Return
```

Comment: J's prohibiting mixed arrays really hurts you here. Try it in APL.

Comment: Very nice approach.  You can do the transpose approach in 15 bytes without worrying about 0 like this: `[:u:@,@|:3&u:&>`.  [TIO](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1koh2qrUykHHocbKWK3USs2OKzU5I18hTcFGPdjTN8DHVR0moB7g7@MTrG6t7hrg6hqMEPaJdAWJOgYE@fshCTs6Obu4AsUTFZKBpKGRsYKpmTlCWikmT8VeCygDRDoaeppKCur//wMA)

Answer (score 4):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 13 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
O$#`.
$.%`
¶
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=TyQjYC4KJC4lYArCtgo&input=QUJDREUKYSBjCjEyMyA1Njc)

#### Explanation

```
O$#`.
$.%`
```

This is based on the standard transposition technique in Retina. We sort (`O`) all non-linefeed characters (`.`), by (`$#`) the number of characters in front of them on the same line (`` $.%` ``), i.e. their horizontal position.

The second stage then simply removes linefeeds from the input.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <strike>19+155=174</strike> 160

```java
String f(java.util.Queue<String> q){String s,r="";while(!q.isEmpty()){s=q.poll();r+=s.isEmpty()?"":s.charAt(0);if(s.length()>1)q.add(s.substring(1));}return r;}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
  String f(java.util.Queue<String> q) {
    String s, r = "";
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
      s = q.poll();
      r += s.isEmpty() ? "" : s.charAt(0);
      if (s.length() > 1) {
        q.add(s.substring(1));
      }
    }
    return r;
  }
```

Output:

> SIMPLE
>
> PEOPLELESS
>
> LAYPERSONS
>
> Aa1B 2Cc3D E567
>
> ",(n.$)?"* ​

First modification: merged string declaration to save some bytes. Removed `import`, it was used by the `main()` method (not shown here) that also needed `LinkedList`. It is fewer bytes to referece `Queue` directly.

Comment: initialize string s with string r can save few more

Comment: I know it's been almost a year ago, but you can golf a few bytes: `String f(java.util.Queue<String>q){String s,r="";for(;!q.isEmpty();r+=s.isEmpty()?"":s.charAt(0))if((s=q.poll()).length()>1)q.add(s.substring(1));return r;}`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
lambda*m:''.join(map(lambda*r:''.join(filter(None,r)),*m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiVa6WurpeVn5mnkZtYoAEVLIILpmXmlKQWafjl56XqFGlq6mjlamr@LyjKzCtRSNPIzCsoLdHQ1EGjNf@rOzo5u7iqc6knKiQDSUMjYwVTM3N1AA)

Comment: Can't you remove the space in `lambda *m`?

Comment: I just did that! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

Golfing suggestions welcome! [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=YSBa4pmCzqPOow&input=IkFCQ0RFIgoiYSBjIgoiMTIzIDU2NyI)

**Edit:** -1 byte thanks to Teal pelican.

```
a Z♂ΣΣ
```

**Ungolfing**

```
          Implicit input each string.
a         Invert the stack so that the strings are in the correct order.
<space>   Get the number of items on the stack, len(stack).
Z         Zip all len(stack) strings into one, transposing them.
♂Σ        sum() every transposed list of chars into strings.
Σ         sum() again to join the strings together.
```

Comment: Can you not remove the # to make it 6 bytes?

Comment: @Tealpelican Welp, now I'm going to have to dig through all of my old Actually answers and see if I can't change `Z♂#Σ` to `Z♂Σ` in all of them. Thanks for the tip :D

Comment: First time looking into the language, it looks so much fun! Glad I could help :))

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 77 bytes

### Golfed

```
function($a){for($d=1;$d!=$s;$i++){$d=$s;foreach($a as$v)$s.=$v[$i];}echo$s;}
```

Anonymous function that takes an array of strings.

I'm sure this could be golfed more, but it's early. On each iteration, we grab the i-th letter from each given string and append it to our final string, one at a time. PHP just throws warnings if we access bits of strings that don't exist, so that's fine. We only stop when no changes have been made after looping through all the strings once.

I feel like the usage of `$d` can be golfed more, but it's early. :P

Comment: How exactly do you put an array of strings in a single argument?

Comment: @Titus. Y'know, I never really thought about it. I just kinda assumed you could.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

```js
f=([[c,...s],...a])=>c?c+f([...a,s]):a+a&&f(a)
```

```html
<textarea oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value.split`\n`)></textarea><div id=o>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 55

```bash
 eval paste `sed "s/.*/<(fold -1<<<'&')/g"`|tr -d \\n\\t
```

I/O via STDIN (line-separated) and STDOUT.

The `sed` formats each line to a [bash process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution).  These are then `eval`ed into `paste` to do the actual interleaving.  `tr` then removes unnecessary newlines and tabs.

[Ideone.](https://ideone.com/KYkv8V)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 63 bytes

Note: uses IBM-850 encoding

```
for(;$s^=1;$i++)for(;n|$w=$argv[++$$i];$s&=$x<~■)echo$x=$w[$i];
```

Run like this:

```
php -r 'for(;$s^=1;$i++)for(;n|$w=$argv[++$$i];$s&=$x<~■)echo$x=$w[$i];' "\"\n\$?*" "" ",(.)\" " 2>/dev/null;echo
> ",\(n.$)?"*
```

## Explanation

```
for(                       # Iterate over string index.
  ;
  $s ^= 1;                 # Continue until $s (stop iterating) is 1.
                           # Flip $s so each iteration starts with $s
                           # being 1.
  $i++                     # Increment string index.
)
  for(
    ;
    "n" | $w=$argv[++$$i]; # Iterate over all input strings. OR with "n"
                           # to allow for empty strings.
    $s &= $x<~■            # If last character printed was greater than
                           # \x0 (all printable chars), set $s to 0,
                           # causing the loop to continue.
  )
    echo $x = $w[$i];      # Print char $i of current string.
```

Comment: IBM-850?! Is that a natural encoding for PHP?

Comment: @Adám what do you mean by "natural"? PHP treats bytes in the range 128-255 as text, which is therefore interpreted as a constant. If the constant is undefined, it will be interpreted as a string. It's so I can do `~■` (negated binary 254) instead of `"\x1"` (binary 1).

Comment: I see. It isn't that you actually need that codepage, you just need a 254 byte.

Comment: @Adám yes, the codepage just makes it a printable char which is a little less annoying.

Comment: Great use of `$$`!

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, <strike>128</strike> 96

I was hoping not to have to use itertools

```
a=lambda a:"".join([i for i in reduce(lambda: b,c:b+c, map(None,*map(lambda m:list(m),a)) if i])
```

Ungolfed

```
 a=lambda a:                              #Start a lambda taking in a
    "".join(                              #Join the result together with empty string
        [i for i in reduce(               #For every item, apply the function and 'keep'
           lambda: b,c:b+c,               #Add lists from...
                map(None,*map(            #None = Identity function, over a map of...
                    lambda m:list(m), a)  #list made for mthe strings m
                   ) if i                 #truthy values only (otherwise the outer map will padd with None.
       ])
```

Comment: Would appreciate feedback/advice on improving this.

Comment: Looks like this answer is invalid due to some syntax errors. Here's a [fixed version](https://tio.run/##LYrLCsIwEAB/ZdlToqFgRYWAB6te/YHqYZOmuNI8iPHg10cLPc3ATPqWZwxtpeO9TuTNQEAasXlFDqJnGGMGBg6Q3fCxTiyPUVabtVWekrjF4NRqtiV6PfG7CC8VSSl5BH7ImjKHAiR6PHXnyxUVIIGdsWm3sNsf8D/9AA), and here's [one possible way to golf it](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfaBvzPycxNyklUSHRSklJLys/M08jN7FAAyKoVQIXTMvMKUkt0vDLz0vVKdHU1NFK1NT8X1CUmVeikKgRreTo5OziqqSjoJSokAyiDI2MFUzNzJViNf8DAA) (58 bytes).

Comment: @DLosc thanks! Not sure how best to incorporate those right now, but I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 75 Bytes

I know the other Python one is shorter, but this is the first time I've used `map` ever in my life so I'm pretty proud of it

```
lambda n:''.join(i[k]for k in range(max(map(len,n)))for i in n if len(i)>k)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3 bytes

```
WVg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/PCz9////jk7OLq7/ExWS/xsaGSuYmpkDAA)

The `WV` (weave) builtin does exactly this. It's commonly used as a binary operator to weave two iterables together, but it can also be used as a unary operator to weave a list of iterables together. Here, `g` is the list of command-line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 59 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and s[0][:1]+f(s[1:]+[s[0][1:]][:s[0]>""])or""
```

A recursive function that takes a list of strings and returns a string. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRodiqWCExL0WhONogNtrKMFY7TaM42tAqVjsaLAJkAYVBTDslpVjN/CIlpf8FRZl5JRppGtFKPpGuwUo6SokFRfl5xUAGUIXmfwA)

#### Explanation

We're going to build the interleaved string one character at a time. There are several cases to consider:

- Is the first string in the list nonempty? Take its first character, move the rest of it to the end of the list, and recurse.
- Is the first string in the list empty? Remove it from the list and recurse.
- Is the list of strings empty? Then we're done. Return empty string.

The implementation goes as follows:

```python
f = lambda s: s and ... or ""
```

Define `f` to be a function of one argument, `s`, which is a list of strings. If `s` is nonempty, do the `...` part (see below); otherwise, return `""`.

```python
s[0][:1] + f(...)
```

Since we now know `s` is nonempty, we can refer to its first element, `s[0]`. We don't know yet whether `s[0]` is empty, though. If it isn't, we want to concatenate its first character to a recursive call; if it is, we can concatenate the empty string to a recursive call. Slicing everything left of index 1 works in both cases.

```python
s[1:] + ...
```

The argument to the recursive call is going to be all but the first element of `s`, concatenated to either a 1-element list (the rest of `s[0]` if it was nonempty) or an empty list (if `s[0]` was empty).

```python
[s[0][1:]][:s[0] > ""]
```

We put `s[0][1:]` (the part of `s[0]` after the first character, which is the empty string if `s[0]` is empty) into a singleton list and then take a slice of that list. If `s[0]` is empty, `s[0] > ""` is `False`, which is treated as `0` in a slice; thus, we slice from index 0 to index 0--an empty slice. If `s[0]` is not empty, `s[0] > ""` is `True`, which is treated as `1`; thus, we slice from index 0 to index 1--the whole 1-element list.

---

If lists of single-character strings can be used in place of strings, this solution can be **54 bytes**:

```python
f=lambda s:s and s[0][:1]+f(s[1:]+(s[0]and[s[0][1:]]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxCsQgEAC/slitJEXkOiFlunSpwmLhEeSEZBXXJq83Xrphhsl3/SX@tBbm01/fw4NYAc8HCE2OrHFDQCFj3YB/0wu9pRundcslcsWAdEapKBpCKiAQGUit@7KpUflcEksH9R4P)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
<!/,/'(!#:)'\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs7JR1NfRV9dQVLbSVI/h4kpT0FBydHJ2cVWyVkpUSAaShkbGCqZm5kqaQDmdaKVgT98AH1elWLBKn0jXYKASx4Agf79gJU0AfEcQ7w==)

Port of [miles's J](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102518/16766) and [DLosc's BQN](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251298/78410). For a language with flatten and grade/sort-by but not zip-longest, I guess this is one of the best possible approaches.

More straightforward port would be `{(,/x)@<,/!'#'x}` because K doesn't have fork or over. But it is possible to use K train by abusing repeat-scan:

```
<!/,/'(!#:)'\
      (   )'\   Given a list of strings, apply this to each list
                until convergence and collect all intermediate values
                (including the input):
       !#:        get the indices of the list
                This always converges after step 1, giving (x;!#x)
   ,/'          Flatten each
<!/             Sort first by second
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>75</s> 71 bytes

Only limitation is the output length. Currently it's 99, but can be easily stretched to 999 (+1 byte).

```
i;main(a,b)char**b;{a--;for(;i<99;i++)*b[i%a+1]&&putchar(*b[i%a+1]++);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
i;
main( a, b )
char **b;
{
    a--;
    for( ; i < 99; i++ )
        *b[i % a + 1] && putchar( *b[i % a + 1]++ );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL, 195 bytes

```
    select listagg(b,'') within group(order by l,o) from(select substr(a,level,1) b,level l,o from i start with length(a)>0 connect by prior a=a and level<=length(a) and prior sys_guid() is not null)
```

Takes its input from a table named `i` with columns `a` (containing the string) and `o` (order of the string):

```
    create table i (a varchar2(4000), a integer)
```

Explanation:
We're exploiting `CONNECT BY` to break up the strings into each of the characters making them up. `PRIOR SYS_GUID()` being `NOT NULL` ensures we don't end up stuck in a loop.
We then concatenate the single characters with `LISTAGG` but we shuffle them around with an `ORDER BY` clause, ordering them first by their position in the original string and only then by the string they came from.

Not as short as the other answers but SQL isn't really meant as a string manipulation language :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), + `-0n` 24 bytes

```perl
1while s/^./!print$&/gem
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@wPCMzJ1WhWD9OT1@xoCgzr0RFTT89Nff//wB/H59gLtcAV9fgf/kFJZn5ecX/dfMMAA)

### Explanation

`-0n` slurps the input into `$_` and repeatedly replaces the first char of each line with the result of negating the `print` of each match (which is the empty string since `print` returns `1` by default)

Comment: I thought I was good in Perl, but this baffled me.  So -0 on input that doesn't contail a NUL is equivalent to slurping all.  And then ^. with /g prints each beginning of line, while replacing it with nothing.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah that's about it! Needing to negate the `print` is a little annoying... Having looked at this again, I can save a byte using `1while s/....` so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 73 bytes

```r
for(i in 1:max(nchar(s<-scan(,""))))for(j in seq(s))cat(substr(s[j],i,i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdAqN7FCIy85I7FIo9hGtzg5MU9DR0lJEwhAarJAaopTCzWKNTWTE0s0ikuTikuAKqOzYnUydTI1Nf8rOTo5u7gqcSklKiQDSUMjYwVTM3Mlrv8A)

Explanation: very simple (but verbose), just loop through printing `i`th character of the `j`th string. Fortunately, `substr` returns an empty string if given an out-of-range input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 49 bytes

```
map(explode)|transpose|map(map(values)[])|implode
```

Explanation

```
                      # example input:          ["LYES","APRONS"]
  map(explode)        # make list of ordinals   [[76,89,69,83],[65,80,82,79,78,83]]
| transpose           # zip lists               [[76,65],[89,80],[69,82],[83,79],[null,78],[null,83]]
| map(map(values)[])  # rm nulls and flatten    [76,65,89,80,69,82,83,79,78,83]
| implode             # convert back to string  "LAYPERSONS"
```

Sample Run

```
$ paste input <(jq -Mrc 'map(explode)|transpose|map(map(values)[])|implode' input)
["SIMPLE"]                  SIMPLE
["POLLS","EPEES"]           PEOPLELESS
["LYES","APRONS"]           LAYPERSONS
["ABCDE", "a c", "123 567"] Aa1B 2Cc3D E567
["\"\\n$?*", "", ",(.)\" "] ",\(n.$)?"* 

$ echo -n 'map(explode)|transpose|map(map(values)[])|implode' | wc -c
  49
```

[**Try it online**](https://jqplay.org/s/u4OgJj_3j2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 22 bytes

```
[ round-robin ""like ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQma@QnVqUl5qjUJxaWJqal5xajGDppVaUFCUWK1hzcVUrKDk6Obu4KikoJSokA0lDI2MFUzNzJYXa/9EKRfmleSm6RflJmXkKSko5mdmpCrH/kxNzchQKijLzSv4DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 1 byte

```
∩
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwi4oipIiwiIiwiWydBQkNERScsICdhIGMnLCAnMTIzIDU2NyddIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>23</s> 10 bytes

*Massive savings by porting [miles's J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102518/16766)*

```
↕∘≠¨⍋⊸⊏○∾⊢
```

Anonymous tacit function that takes a list of strings and returns a string. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oaV4oiY4omgwqjijYviirjiio/il4viiL7iiqIKCkYgIiLigL8iTFlFUyLigL8iQVBST05TIg==)

#### Explanation

```
↕∘≠¨⍋⊸⊏○∾⊢
   ¨         For each string in the argument list:
  ≠            Take its length
↕∘             and make a range from 0 to that number (exclusive)
             With that list of lists of indices as the left argument
          ⊢  and the original list of lists of strings as the right argument:
        ○∾     Flatten both lists
      ⊸⊏       Index into the flattened string using
    ⍋          the grade-up of the flattened list of indices
```

Grade up, for those unfamiliar with APL-related languages, is an operation that takes a list and returns a permutation of its indices, such that if the items in the list were reordered according to the order of the indices, the list would become sorted ascending. For example:

```
Indices:  0 1 2 3 4 5
List:     3 1 4 1 5 9

Grade up: 1 3 0 2 4 5
Sorted:   1 1 3 4 5 9
```

This operation is useful for sorting one list according to the values of another list, as seen in the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 112 bytes

```
i=len(x)if len(x)>len(y) else len(y) h=0 a="" while h<i: if h<len(x) a+=x[h] if h<len(y): a += y[h] h+=1 print a
```

Comment: Your formatting is really messed up.. where do you even get `x` and `y` from?

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 53 bytes

```perl
$i=0,map{push@{$a[$i++]},$_}/./g for<>;print@$_ for@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l09ZAJzexoLqgtDjDoVolMVolU1s7tlZHJb5WX08/XSEtv8jGzrqgKDOvxEElHsR1SPz/3yfSNZiLyzEgyN8v@F9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQwMA)

**Method**

Creates a two dimensional array where the number of rows is equal to the length of the longest string and the maximum number of columns is equal to the number of strings.  Then output each row of the array without spacing.

Answer (score 0):

## [TXR Lisp](http://nongnu.org/txr), 20 bytes

```
(opip weave cat-str)
```

Run:

```
1> (opip weave cat-str)
#<intrinsic fun: 0 param + variadic>
2> [*1 "LYES" "APRONS"]
"LAYPERSONS"
3> [*1 "ABCDE" "a c" "" "123 567"]
"Aa1B 2Cc3D E567"
4> [*1 "\"\\n$?*" "" ",(.) "]
"\",\\(n.$)? *"
```

The `weave` function is lazy, so it returns a list, which is why we have to force the result to a string. Being lazy, it can weave infinite sequences. For instance, we can weave the even and odd natural numbers, which are themselves infinite lazy lists:

```
5> (take 20 (weave (range 2 : 2) (range 1 : 2)))
(2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 10 9 12 11 14 13 16 15 18 17 20 19)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>35</s> 29 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{`c$r@&~^r:,/+(`i$x)[;!#,/x]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/vzohWaXIQa0urshKR19bIyFTpUIz2lpRWUe/IrZWQ8nRydnFVclaKVEhGUgaGhkrmJqZK2n@/w8A)

**Example:**

```
> {`c$r@&~^r:,/+(`i$x)[;!#,/x]}("ABCDE";"a c";"123 567")
"Aa1B 2Cc3D E567"
> {`c$r@&~^r:,/+(`i$x)[;!#,/x]}("\n$?*";"";",(.)\" ")
"\n,$(?.*)\" "
> {`c$r@&~^r:,/+(`i$x)[;!#,/x]}("POLLS";"EPEES")
"PEOPLELESS"
```

**Explanation:**

Use 2nd-level indexing to pull out indices from 0 to max (length of flattened list) across all input lists. Any indexing beyond the bound of the sub-list will return a null. Flip (rotates 90), flatten, and then pull out the non-null results.

**Notes:**

- I cast to integer (`i$`) so that we get useful nulls, as space () is considered null for a char list which means you cant tell nulls from valid spaces.
- Also I couldnt get the TIO to work with input (worked fine in the oK repl) so the TIO link includes the "ABCDE"... example.

Answer (score 0):

### Python3 -66

Python3 version of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116670/110481):

```python
lambda*m:''.join(map(lambda*r:''.join([_f for _f in r if _f]),*m))
```

A super golfed version:

```python
exec(bytes('慬扭慤洪✺⸧潪湩洨灡氨浡摢⩡㩲✧樮楯⡮彛⁦潦⁲晟椠⁮⁲晩张嵦Ⱙ洪⤩','u16')[2:])
```

Comment: How long is the "super golfed" version?  It looks longer.

Comment: It has 8 fewer characters.

Comment: Why not use a filter instead of a list comprehension like the answer you're porting from?

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 86 bytes

```cs
a=>a.SelectMany(b=>b.Select((c,i)=>(i,c))).OrderBy(b=>b.i).Aggregate("",(s,x)=>s+x.c);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBdS8MwFH1ef8U1@JCwWtyGCnYt7CPCoHPFPoiID1mW1rCaStrppPS316ROnfh0P86955x7eXnGS9ne7BSH8YKq3YvQbJ2LcVlpqbLQhUMCKQTQsiBkXiJywaslUx94HYTrQ40xdyUJQixdTgjxVnoj9PQwIok3yTItMlYJjJCLS3dvZsv@3uPEb9@YhmJrBCq9E75jS6led1VpWkq8w@MT1D8JShbLOKKocX9b8SqKEuQCojGlyR8oeqAdMonvVrd/ocl0NqcWY8BtGAxHcHF5hRpovkyI/au5TGyObHyrm/GYrkwW0aTjjyYPMb1LrIZVY4MpDGd8NAfaUfpOWmjAUlUgDd25b8L4cKUXCZVVzz70@5I4tdOTKeAUf4GP8onASfDjxdZOzwz1ZoUqi1x491pWIpJK4FOUMpmLzTXUx@uN3a@PCBpEfEPQvTxleWl@3mucxrG6xbaz8J8cFVu71rSf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 103 bytes

```
;=m=iF;W=xP;=mI>mLx mLxE++"=x"=i+1i" x"W+=m-mT1;=j~1W>i=j+1j;O+G E+"x"+1jF1'\'E++++"=x"+1j"Sx"+1j"F1''"
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PW09aUY7Vz14UDs9bUk+bUx4IG1MeEUrK1wiPXhcIj1pKzFpXCIgeFwiVys9bS1tVDE7PWp+MVc+aT1qKzFqO08rRyBFK1wieFwiKzFqRjEnXFwnRSsrKytcIj14XCIrMWpcIlN4XCIrMWpcIkYxJydcIiIsIkFCQ0RFXG5hIGNcbjEyMyA1NjciXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 68 bytes

```
lambda S:filter(None,chain(*zip_longest(*S)))
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3XXISc5NSEhWCrdIyc0pSizT88vNSdZIzEjPzNLSqMgvic_Lz0lOLSzS0gjU1NbnSivJzFTKB6kry83OKFTJzC_KLSrQgZu0sKMrMK9GI1krTiFZKTEpW0lFKSVWK1YzVhMgvWAChAQ)