# Flip rows and columns

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge

## Objective

To flip the rows and columns of a table in a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.

## Instructions

You will be passed a "table" of 3 arrays/lists with 3 items each as input. Your job is to flip the rows and columns on it by writing a **program** that can do this efficiently and creatively. You will flip the "table" according to the example below.

## Example

### Input

```python
["foo", 5, 0b1011]
[3.14, "bar", 10]
["apple", 90, "monty"]
```

### Output

```python
["foo", 3.14, "apple"]
[5, "bar", 90]
[0b1011, 10, "monty"]
```

## Qualification

In order to qualify for winning, you must:

1. Solve the challenge (use the above input for a test case)
2. *Optional:* Post a link to an [ideone](http://ideone.com) or [repl.it](http://repl.it)
3. Follow standard loopholes
4. Put a header in the format: `Language, XX bytes`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so least bytes wins. Good Luck!

## Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=127611,OVERRIDE_USER=46066;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Is STDIN required? Can we not use the [Standard IO](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)?

Comment: So, essentially "zip"?

Comment: @ATaco I thought STDIN was Standard IO. Go ahead and use Standard IO. It seems the same. As long as it isn't arguments.

Comment: What kind of arguments? Also, why require ideone or repl.it? Why not [TIO](tio.run) ?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline as in terminal or function arguments. Just as a convenient way to run.

Comment: @juniorRubyist What do you mean by arguments? Did you follow the link? Standard IO is our communities standard consensus for Input Output. It's not necessary for a challenge writer to follow, but it's suggested.

Comment: @ATaco Oh ok. Sorry about that.

Comment: Please edit the question to remove the IO restrictions.

Comment: This challenge's IO seems to be geared towards a particular language (Not sure which one), and is unusually restrictive about it when handling IO doesn't seem like it should be the main focus of the challenge. I _strongly_ recommend allowing much more flexible IO.

Comment: -1 for having a very strict IO format; it ends up becoming a larger portion of the answer than the actual challenge. I will revert if you change that.

Comment: -1 because of `2. Post a link to an ideone or repl.it`. Some languages are not available on those sites.

Comment: Not to mention that `0` answers follow this rule circa now.

Comment: In the future, I recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get early feedback on your question.

Comment: Can we take input/output as a list of lists?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17305/62131). Not quite a duplicate, though, AFAICT, because the padding rules are different (this challenge allows you to assume that the input is 3×3 rather than needing to be able to handle a ragged array).

Comment: @ais523 That one is also zip+reverse (so rotate), not quite just zip. but yes, closely related

Comment: Voting to reopen as this is on the diagonal, not the antidiagonal.

Answer (score 2):

## Math.JS, 1 byte

```
'
```

`'` is a named operator which takes it's left argument and transposes it.

[Try it out](https://a-ta.co/math/%5B%5B%22foo%22%2C%205%2C%2011%5D%2C%0A%5B3.14%2C%20%22bar%22%2C%2010%5D%2C%0A%5B%22apple%22%2C%2090%2C%20%22monty%22%5D%5D%27)

Comment: Doesn't output in the correct format.

Comment: @juniorRubyist That's fine. But do consider that it does technically solve the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 3 bytes

```

```

This character (U+F3C7) is Mathematica's builtin `Transpose` suffix operator.

Comment: Yes it is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 3 bytes

```
zip
```

Note that you must pass the arguments not in a list, but rather as separate arguments, which I believe is acceptable. If not, `lambda x:zip(*x)` works too for a list as a parameter.

If builtins are not allowed (which was not specified), `lambda x:[[b[a]for b in x]for a in range(len(x[0]))]` works, or, since it's specified to be 3 × 3, `lambda x:[[b[a]for b in x]for a in[1,2,3]]` works.

If you're going to enforce the strict IO, then here you go:

```
print(zip(*[input()for i in'3cs'])) # '3cs' because why not, CalcCat
```

Comment: @juniorRubyist Functional under site standards. Override standards and enforce STDIN? (not recommended)

Comment: `[0]*3` can be `"3cs"` for +customizability.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Oh smart. Thanks!

Comment: wait that doesn't save bytes. nvm. but still, nice

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 1 byte

```
C
```

Pyth's `C` command transposes the given nested list.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 2 bytes

> Ans<sup>T</sup>

Not eligible for "winning" due to specification #2 but a valid answer nonetheless.

Comment: Please use a code block.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline: The answer appears to be using HTML to reproduce characters that are in TI-Basic's character set but not in ASCII. You could use Unicode instead, though: `Ansᵀ`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>44</s> 51 bytes

*Crossed out 44 is still <s>44</s> :(*

```
for i in zip(*[input()for i in"hi!"]):print list(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSqzQEMrOjOvoLREQxMmqpSRqagUq2lVUJSZV6KQk1lcopGp@f9/tKGOkY5xLFe0iY6pjhmQNtex0LGMBQA)

Follows original IO rules. Only works for 3 high input (other heights are not required). Change the length of `"hi!"` to height of input.

Comment: You can't request for the code to be changed given the input. You need to account for it somehow *programmatically*.

Comment: Nope. See question.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I see that you only need to support up to three. You might want to mention, though, `Only works for \`3\` high input, as required`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q/@F29///o6OV0vLzlXQUTHUUDJIMDQwNY3W4oo31DE10FJSSEouAMoYGICGlxIKCnFQg19IAKJObn1dSqRQbCwA)

Footer added on the TIO link to make the result easier to see.

This is Jelly's builtin for Zip.

Answer (score 1):

## MacOS bash, 6

```
rs -Tc
```

Works on Linux as well, if `rs` is installed, as TIO:

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6hYQTck@f//tPx8TlNOgyRDA0NDLmM9QxPOpMQiTkMDrsSCgpxUTksDztz8vJJKLgA).

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 26 bytes

```
import Data.List
transpose
```

This is a built-in